# Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 1H 2014

Tags: discussion, community-ads, open-source-advertising

December 2013 has come to us now, which means a new edition of our Free Vote-Based Advertising for Open Source Projects. We are clearing the leaderboards to start the beginning of 2014.

Here is your chance to create a [Free Vote-Based Advertisement for an Open Source Project](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/). Create a graphical ad for an open source programming project and post it as an answer to this question (in the right format), and it will feed live remnant ads on Stack Overflow.

### Ad Requirements

It must be an advertisement **soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code**. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source. It's for finding programmers who will help contribute code or other programmery things (documentation, code review, bug fixes, etc.).

Your ad should be an original creation which has not previously appeared on Stack Overflow. Please do not resubmit entries that have appeared as ads on Stack Overflow in previous periods.

In order to work, the answers you post to this question **must** conform to the following rules.

### Answer Template

```
[![alternative text if image is not displayed][1]][2]
    
  [1]: http://image-url
  [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to add any commentary, keep it in the comments.

### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 pixels by 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- Must have a 1px border if (part of) the background is white

The output, which ultimately will be served in an ad slot on Stack Overflow, can be previewed by clicking through to this URL:

http://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/220x250

### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be served up by that URL and shown on Stack Overflow. You can see all the ads that currently make the threshold and meet our criteria on this page:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/251196

**Note:** *As with previous [iterations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195823/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2013) of this program, if your ad has already appeared in a previous cycle, it is not eligible to be run in this cycle. See also the first comment for additional notes about this cycle*

Comment: *Must have a 1px border if (part of) the background is white* refers to absolutely any portion of the background, or just the border of the image? Also, I'm assuming this can't be a white border? If so, several highly-voted ads violate this rule, and are running.

Comment: It seems the MSO migration moved the ad link [(I edited it)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/251196/revisions) but the clicks now all show as zero.  :-/  Can the numbers be restored?  Also: is it time for a new ad cycle?

Comment: ... shouldn't the [meta-tag:community-ads] tag be moderator-only?

Comment: @HostileFork, the ads actually seemed to have stopped running, too, that's why the numbers are all zero.

Comment: There's a date for 2H 2014 to launch?

Comment: @cvsguimaraes Yeah. Let's make it today, shall we?

Comment: No objection from me, but it will take me some time to prepare my campaigns anyway :)

Answer (score 106):

[image: StackEdit]

Comment: Are you asking for programming and/or development help or is this just an ad for your product? The link/image needs to make it clear.

Comment: Both, like the other ads I guess. NOTE: StackEdit is not a product but an open source project. https://stackedit.io is a show case, which is more eloquent than https://github.com/benweet/stackedit.

Comment: It's an open source product that shows no indication you are asking for development help. You should instead link to the README or the CONTRIBUTING file which suggests ways to help.

Comment: Added a border per our guidelines.

Comment: @random is it personal? Most of the other ads images have no such indication. And other links are usage/installation pages not contributing files.

Comment: There are comments left on others asking them to clarify where it's not evident. Others have also been deleted because they make no mention.

Comment: @random I don't see any comment from you about NGINX and others. They are also not pointing to a development repo but to a usage/installation page.

Comment: Thanks, missed the NGINX one. The other one is negative scoring currently.

Answer (score 87):

[image: Take control of your ENTIRE programming stack!]

Comment: Full stack - and according to your diagram, down to the hardware level.  So, will I eventually be able to recompile both for an OS and directly for hardware like Verilog?

Comment: @HostileFork Does Red plan to support iOS as a compilation target?

Comment: Isn't this a GC based language?

Comment: For questions about Red, the current best place to go is the [Red chat rooms on gitter.im](https://gitter.im/red/red).  But summary: (1) "Full stack" in this case really is more geared to say IL/assembly, though you could do a dialect like verilog or VHDL.  (2) Red plans to support iOS but Android is the first mobile market being supported.  (3) Red is GC-based like Rebol, but Red/System is more C-like and if you're going to involve the GC you'd have to invoke it explicitly.

Answer (score 55):

[image: Let's build an OPEN SOURCE MACHINE LEARNING SERVER - http://prediction.io]

Comment: No most popular SO language hash tag on banner :(

Comment: @Den oops, good point! Sorry I guess I thought if I typed #c# the world might have exploded. We do now have [#C/.Net SDK](http://docs.prediction.io/current/contribution/projects.html) thanks to [Themos Piperakis](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1113958/themos-piperakis)

Answer (score 44):

[image: Code Review Stack Exchange. Tough questions, smart answers.]

Comment: Always choosing the best local solution doe not bring you to have the best global solution. It rarely does in fact ;D. Anyway, I like this one

Comment: I don't think python likes smart quotes, also, you should be using hashes for commenting. Triple quotes are meant for [documentation purposes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/675448/1578604). But then again, it might be that that was the intended message?

Comment: @Jerry haha there's more language abuse (`</semi-sarcasm>`) to be reviewed [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python)! This post is the result of a little meta-contest we had on CR - you may want to ask the author of the [original ad post](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1791/23788), I'm just the messenger (I mostly review C# code)!

Comment: @retailcoder Ohh, someone already pointed it out there, so all's good I guess. And sorry, I didn't know that one was not the original one ^^; And woot for C# :)

Comment: @Jerry The triple-quotes *are* being used correctly since that is a docstring. See [PEP257](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) for more details.

Comment: @NewWorld Is that really a documentation string now? It's more a comment to me.

Comment: @Jerry Well it's describing what the function does. That's what goes in the first line of a function/method's docstring.

Comment: Jerry and NewWorld, it seems that you would both make excellent code reviewers.

Comment: Why some weird language and the most popular SO language?

Answer (score 25):

[image: BXR.SU — Super User's BSD Cross Reference — BSD Source Code Search Engine over FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD and DragonFly BSD kernel and userland source trees, based on OpenGrok, powered by nginx and regular expressions]

Comment: Where on the linked page is this asking for development help?

Comment: @random, type `todo` or `fixme` into the search field.  http://bxr.su/search?q=todo+OR+fixme+OR+XXX

Comment: How are people supposed to get that? Why not make that the link?

Comment: Border added because borders enhance the flavor of ads (also: per our guidelines)

Comment: First time I clicked an add and found myself clueless. If this is not intentional, please add some explanatory text.

Comment: BSD Unix is not for the feint of heart. if you're put off by the landing page, maybe this is not for you.

Comment: I love this ad!  It looks like a spam ad for virus protection malware, but it's recruiting OS hackers!

Comment: A bug tracker is a strange place to link to.  You may want to consider a landing page describing how to get started, where to commit to, style guidelines, etc.  You can then link to the bug tracker from that landing page when folks are ready to actually do something.

Comment: Man this ad would remind me of why BSD is dying. Looks old and outdated.

Comment: I ouldn't stop laught at this one. I didn't knew this joke yet persists!

Comment: so it's basically a joke?

Answer (score 22):

[image: Join the Stratosphere.eu Team]

Comment: Since this is the first time we're participating the open source ads, I'm very happy about feedback and suggestions (especially if someone votes us down)

Comment: I would recommend removing the hashtags. Some people (well, me, at least) have a natural negative reaction to inline usage of this sort. This goes doubly when it's an image, where the tag doesn't actually contribute to rankings as it would in text.

Answer (score 21):

[image: PyBuilder]

Comment: Borderified for your enjoyment (and per our guidelines)

Comment: That is a terrible font.

Comment: Or just terrible hinting. Either way, horrible to read.

Answer (score 20):

[image: AnkiDroid: Flashcards for Android]

Comment: I love Anki! It helped me when I moved to Japan in 2009, and I never knew it was open source until now. Why does it link to the Play Store, though? It makes it seem more like an ad for *consumers*, not *developers*. Maybe it should link to somewhere on the [Google Code page](https://code.google.com/p/ankidroid/wiki/Contribution) instead?

Comment: @Geobits: Fixed, thanks for the feedback! In addition, here is the Play Store URL for the majority who don't know yet what AnkiDroid looks like: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ichi2.anki

Answer (score 19):

[image: Zyan Drench, a retro-style game for Android with WiFi support]

Comment: UX advice: shorten the bottom section to only include your call to action (i.e. "Help port it to...").

Comment: That's a big QR taking up a big chunk of the space. Couldn't a smaller one be made using a shorter URL?

Comment: Thanks for your helpful tips! I'm going to repaint this banner soon anyway.

Answer (score 15):

[image: droidQuery: The Android port of jQuery]

Comment: I'd appreciate seeing the whole name here - the 'd' looks like it's merged with the 'Q', which is technically not correct by the name of the library. Also, since it's obscured, I wouldn't have known what this said until I hovered over it.

Comment: @trojansdestroy I will improve the logo. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Borderified for maximum enjoyment (and per our guidelines)

Comment: This ad looks really good.

Comment: The project seems technically questionable to me.  jQuery is very DOM-centric; the Android UI (unless you've got a WebView based app a la PhoneGap) is much closer to Swing than HTML.  It's hard to see how this isn't a "square peg in a round hole" kind of deal.  Anyhow, with respect to the ad itself it feels a bit cluttered.  I think the bolded comment should be the first line, and it would help if the indentation were more consistent.  Probably one code snippet is sufficient, and then the "droidQuery" bit could be moved up above the Android logo.

Comment: @aroth thanks for the feedback. I plan to update the image soon. You can think of *droidQuery* more in terms of an analogy than thinking of the *jQuery* technical aspect: __droidQuery is to Android development as jQuery is to web development__. *droidQuery* does not work with a DOM, but rather the Android layout. Additionally, RESTful AsyncTasks are made easy with Ajax-like Syntax, and animation are made easy with CSS-like syntax - to name some of the main features.

Comment: @Trojan what is your opinion on the redesign?

Comment: @Phil Visually, much better! It's concise and easy on the eyes. As you've said, it's not technically "jQuery *for* Android", but an analog using Java. You should communicate that this project isn't developing jQuery (I'm not sure how, unfortunately).

Comment: @Trojan would something like "The Port of jQuery to Java Android" be better than "jQuery for Android", or would it be too verbose?

Comment: @Phil it's a little verbose. I'm not sure it's entirely necessary, but it's a difficult task to describe this project correctly while being concise

Answer (score 15):

[image: Cascade Framework - Putting back the C in CSS]

Answer (score 11):

[image: New PHP framework with content editor - ImpressPages 4.0]

Comment: This project is not meant for free advertisement, but to help open source projects **recruit developers**.

Comment: ImpressPages is an open-source project where every developer is welcome to contribute at GitHub by submitting their personal code, plugins, etc.

Comment: Then link to the github project, not to the page that only promotes the product. (See the other posts here as well)

Comment: You should probably not use the term "Lightweight MVC engine". It's a meaningless term to begin with. MVC is a very specific architectural pattern - the term "MVC engine" has no meaning, that's like "Front Controller Engine" - it's meaningless to put "pattern name - engine". On top of it, your project does not even use MVC architecture to begin with...

Answer (score 6):

[image: Concourse: Looking for Java developers]
<sub>(source: [cinchapi.org](http://cinchapi.org/concourse/stack-overflow-add.png))</sub>

Comment: *"schemaless"* is kind of a hard word to parse, it scans like "shameless".  :-)  You might consider something like *"schema-free"* or *"schema-neutral"*.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Subview.js - Views done right!]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Zyan Communication Framework]

Comment: However, your new image lacks the key point of "Looking for Contributors" - the current image is just an advertisement and does not **solicit participation and contribution**.

Answer (score 5):

[image: popscript.js: A new way of creating modals and tooltips]

Answer (score 1):

[image: mdoc.su — short manual page URLs, a deterministic URL shortener for BSD manual pages, written in nginx.conf]

Comment: Whoa, sorry people were so hard on your ad!  +1 for sincerity and trying to put forth a grassroots one-person effort.  But I don't personally think I would use it, and it's a bit "noisy".  The graphics don't really support the message.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Database Deployment Manager needs C++ / Qt programmers]

Answer (score -6):

[image: EasyDevop]

Comment: You want a border? I'LL GIVE YOU A BORDER! (border added per our guidelines)

Comment: You should make clear how you want people to help with this. At least in the README

Comment: is it meant to say "easy devop"?

Comment: @Qwertie it's not a typo, the creator also [got account on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3114169/easydevop) so the one here is either somebody working on the project as well, or a sock.

Comment: What is it? What problems does it solve?