# Did open-source ads stop running?

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, open-source-advertising

It appears that the open-source ads, [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 1H 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251196/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2014), have stopped running since the moveout last week.

If you look at the supposed stats, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/251196, there's zero clicks per day for all of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, they stopped running for a bit. The way these work involves hooking up the specific threads that they're run on. Each time we cycle I give Nick Craver a big list of every question across the network for these, and he hooks them all up.

When we moved MSE out of here, the thread got caught in all of the things and ended up doing the migration shuffle. Which we didn't then go back and hook it back up.

This should be fixed now.

Comment: While you're at it, you should give the [meta-tag:community-ads] tag its red glow back.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it!  Also, as a side-effect of the move, all ads now have the "Clicks per day" reset, so, we can have a level measurement of how effective each ad is.

Comment: @cnst Still winning! *(clickwise, though personally perhaps more generally in the Charlie Sheen sense)*.  Yet even so, at a reported 16.06 clicks per day, it may well be time for a new ad cycle--either the impression counts are really low, or the audience is bored.  *(P.S. If anyone wants me to help design other FOSS graphics, get in touch.)*