# Why is the click-rate way down on open source advertisements?

Tags: support, open-source-advertising

I am wondering if they have stopped running ([it's happened before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251554/did-open-source-ads-stop-running))

- [Current click counts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/362773): clicks per day: **avg 0.07ish** (range: 0.01-> 0.17)
- [2018](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/349017)  clicks per day **avg 3ish**
- [2017H2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/327559) clicks per day avg **4ish**

So it seems like either:

- They have stopped running,
- or they are being shown 1/40 as often as before

  - Possible and reasonable, if Stack Overflow has sold out its excess advertising inventory space to paying customers.
- Or they are only 1/40 as appealing

  - though it seems unlikely to be true across the board.
- Alternatively, the thing which displays click counts has broken.

Comment: SO currently introduced https://www.selfserve-stackexchange.com/. So I think now there are more ads than previous. So those might take the open source ad space.

Comment: I wonder if this is related to [the site analytics bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308966/traffic-views-visits-isnt-correctly-registered-on-site-analytics-or-area-51) that shows significantly fewer visitors than the true counts?