# Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 2H 2014

Tags: discussion, community-ads, open-source-advertising

It is now June 2014 and thus a new edition of our Free Vote-Based Advertising for Open Source Projects. We are clearing the leaderboards for the second half of 2014.

Here is your chance to create a [Free Vote-Based Advertisement for an Open Source Project](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/). Create a graphical ad for an open source programming project and post it as an answer to this question (in the right format), and it will feed live remnant ads on Stack Overflow.

### Ad Requirements

It must be an advertisement **soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code**. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source. It's for finding programmers who will help contribute code or other programmery things (documentation, code review, bug fixes, etc.).

Your ad should be an original creation which has not previously appeared on Stack Overflow. Please do not resubmit entries that have appeared as ads on Stack Overflow in previous periods.

In order to work, the answers you post to this question **must** conform to the following rules.

### Answer Template

```
[![alternative text if image is not displayed][1]][2]
    
  [1]: http://image-url
  [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to add any commentary, keep it in the comments.

### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 pixels by 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- Must have a 1px border if (part of) the background is white

The output, which ultimately will be served in an ad slot on Stack Overflow, can be previewed by clicking through to this URL:

http://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/220x250

### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be served up by that URL and shown on Stack Overflow. You can see all the ads that currently make the threshold and meet our criteria on this page:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/260377

**Note:** *As with previous [iterations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251196/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2014) of this program, if your ad has already appeared in a previous cycle, it is not eligible to be run in this cycle.*

Comment: <joke>May the best scantily clad man/woman win!</joke>

Comment: Thank you! I'll start working on this tomorrow!

Comment: Random suggestion - in the answers, move the alternative text to mouse-over text, so people can see that without needing to edit the answer. Or is there a reason to not do that?

Comment: Why was the django ad deleted ? It looked fine...

Comment: @dystroy The owner chose to delete it.

Comment: The community ad system is working properly?! I haven't seem any of these ads in SO pages yet, also the [number of clicks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/260377) are more compatible with the number of views in this question than SO's daily pageviews.

Comment: @cvsguimaraes Everything looks green on our end, it's all been hooked up since I posted this thread.

Comment: I'm not intending to be rude, but the chances of community ads being selected for sidebar are like 0.1%?

Comment: In a workplace where imgur images are filtered, this was initially a *very* confusing set of answers.  May also explain @cvsguimaraes issue?

Comment: @ruffin I've already asked other peeps, I'm not aware of anyone that saw those ads anywhere than in this post...

Comment: @cvs I'll have another check on this.

Comment: This is freaking incredible. I absolutely LOVE SO for implementing this. I think this will facilitate a lot more contribution to Open source projects and hopefully a lot more questions on SO relating to helping build them :)

Answer (score 104):

[image: Help us to maintain a new concept in PHP frameworks!]

Comment: This framework is setup as the inventor of php had in mind.

Comment: In which sense did he fail? I am not talking about the framework it self, but how it is setup / build. A C program which can be used trough php, is what i am talking about.

Comment: Phalcon is great option for programmers and companies that want to deliver fast and lightweight applications. In our softwarehouse we were wondering for the long time what to use as a base for our CMF. In the end Phalcon has won with SF2 and Zend2. That was the perfect choice :)

Comment: PHP Framework that "Think different".

Comment: Phalcon is the future

Answer (score 88):

[image: Miaou is a friendly chat. Help us improve it !]

Comment: Definitely this! This project could really use more contributers. Very cool project.

Comment: looks so cheesy! Defenitely deserves more votes

Comment: Sadly not related to MeowMeowBeenz..

Comment: One of the best chat platforms out there. +10.

Comment: I was once stranded in a desert island with no way of communicating with the outside world. Wandering around aimlessly for days, I lost consciousness. In my dream, a clowder came to me, licked my wounds and gave me nourishment. They then gave me a direct connection to Miaou and that's how I was saved.

Comment: This ad will mean absolutely nothing to someone who hasn't heard of it. Shouldn't you add a line or two including what it is and what technologies it uses?

Comment: If zirak's comment wasn't clear enough, *Miaou* is an extensible chat server. It's developed in JavaScript, node.js, PostgreSQL, socket.IO, WebRTC.

Comment: @Dukeling if you look at the rules, the answer must have only the image and a link. If you follow the link, you'll see all the answers to your questions :)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine That doesn't mean the image itself just has to contain 3 words. Look at some answers from [the previous one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251196/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2014?lq=1), and even [the other answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260540/1711796) - there's a lot of information there.

Comment: Brilliant advertising. I just ***had*** to click on this to figure out what the hell it was :) Kinda hoped in the back of my mind it had something to do with Schrödinger's cat.

Comment: It might also be said that Miaou is mostly a platform to play Tribo ;)

Comment: Show your support for Miaou and please keep comment votes orderly!

Comment: Just like this!

Comment: Miaou + Tribo = <3

Comment: Vote for Miaou right meow.

Comment: 72 votes in two days?  Guess it pays to have connections.  :-/  I'm all for being a bit enigmatic with an ad, but could the red part at least be a square and could it have some margins?  Suggestion: http://i.stack.imgur.com/aNQ8t.png

Comment: Not 72 : 90 votes (including 9 downvotes). But you know Miaou has  more than 81 users.

Comment: @HostileFork It's advertising, shameless plugs get results ;-)

Comment: I saw the cat icon and looked at the project. Upvoted. Looks fun. Meow.

Answer (score 20):

[image: Open your Virtual Datacenter]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Ta4j: technical analysis for Java]

Comment: Please anti-alias the text!

Comment: This is a quite nice project !

Answer (score 7):

[image: SocketCluster - Scalable Node.js]

Comment: That logo is more intricate *and* fitting than it may appear at a first glance! The blue bar at the bottom could be a bit slimmer. Perhaps putting the name at the top would vertically center the logo a bit better,

Comment: As per the guidelines, the advertisements are supposed to **solicit the participation and contribution of programmers**. You should try modifying the image to indicate that you want help, not make it look like you're just advertising a product. As well, images with a white background must have a border.

Comment: I made the required changes.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Lightning quick JSON deserialization for iOS & OS X]

Comment: As per the guidelines, the advertisements are supposed to **solicit the participation and contribution of programmers**. You should try modifying the image to indicate that you want help, not make it look like you're just advertising a product.

Comment: I'll get working on that ASAP.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Contribute on Github]

Comment: I like the project better than the other current contender (+1), but if you can take some constructive criticism, your ad needs some work.  Image is everything in an ad to get clicks. Maybe octokitty holding a dollar sign. :) Just a thought.  Good luck.

Comment: @paqogomez I appreciate constructive criticism and thanks for the idea. Let me see what I can do. This is my attempt considering I am not a graphics designer but will try another image. If I change the image does it reset the upvotes?

Comment: @EncorePTL it does not.

Comment: @paqogomez Updated ad. What do you think of this?

Comment: Much nicer! :) .

Comment: This new image is much much better. Props.

Comment: +1 This project looks really cool! This seems like just what swift needs right now.

Comment: I'm not sure using [stolen art](http://manichsayshi.com/) is good for the project's reputation.

Comment: In which areas of your code do you need contributions?

Comment: Fixing cocoa pod or a way to import the library easily into an Xcode project. Adding more chaining methods. Adding better documentation and recreate another site with better ways to find and search docs. Optimizations to existing methods if they aren't already. Add example iOS or Test project using imported library.

Comment: *"Must have a 1px border if (part of) the background is white"*

Comment: Added the border.

Answer (score 5):

[image: CHEAT]

Comment: As per the guidelines, the advertisements are supposed to **solicit the participation and contribution of programmers**. You should try modifying the image to indicate that you want help, not make it look like you're just advertising a product.

Comment: That should do.

Answer (score 5):

[image: ASNE Simple Android Social Networks integration]

Comment: Cool project. Bad name. I'm not even sure why an "E" is used when "integration" starts with an "i".

Answer (score 3):

[image: vertx.io]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Comment: As per the guidelines, the advertisements are supposed to solicit the participation and contribution of programmers. You should try modifying the image to indicate that you want help, not make it look like you're just advertising a product.

Answer (score 0):

[image: A smart and nice Twitter client on terminal]

Comment: As per the guidelines, the advertisements are supposed to **solicit the participation and contribution of programmers**. You should try modifying the image to indicate that you want help, not make it look like you're just advertising a product.

Comment: I will modify asap

Answer (score -3):

[image: Zapata - An Automatic Automated Test Writer]

Comment: As per the guidelines, the advertisements are supposed to solicit the participation and contribution of programmers. You should try modifying the image to indicate that you want help, not make it look like you're just advertising a product.