# Is there a way for me to make announcements on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

I created some videos for PayPal's REST API and a C# Code First ASP.NET MVC 5 demo application, all of them free. The [ASP.NET Forums](http://forums.asp.net/) has a place for announcements, and so does LinkedIn.

I searched Stack Overflow for such an option, but didn't find anything.

Does Stack Overflow have, or intend to have, something like the ASP.NET Forums and LinkedIn announcement facilities?

Stack Overflow Careers 2.0 has job announcements and Stack Overflow itself has only questions.

I'm hoping such a facility exists at Stack Overflow, but I'm guessing that it doesn't.

Comment: No is the answer,  but kudos for asking,  and recognizing that questions/answers aren't the right way.

Comment: +1 for asking before trying to do so. It would quickly turn into a -1 if this was a feature request. :-) There are dozens of sites where an announcement would be appropriate, but definitely not here.

Comment: If the things he mentioned are relevant to particular questions, is there any problem with adding comments with links?

Comment: Seems like you found a way :)

Comment: You could always [buy an ad](http://stackexchange.com/mediakit).

Comment: i appreciate the feedback from everyone; although not perfect, the @Andrew Barber/@Rapptx suggestion is a decent idea; i've already updated my SO profile; FWIW, just because other sites have an announcements facility doesn't necessarily mean that anyone reads them any more often that someone might view my SO profile.

Comment: @gerryLowry You *might* be surprised. People interested in/impressed by your content may tend to go to your profile, and some relevant stuff could very well get hit there. No; it's certainly not something "meant" for promotion, but that's also not the purpose of the site.

Comment: @AndrewBarber yes, there's a very fine line between _sharing_ and blatant self promotion; i _hope_ to be surprised _in a good way_.

Comment: You could always ask a question on Meta about it ;)

Comment: You could ask about the English grammar used in the video with a choice title with c# and paypal keywords (for example) on another stack exchange site and let the related questions take care of the rest? (not a serious answer!)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Stack Overflow doesn't have such a facility because it's not a forum, but rather a site to answer and ask questions. Adding a facility to have user announcements is too much noise for a Q&A site.

If you really want to showcase some of the stuff you've done, there's an area in your profile for exactly that called "About Me". Interested users could click your profile and then view your accomplishments or self-announcements there.

[image: About Me]

It looks like you've already utilized that space with some information about yourself, but this is another possible use for it.

Comment: Could you type louder?  I can't hear over the noise. .. ;)

Comment: Oh,  also maybe add that one could put whatever they wanted in the about area of their profile.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Good idea. I've added it in my post

Comment: -1: no hand-drawn circle. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters it probably was hand-drawn. Rapptz is just that good.

Comment: @Trojan: There is no such thing as a "good" hand-drawn circle.

Comment: @BoltClock [really?](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=eAhfZUZiwSE) :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'll take the blame since I added the screenshot, but [I have a stance on that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268339/how-to-handle-edits-you-think-shouldnt-have-been-made#comment76617_268340).

Answer (score 17):

Although not directly related to your situation I think the [Free Vote-Based Advertising for Open Source Projects](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/) is highly related this question.
They are not announcements but it is probably a better way to promote a project.

If you are running an Open Source project and are in need of programmer assistance you can promote it by submitting your advert as an answer to [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260377/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2014).

The adverts with over 6 votes are then displayed as an advert in the sidebar on Stack Overflow (on a rotation).

Comment: @psubsee2003 I've edited my answer to avoid confusing around your point. Further details about the program can be read in the links I provided.

Comment: thanks, I think that should satisfy my concerns