# Is Open Source Advertising working as intended?

Tags: discussion, advertising, open-source-advertising

I'm the project leader of one of the most upvoted projects [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260377/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2014) (which one isn't very important as my question is about the program, not my project).

I made two observations :

- no one ever came through the ad to contribute (hopefully I have other helpers) even while the ad sends to a serious page listing the points on which I most want help
- almost all other "advertisers" first came with an ad for their product and it's only after the rules were remembered they mentioned contributions

It looks like those ads are really ads for products and not ads for contribution, both in the eye of the advertisers and in the one of the users.

So I'd like to hear from other project leaders (especially of past years) about whether it seemed to work as intended for them, and possibly launch a discussion about what should be done (do they look too much like standard money-making ads ?).

Comment: I was slightly surprised when I heard of "Open Source Advertising".  It really should be better controlled to only allow open source work that isn't suggesting that people need to use it, but for them to contribute to it.

Comment: Isn't it still better than nothing ? While you may not get as much contributors as you hoped for, you still get free advertising for your project which makes it popular (more users) and will indirectly give you more contribution in the future (more users = more incentive to contribute to a frequently used project rather than some unknown project that only two people use).

Comment: @AndréDaniel I'm not complaining, I'm **1)** reporting my experience **2)** trying to discuss if we could improve that, with a focus on experienced developers happy to contribute (as they do on SO) rather than on customers being sold open-source products. I have no real solution right now, I'm opening the debate. And I'm really curious regarding how it turned for other ads.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I never said you were complaining.

Answer (score 12):

I think this isn't a matter of "Open Source Ads" vs "Products Ads", after all advertising works the same for products, services, open source, free or closed, looking for contributors or attracting potential customers/users.

I've checked the link you provided and also read all your `helpus` copy. In just a few seconds I found your project really interesting so I put it in my favorites. However, after reading the list of things you'd like to be done, I noticed some points that at least for me don't encourage me to go further.

First of all your copy seems to miss the target, you want to attract developers and designers but neither of them are being addressed anywhere in your copy.

Your list of tasks is pretty vague, you could improve it so it can let other developers or designers know in a glimpse what is already working, how could it be improved, what needs to be done and the expertise needed to contribute to the task.

Put a project roadmap so people can easily check what has been done and what needs to be done. Also it would be great to know all the details in case you want to be involved in the project, without the need to log into a chatroom all day long to wait for main developers to show and start talking.

> You've to make it as easier as possible to contribute, otherwise
>   people will just pass.

The idea behind advertising is to convince people they will obtain rewards in exchange for their precious time (it can be anything, from an object to the pure satisfaction of helping out). You're giving nothing, not even the simplicity of contributing because you forgot to put days and hours if anyone wanted to log into your chatroom to ask you what they have to do in order for them to be able to help you with your project.

You want developers? Ask them to help, need designers tell them how they could improve your project. Want people to help? Explain them why they should care. Give them all easy steps to follow and I'm pretty sure you'll see better results.

> **tl;dr**
>
> - Address your target audience: web developers, web designers
> - Put a project roadmap explaining what has been done, work in progress, what needs to be done
> - Better information, explain how can people contribute without the
>     need to log into a chatroom
> - List the rules people involved in the project must
>     follow
> - Show people why they should care, got testimonials from current
>     users? put them in your page and show the world how improving Miaou
>     could positively impact on others