# Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 1H 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads, open-source-advertising

It is now January 2015, or pretty much on the boundary of it, and thus a new edition of our Free Vote-Based Advertising for Open Source Projects. We are clearing the leaderboards for the beginning of 2015

Here is your chance to create a [Free Vote-Based Advertisement for an Open Source Project](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/). Create a graphical ad for an open source programming project and post it as an answer to this question (in the right format), and it will feed live remnant ads on Stack Overflow.

### Ad Requirements

It must be an advertisement **soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code**. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source. It's for finding programmers who will help contribute code or other programmery things (documentation, code review, bug fixes, etc.).

Your ad should be an original creation which has not previously appeared on Stack Overflow. Please do not resubmit entries that have appeared as ads on Stack Overflow in previous periods.

In order to work, the answers you post to this question **must** conform to the following rules.

### Answer Template

```
[![alternative text if image is not displayed][1]][2]
    
  [1]: http://image-url
  [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to add any commentary, keep it in the comments.

### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 pixels by 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- Must have a 1px border if (part of) the background is white

The output, which ultimately will be served in an ad slot on Stack Overflow, can be previewed by clicking through to this URL:

http://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/220x250

### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be served up by that URL and shown on Stack Overflow. You can see all the ads that currently make the threshold and meet our criteria on this page:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/281524

**Note:** *As with previous [iterations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260377/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2014) of this program, if your ad has already appeared in a previous cycle, it is not eligible to be run in this cycle.*

Comment: Can I ask why you don't accept JPG?  Just curious.

Comment: @asteri, probably because jpg is a lossy format not intended for crisp logos on the web and Stack Overflow and quality standards to maintain on things promoted over their site.

Comment: @KyleMit Probably this, but for certain imagery, given the 150KB file size limit, JPG will yield better results. Also, if crisp logos are what you want, [why not ask for high density sizes](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10168/community-promotion-ads-2015#comment29277_10170)?

Comment: Question, wrt the statement "As with previous iterations of this program, if your ad has already appeared in a previous cycle, it is not eligible to be run in this cycle." - Does this prohibit just reusing the same ad, or the project itself? In other words, if the previous iteration had an ad for project X, can this iteration have a different ad for the same project?

Comment: The ad itself, @Mureinik

Comment: @GraceNote awesome, thanks!

Comment: @animuson, according to Grace Note's comment above, the restriction is on the ad, not the project - can you clarify please?

Comment: @GraceNote: since, according to Kevin Brown's comment to [this proposal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281766/724361), the adverts aren't yet live (which seems to superficially contradict the stats, but they may be skewed by other processes), can you clarify **when do they go live**?

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato We just had a fix to get them all live today. Sorry 'bout the delay.

Comment: @GraceNote: no need to apologize, perhaps my bolding of the question for readability came out wrong ;).

Comment: On some other sites people are posting ads double the size, citing retina/etc. Is it OK to do the same here, or is there a specific reason why all 18 answers use the normal size?

Comment: Does an ad for a community-run conference around an Open Source project work within the rules?  I know at least one conference has done this, but I want to make sure I'm not falling afoul of the rules before I post mine.  Thanks!

Comment: @gorthx DEFINITELY within the rules. When we started this program, I actually envisioned the community-based advertising (really a community "bulletin board") being used more for these types of announcements/activities of interest to the community rather than using it for traditional product advertisements (and directing people to other sites) that we are seeing on many sites.

Comment: @RobertCartaino thank you!

Comment: @GraceNote Was looking for this post and had some trouble, posted about [the tag division issue on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302893/211160).  Also...seems a new iteration is due...

Comment: Where's the 2H edition?

Comment: @GraceNote yeah good question

Answer (score 57):

[image: Codebrag - an open source code review tool, by developers, for developers, with a non-blocking code review workflow, centralized discussion, smart email notifications, a clear to-review list, and more.]

Comment: _Full disclosure:_ I work for the company that has created the tool. The project has been open sourced some time ago, and we're eager to see the community's input.

Comment: The logo is pretty cool but the text has way too much emphasis: it's so fat and wide, it's crawling up on the edges. Making the font smaller could help, but I'd try a slightly less bold font and use the same size and spacing.

Comment: @Jongware: that's because, while the logo was created by a dedicated graphic artist, the banner was assembled by well... me. I'm refraining for editing it, since a) I feel it would be somewhat unfair at this point, b) doesn't seem to be SOP, by looking over the previous OSA-S editions. However, thanks for the feedback, you're right that it's a bit too crowded.

Comment: "Help us in improving" -> "Help us improve" would be shorter and look a bit less crowded, I believe.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato Here is a copy of it with the first line shortened: http://i.imgur.com/faYXwI4.png It doesn't look as crowded.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul , Gunther : thank you for your efforts. I was about to replace it myself, but you've beaten me to it.

Answer (score 52):

[image: Help us improve ChatterBot: a machine learning, conversational dialog engine.]

Answer (score 50):

[image: Django REST framework: A powerful and flexible toolkit that makes it easy to build Web APIs.]

Answer (score 48):

[image: rOpenSci - Join Us!]

Answer (score 31):

[image: F-Droid: Certified open source Android apps]

Comment: Many "open source" apps found in the wild require removing Google Analytics, ad SDKs and other non-free parts, so dev contributors are needed, it is not strictly about compiling only. If there is a good way to convey that, please let me know, thanks :-)

Comment: @KevinBrown: F-Droid is looking for volunteers to write actual source code, yes. Most apps are not compilable directly, often parts of the source code have to be rewritten to be truly open source.

Comment: @KevinBrown But but... I was so proud of my use of the "X all the Y" meme... OK I will find a way to indicate that developers are needed :-)

Comment: Just add a the word "contribute", I think it will be OK? @KevinBrown

Comment: @KevinBrown: How is it now? :-)

Comment: F-Droid rocks!   +1

Answer (score 26):

[image: NOGAPPS: Help develop an Open Source replacement for Google Play Services]

Comment: This is stupid. Why did I got completely barraged with ads when I tried to look at YOUR ad? Two popups, top banner, several side bar -- no thank you.

Comment: @djechlin: Sorry for the non-optimal experience, could you please [create a new question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) detailing what you saw and how it could be improved? Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 25):

[image: Do science with Python. Pathomx: the workflow-based data analysis tool.]

Answer (score 24):

[image: AnkiDroid flashcards: Open source Android app looking for volunteers]

Answer (score 22):

[image: Free. Open Source. Powerful. Taiga is a project management platform for startups and agile developers & designers who want a simple, beautiful tool that makes work truly enjoyable.]

Comment: Official docker support would be nice, please

Comment: This is a community docker, could it work for you? > https://github.com/ipedrazas/taiga-docker

Comment: Yeah setting it up gave me a headache. Thanks anyway (y)

Answer (score 21):

[image: Replicant: Develop open source drivers for Android]

Answer (score 20):

[image: FreeIPA: Integrated Identity Management]

Answer (score 20):

[image: Help us build the future of real-time messaging]

Answer (score 19):

[image: Open LaTeX Studio project]

Answer (score 16):

[image: Geppetto: Open Simulation Platform]

Comment: Should that be "Help us _simulate_ life."?

Comment: Btw, a live deployment is available here https://live.geppetto.org/ documentation can be found here http://docs.geppetto.org. Any feedback is welcome!

Comment: All the past, present and future tasks can be found here https://waffle.io/openworm/org.geppetto, they are GitHub issues so anyone with a GitHub account can comment, add new ones, etc. Again, any feedback is welcome, thanks!

Comment: Pretty cool banner :)

Comment: i dont think so :)

Answer (score 15):

[image: ACRA: Crash reporting for Android. All open source, web UI, all Android versions]

Comment: The red no symbol is very reminiscent of ads designed to catch your eye. These are the sort of ads that make me want to turn back on ublock.

Comment: @PeadarDoyle: It is the official logo of this project. What colour would you suggest? If you have an HTML code I will try.

Comment: this needs redesigned for the new wider sidebar

Comment: @DanielA.White: I believe the "*if your ad has already appeared in a previous cycle, it is not eligible to be run in this cycle*" rule prevents me from re-running this one.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Pylease - versioning and release management for Python]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Siminov Framework]

Comment: The dots in the background are a nice touch - different than the usual gray background or gradient! - but they could be ever so slightly less dark. And remove them under "Contribute". The text might be a bit larger, there is enough space around it.

Comment: Thanks Jongware and Kevin Brown for your valuable feedback, we have done the required changes.

Comment: The border is messed by antialiasing. Better generate from your vector software and only then add the border with a bitmap editor.

Comment: Maybe "Platforms" is not really needed?

Answer (score 7):

[image: Services+]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Quack - An smart way to reuse your git repository modules]

Answer (score 5):

[image: CmisSync: Dropbox-like sync for Alfresco, SharePoint, ECM]

Answer (score 3):

[image: NemakiWare: NoSQL, CMIS-compliant Enterprise Content Management server]

Comment: I mean *"join"* as *"join the community of developers who make NemakiWare"*. Is it explicit enough, or should I reword?

Answer (score 3):

[image: Simple, block-based, lightweight library over CoreBluetooth. Will clean up your Core Bluetooth related code.]

Comment: Is the LGB* reference intentional?

Comment: you mean LGBT? :D of course no, it means LoggerBluetooth

Answer (score -2):

[image: help us improve deepstream.io, a realtime server for nodejs]

Comment: This doesn't appear to solicit contributors; you should link to a contribution help page in your clickthrough, rather than the marketing-focused homepage.

Answer (score -2):

[image: VRT - Realtime HTML5 Data Visualization Application]

Comment: 1) I don't see the part where you're "soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code." 2) You probably want to have some _text_ information about the project on the github page that this links to. Not everyone can/will view a youtube video to figure out what your project is all about.

Comment: Ok, I've done that now

Comment: The link is good now, but the ad itself doesn't mention 'Contribute' or 'Collaborate'. See [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281678/5240004) for what I mean.

Comment: what about now? does it say 'Contribute' or 'Collaborate' now?

Answer (score -2):

[image: Eclipse plugins for the creation of graphical user interfaces that are based on trees.]

Answer (score -3):

[image: Trip Express: An online bus and airline booking management system.]

Comment: This image fails the "must be an advertisement soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers" requirement

Answer (score -3):

[image: C++11 Asynchronous RESTful Framework]

Comment: Why the down votes?

Comment: This ad didn't get to run in the last set, but I'd recommend resizing this (check the new guidelines), adding the required 1px border, and [posting it for the new set of ads](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314722/359284).

Answer (score -6):

[image: rspamd spam filtering system]

Comment: Link destination is how to contribute page.

Comment: The requirement isn't "you must have a page soliciting programmer involvement".  The **advertisement** itself must do so.

Comment: Just a heads up, the dimensions of the image changed when you added the "collaborate" text. It's now 200x220 instead of 220x250.

Answer (score -8):

[image: i3DML.org - Create interactive 3D worlds with XML and JavaScript !]

Comment: This image fails the "must be an advertisement soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers" requirement.

Answer (score -11):

[image: ScrollerJS -- A light weight number scroller module to be embedded in your web apps]

Comment: This image fails the "must be an advertisement soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers" requirement.

Answer (score -22):

This is the pdf report plugin library written for testng/selenium, this listener will generate the pdf report on testcases execution, its very simple to configure no need to write any code.[pdfngreport](https://github.com/uttesh/pdfngreport)

Comment: Please: 1) Include the name of the project 2) Show the image undistorted 3) Say you are looking for developers. Cheers!

Comment: Much better but it is still distorted... In your image editor, whenever you resize something press CTRL (or SHIFT maybe) so that vertical/horizontal scale is preserved.

Comment: It's usually best not to have any exclamation marks at all, but if you must use them, just use one.