# Migrate stray programming-related "community-ad" posts to Stack Overflow

Tags: support, retag-request, mso-mse-split, open-source-advertising

The most current open-source advertising run for Stack Overflow is harder to find than it probably should be. I don't remember exactly what I typed but my search first landed me on [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23899/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects), which offered me a tag list of lots of discussion on the idea in general, which I scrolled down into and found this:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/new/community-ads

Following that makes it look like they've stopped, with the last one in 2013.  But because I know it hasn't stopped, and know about the meta/SO split, I can hunt down the current tag:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/new/community-ads

I'd suggest that the legacy SO-ad posts be migrated from meta.SE to SO, and that the meta post which discusses it links to the SO version of the tag (listing newest first, so that it can stay up to date).  If people want to find the discussion, perhaps each ad post could guide people to what tag to use and where to post about it.

I'm not sure how many of the open-source-advertising tagged  posts are actually general commentary on the community ad process, though many of them likely are.

---

The [1H 2015 ad post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281524/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2015?rq=1) is rather old and it's almost end-of-year. It would be nice if a new ad cycle were to get started at least for 2016!