# Can the old Open Source Advertising posts be updated?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, help-center, open-source-advertising

Hidden away right at the end of the [What kind of behaviour is expected of users?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) is a link to [Community Promotion Ads](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/). Skim-reading this Stack Overflow blog entry from May 2011 has lead me to create this post.

## Problem #1 - A Missing Image

The first problem is that one of the images is broken. Not a *huge* issue, but an issue nonetheless:

> [image: Screenshot of the missing image - it's like trying to take a picture of someone who isn't actually there]

That cute little <sub>[image: Chrome's Missing Image icon]</sub>, which Chrome is nice enough to display, links to https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/community-promotion-ad-meta-post.png, which in turn greets me with the following message (which goes on to tell me to make this post that I'm making right now (go me!)):

> ### Sorry, we can't find that page that you're looking for.

## Problem #2 - A Tedious Link Chain

The second and arguably more important issue is that the blog post goes on to include this:

> Incidentally, we [just reset the Free Vote-Based Advertising for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/93312/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2011), so get on over there to issue your new ad submissions and **vote for your favorite content!**

Clicking on that link will take you to a post on Stack Exchange's Meta titled [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 2H 2011 [duplicate]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/93312/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2011). Yes. A dirty duplicate! But that's not the main problem here. The main problem here is that this is **a chain of devilish, dirty duplicates**:

1. [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 2H 2011 [duplicate]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/93312/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2011)
2. ↳ [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 1H 2012 [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114442/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2012)
3. ↳ [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 2012 [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132988/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2012) <sub><sup><-- Oh no, this one's missing the "2H"!</sup></sub>
4. ↳ [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 1H 2013 [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162128/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2013)
5. ↳ [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 2H 2013 [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195823/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2013)
6. ↳ [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 1H 2014 [duplicate]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251196/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2014) <sub><sup><-- Wait, we're now on Stack Overflow's Meta?</sup></sub>
7. ↳ [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 2H 2014 [duplicate]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260377/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2014)
8. ↳ [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 1H 2015](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281524/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2015)

**WE'VE FINALLY REACHED THE EN... Wait what?**

## Problem #3 - [Where's 2015's 2H Edition](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281524/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2015#comment249076_281524)?!

The third and final problem here is that with 4 years of precious somewhere-between-April-and-September tradition, this year appears to be missing an [**Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 2H 2015 <del>[Duplicate]</del>**](http://philadams.co/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/tumbleweed.jpg).

## WHAT IS THIS MADNESS?

Can we...

1. Get that image working again.
2. Update *all* of those articles to be an article of the latest revision.
3. Create a 2H post for 2015 and go back to the previous step.

Comment: [Is there an echo in here?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302893/migrate-stray-programming-related-community-ad-posts-to-stackoverflow)  Good.  :-)  Yes, agreed!