# Strange Vote Button below my Tags

Tags: bug

Sometimes when I visit/reload the question page, I've got this empty white filed on the right side of the page. If I hover with the mouse over it, a vote button appears, which seems to be somehow missplaced.

It is happening in Chrome and Firefox. What is this and can this be removed?

[image]

Comment: You can like/dislike if you enjoy the new free space you got there! (You should see the ads there: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281524/3933332)

Comment: @MarounMaroun Yeah I thought the same but I have no Ad Blocker enabled.

Comment: @Rizier123 Haha ok nice.

Comment: Maybe the network you're on blocks ads?

Comment: @rene That might be. I didn't setup the network, but ads are displayed on other pages (not sure if all or just some). If someone tells me how, I could test it.

Comment: if you open the dev console of Chrome you can see if you have any failing network call