# Will there be an Open Source Advertising in 2016?

Tags: support, open-source-advertising

Last year there was [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 1H 2015](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281524/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2015) but not a second half so I’m wondering whether there will be any Open Source Advertising this year? Will there be?

Comment: There will be, yes. Some minor changes to the design in the offing; announcement forthcoming.