# A page to list all ads, that is easily accessible

Tags: discussion, feature-request, advertising

One of the things I really like about StackOverflow is the ads are relevant to developers.

However, sometimes I forget to click on an ad and then when I refresh the page of course another ad comes up.

I already know that there is a [page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281524/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2015) that lists these ads, the problem is it is very difficult to reach - you have to click through all the previous ad pages.

To get to that page:

1. I searched for 'opensource ads' at meta.
2. I reached [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76288/non-opensource-ads?s=1|3.4719);
3. From that question, I reached [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162128/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2013).
4. From there [this question - 2H 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195823/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2013), then [1H-2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210389/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2014), then [2H-2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260377/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2014), and then finally [1H-2015](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281524/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2015)

I suggest to create a separate page on meta that just lists the final - <strike>in fact, I remember there was such a page, but sadly I cannot manage to bring it up during my search</strike> like [this page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/281524), nominated/published ads per quarter and a link to this be provided in some obvious fashion.

Even on that page, I did not see the twilio ad that prompted this question; so maybe there needs to be a comprehensive ad page?

Comment: Worth noting is that the links you include are meta posts, meaning they would have to be updated manually. It also appears they are unlikely to include ads for anything other than open source software (such as licensed or closed source software).