# Open Source Advertising - 1H 2016

Tags: discussion, community-ads, open-source-advertising

It's 2016 now, and we've [made some changes to the sidebar size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites) (on top of... accidentally passing over 2H 2015). And with that all in play now, we're restarting our Free Vote-Based Advertising for Open Source Projects. We are clearing the leaderboards for the beginning of 2016. We are also instituting some new requirements for images - these have been marked bold in the Image Requirements section, please abide them.

Here is your chance to create a [Free Vote-Based Advertisement for an Open Source Project](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/). Create a graphical ad for an open source programming project and post it as an answer to this question (in the right format), and it will feed live remnant ads on Stack Overflow.

### Ad Requirements

It must be an advertisement **soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code**. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source. It's for finding programmers who will help contribute code or other programmery things (documentation, code review, bug fixes, etc.).

Your ad should be an original creation which has not previously appeared on Stack Overflow. Please do not resubmit entries that have appeared as ads on Stack Overflow in previous periods.

In order to work, the answers you post to this question **must** conform to the following rules.

### Answer Template

```
[![alternative text if image is not displayed][1]][2]
    
  [1]: http://image-url
  [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to add any commentary, keep it in the comments.

### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **300 pixels by 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
- Must have a 1px border if (part of) the background is white

The output ultimately will be served in an ad slot on Stack Overflow.

### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be served up by that URL and shown on Stack Overflow. You can see all the ads that currently make the threshold and meet our criteria on this page:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/314722

**Note:** *As with previous [iterations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281524/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2015) of this program, if your ad has already appeared in a previous cycle, it is not eligible to be run in this cycle.*

Comment: Wait, how did something appear in my answer area, all of a sudden?

Comment: @BhargavRao I see it too: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hKQPZ.png

Comment: That's the template for posting ads. It's there for your convenience.

Comment: Whoa. That's cool. Can you guys also auto paste my [Java] answers?

Comment: The template image should be updated for the new width.

Comment: Could you clarify the previous iteration rule? We had an [ad for oVirt in 2014 2H](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261094/2422776). Can we feature oVirt with a different ad, or did oVirt have it's shot and now it's done?

Comment: Can you confirm that the "or double that if retina" note on sizes ([seen on other sites](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/22419/238061)) applies to these ads as well?

Comment: I am pretty sure it should read "*if your ad has already appeared in **the** previous cycle*".

Comment: If possible please make adding comments mandatory on down vote which will help developer/team.

Comment: @GraceNote When were you thinking about enabling these across Stack Overflow? (I noticed that 7 ads have reached the threshold already)

Comment: I like how this (presumably official) post was downvoted by someone.

Comment: ***Plus One*** for the initiative.

Comment: Is there any way to get list of qualified ads from some RSS link? So I can also display them on my site and blogs. I would like to advertise deserving applications wherever possible.

Answer (score 40):

[image: Contribute to Traccar GPS Tracking System open source project]

Comment: Best thing i have ever used!  simply brilliant. And totally free!

Answer (score 31):

[image: Help us improve Zorg: A Python framework for robotics and the Internet of Things]

Comment: @Jongware It's actually _worse than that_, it was done in a short amount of time with the equivalent of MS paint. We're open to improvements though, if you have any specific recommendations.

Comment: I was potentially thinking about some contributions to this project. What is its current state? There doesn't appear to be much in the way of activity.

Comment: Hi @ChristopherSchneider, the base repository for zorg is relatively stable at the moment with a pull request staged that will introduce events in the next release. There is also several projects that have been created to add support for different devices and sensors (https://github.com/zorg). There are also a few more items listed in the roadmap of the project wike (https://github.com/zorg/zorg/wiki/Roadmap). I realize that the roadmap is fairly sparse, I will add some more details to it within the next few days.

Comment: @Gunther Thanks for the response. IoT isn't a domain I'm familiar with, but it looks like fun. I was always jealous of my college roommate's hardware based projects, so I want to try my hand at it. Is the Pi acceptable hardware or do you recommend the Edison?

Comment: @Chris sorry for the late response here. We have an [adapter for the Raspberry Pi](https://github.com/zorg/zorg-raspi) that is mostly working, but it is not yet available on PyPI and the docs are not yet built. You can still use it by copying/pasting the folder onto your Pi, and it should work well with other existing drivers.

Answer (score 18):

[image: Because research needs bechmarking!]

Comment: +1 because that bluish thing is kinda cute.

Comment: @AmitJoki clearly, it's an Elk :D

Comment: @cat says a *cat* :D

Comment: @AmitJoki Exactly c:

Answer (score 17):

[image: YAWP! - Simple, Elegant and Powerful APIs]

Comment: Curious why you have the postgresql logo there? Does it only work with postgresql?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, so far, our persistence layer has two drivers, one for PostgreSQL (jsonb) and the other for Google Appengine Datastore (logo in the middle).

Comment: Please, I'd appreciate more info from downvoters.

Comment: Well, you could use the correct logo for the datastore

Comment: @BurhanKhalid the framework also implements usage patterns for other Appengine features. The postgresql driver is a convenience driver to be used when your API doesn't need high scalability or you'd rather manage it  yourself.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gVNh1.png  :-)

Comment: @BhargavRao ?? :)

Comment: Ntn, Just saw your advert so I added it here :)

Answer (score 17):

[image: Upload To Commons: helping witnesses and journalists easily upload pictures to Wikimedia. Join our Android dev team!]

Comment: I'm a little puzzled by the fact that the ad links to your fork of a fork of a fork of the orginal project, which is hosted elsewhere.. Although your version is newer, why should we contribute to your fork instead of to the original wikimedia project ?

Comment: @JonasCz: How about linking to https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Mobile_app instead? The app was originally started by WMF, they abandoned it in 2013 to focus on the Wikipedia app and I have been maintaining it to this day. Currently WMF staff and a full-time intern (misaochan) are collaborating on my fork. No other fork has received any activity since 2013.

Comment: I think that linking to GitHub directly is better (especially if you're looking for contributors), as https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Mobile_app does not actually contain much information on how to contribute, but it might be worthwhile to add a section about the status of the project and why it was forked to your GitHub landing page, maybe with that link you mentioned.

Answer (score 15):

[image: Material elements for Python GUI]

Comment: A comment not on the ad but the project: I think people will want to see what the design elements look like before contributing or even downloading the package. Maybe you could include a URL to some screenshots in the Readme?

Comment: @Djizeus Thanks for the suggestion. We'll do that as soon as we get some components ready for work.

Comment: Strongly object to advertising half-finished code.

Comment: @DeerHunter I wouldn't have if there was any rule against it. And moreover, why would I need contributers for an already completed project?

Comment: To make it better, and not to free-ride on others' efforts?

Comment: @DeerHunter So, you're saying that asking people to contribute to a yet-not-completed project is free-riding? Well forgive me for thinking that that is how opensource works.

Comment: @Djizeus: Showing the "Contribute" button rendered with PyMaterial would be a great idea indeed. But I don't think the ad would benefit from including other design elements. Designers will immediately know what it looks like just by reading the name "PyMaterial". And if that was not enough, the Python logo rendered in material design leaves no doubt.

Comment: @Nicolas, I would kind of disagree that PyMaterial immediately tells the viewer what it's about - Yet another python GUI framework ? Something that runs on Android ? Something else ? I'd say leave the text, since it make it clear what the project is about.

Answer (score 15):

[image: Help us give the VBE the IDE features of this century!]

Comment: Recent pull requests include: added support for unit testing in AutoCAD and CorelDraw VBE hosts, revamped WPF UI for the *ToDo Explorer*, some code inspections, and a *move declaration closer to usage* refactoring. Our issues list is constantly growing with feature requests, including support for XML comments, a Win32 `Declare` helper, and so much more; features for next release include IDE-integrated Git source control, tons of new refactorings, host-specific code inspections and quick-fixes, keyhook-triggered parsing and 2-step hotkeys... lots of work on our plates! :-)

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but that black text seems a little too fuzzy, as if it has been scaled up, which I find somewhat jarring. The text in the other ads is sharper in comparison. Awesome project though !

Comment: @JonasCz removed the fuzziness in the black text (increased font size a bit, too). Better?

Comment: Much better ! Also having the word "Contribute" on its own line makes it stand out more, which is great too.

Answer (score 13):

[image: Cascade Framework! - Putting back the C in CSS]

Comment: Would the downvoters care to elaborate on why they didn't like my post?

Comment: Likely because you linked to a page that doesn't give anyone information on how to contribute. Alternatively, linking to a repository would be nice.

Comment: @RubberDuck : I replaced the link with the a to the Github repo.

Comment: Good enough for my upvote.

Comment: @RubberDuck : Thx!

Comment: Didn't this ad run previously already ? I remember seeing it sometime before, and the question says that ads which have run before cannot be submitted again. Still, you've got my upvote.

Comment: @JonasCz [Confirmed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251210/359284), it was actually pretty successful. But there has been a general trend for the "don't submit it twice" rule to only apply as ["don't submit it twice in one year"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314722/open-source-advertising-1h-2016#comment295342_314722), and this last ran in 2014.

Comment: "Putting back the C in CSS" should be "Putting the C back in CSS".

Comment: @TylerH : For real? You're the first one to mention this ever since I released the framework in 3 year. Godd*****!!

Comment: @JohnSlegers Sorry! This is my first time seeing the ad or hearing of the framework :-)

Comment: @TylerH : No problem. Thank you for your feedback. I'll look into it :-)

Answer (score 13):

[image: Boolean Sequence]

Comment: +1 I am impressed that they can be applied on input streams as well. and surprised that they are faster than java RE. keep it up. However I am missing more support for advanced feature of RE.

Comment: thanks. It has more features over the RE, like : auto optimization, you can merge multiple sequences together, you can see how your expression is evaluated, you can write your custom matcher, and custom return type too.

I'll try to add more features as soon as I get time to do that. However I'll appreciate if someone also participate to do that.

Comment: This is interesting!

Comment: I'm guessing the downvotes are about the quality of the graphics; the positioning is terrible.

Comment: :) better to focus on code ;) Otherwise I would become graphics developer

Comment: No, it's pretty important to focus on graphics. Otherwise no one uses your code, and you're wasting your time. For starters, please use proper English grammar -- "regular expressions" would be more correct. Also, the "for" should probably be bigger and centered, and the "experience and contribute" button shouldn't be exactly on the bottom.

Comment: I hope now it is better

Answer (score 11):

[image: Quack - Reuse modules.]

Comment: Interesting and useful stuff. +1

Answer (score 10):

[image: WinFsp - Windows File System Proxy]

Comment: Is this similar to FUSE only for Windows?

Comment: @NathanOsman Yea, it is. At least they say that on their page.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Contribute to Calm]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Native Bootstrap Widgets for Android]

Comment: The image is made using a screenshot of the views available in the project, in case anyone is interested. If anybody has any suggestions on how to improve the graphic that would be amazing - I am definitely not artistically gifted

Answer (score 6):

[image: CmisSync: Dropbox-like synchronization for Alfresco, SharePoint, Documentum, Nuxeo, Filenet. Contribute your C#]

Comment: Very interesting project.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Myrtille, a native HTML4/5 Remote Desktop Protocol client]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Eclipse plugins for the creation of graphical user interfaces that are based on trees.]

Comment: I'd like to +1 for this.

Answer (score 3):

[image: OmniDB - open source web tool for database management and conversion]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Join us in building this great cms]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Lightweight-Productive-Reliable parallel task running and results aggregation (MapReduce on multicore)]

Answer (score -4):

[image: IntelliJ IDEA - The Most Intelligent Java IDE]

Comment: Would the downvoters care to elaborate on why they didn't like my post?

Comment: I personally don't have an issue with the ad, but rather the page it links to doesn't really have clear directions on how to contribute with the development of it. The [github link](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community) is burried down on the page. I think if you narrow this down to having a specific focus (like a bug bounty or a competition for plugins) that might make it more appropriate for the open source section; otherwise I think you should advertise this directly.

Comment: The ad, mainly. It looks terrible. A very poor choice of fonts and colors. Looks like something designed in 30 seconds in Microsoft Paint.

Comment: @CodyGray 30 minutes, actually. I wanted it to look like IDEA's Darcula theme.

Answer (score -7):

[image: Java Quadratic Sieve]