# I didn't ask for this ducky tag, but I can live with it. Does it belong here?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

To my greatest surprise, a [rubberduck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rubberduck) tag was recently created on SO. This was my reaction:

> *I could never have dreamed of a rubberduck tag being created on SO! ...still, I think this question would be better off asked on our [GitHub repository](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/new).*

Now, there's an [SO Team](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/189/rubberduck) for the OSS project, and a [community ad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315297/1188513) in the running for 1H 2016.

I can (and will!) follow a [rubberduck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rubberduck) tag on SO just like I do on Code Review [(see tag's page on CR)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/rubberduck/info), and this might be my impostor syndrome speaking, but...

#### Do questions about an open-source IDE plug-in belong on Stack Overflow?

Or are they better off on GitHub?

Interesting flipside, there are quite an appreciatable amount of questions tagged [resharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resharper)... and JetBrains has tremendous user support.

Comment: Not exactly a dupe [http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) but should give you an at least some of the things that are appropriate for SO and what isn't.

Comment: If you're involved with the product, or even just know about it, and would like to see it used well on SO, please [propose a tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/117629) (at the very minimum an excerpt) for it so that the rest of us know what the duck it is.

Comment: @JoshCaswell don't worry, I'll make sure the wiki page matches that of the CR tag.. but there's an edit pending that I can't improve because I'm below 20K ;-)

Comment: Oh, I missed the pending edit, sorry. I voted on it.

Comment: Is this a way to advertise more for your advertisement? o_O

Comment: @BhargavRao nope. As a moderator (on CR), I feel sort-of-obligated to take this to meta. Sorry if it looks like an ad, it's not the intention. I linked to the SO Team and SO ad to show that the project is already present on SO.

Comment: Is there a real question somewhere?  If you can't "dream" about a tag getting created then sleep on it.  Every [tag] starts with one question, its name is irrelevant.  Very excellent project name btw.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> Do questions about an open-source IDE plug-in belong on Stack
>   Overflow?

Yes they do. According to the [on-topic guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and more specifically

> software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical,
>   answerable problem that is unique to software development

They are on-topic on SO. The rubberduck tag will be able to help both users and project supporters to identify that the question is related to that Tool and will be as valid as the resharper tag.

If SO should or not keep those questions on-topic or what kind of action should we take to those kind of questions may be left for [other meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316300/what-should-we-do-to-tool-related-questions). But I left my opinion on my other answer.

Comment: I wonder if we want to namespace these tags though? Projects with generic-ish names are bound to conflict not only with the technical term but also with the other tools with a similar name? This particular tag should be `rubberduck-vba` imo.

Comment: Note, however, that on-topic SO questions about development tools are about *using* those tools.  Questions about *building* tools may be on topic if they are sufficiently general, but I would not expect to see such a question tagged with the tool being built -- that would imply that the question is specific to the project, and thus probably off-topic.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't get it. Do users do not use resharper tag if they are developing an extension as well? I don't see any harm on having a tag serving more than 1 porpuse.

Comment: Perhaps the context here has been lost, @BrunoCosta.  I take the OP to be asking in part about whether it would be appropriate for contributors to the Rubberduck project to ask questions on SO about details of project implementation and practice.  The fact that Rubberduck is a software tool used by programmers does not automatically make such questions on-topic here.  When the on-topic guide mentions questions about those as on-topic, it's talking about questions regarding how to *use* them (including how to extend, write plug-ins for, *etc*.).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Didn't seem to be the case to me. I also took a look at all questions with the given tag and there wasn't any question regarding project details. I agree those questions are better off to be asked within the developer community of the project or in their git repository.

Answer (score 8):

> **Do questions about an open-source IDE plug-in belong on Stack
>   Overflow?**
>
> Or are they better off on GitHub?

SO: yes, GitHub: no.

I'm involved with a number of open-source projects on GitHub and the policy is similar with all: use the GitHub issues list for...*issues* (bug reports, feature requests, etc.) but use SO for questions like "how do I", "why does this not work". I realize GitHub projects are very diverse as for how they handle that but AFAICS most don't like seeing their issues list (ab)used as a support "forum".

Comment: Remember, though, one of the default labels for issues is "question".  So, I would say that support is _partially_ intended.