# What should we do to tool-related questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

I had to discuss this question [after this other one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316277)

Currently tool-related questions are [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on SO but I have a strong feeling that they could be avoided if the tool has better documentation to start with.

**EDIT**

Those tools usually also have user support and we are probably able to post questions regarding to the tool on the site. So if the information is not available we can create a question for it on the tool site.

My point is that everything related to the tool should be available in some form of documentation on the tool website.

What are the pros/cons of having this topic on SO?

Should we keep this kind of questions on-topic on SO, which kind of action can we take to improve our content?

Comment: Your question is extremely broad, you want all of the pros and cons associated with having these questions on-topic, whether or not we should keep them on-topic or not, and how we can improve the content on the site?

Comment: @TinyGiant What I really want here is a discussion. I think if the whole community works out on a better way to provide the content in a more useful fashion to everybody is what matters the most. I was trying to get an answer on what we can do about questions related to tools, so the users can have a place to search for them. Gabe already kinda answered that by suggesting a tools community

Comment: I could probably make an argument that tool questions belong on SuperUser, but I'm sure if I searched enough I'd find an answer saying why IDE questions are a better fit here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Currently tool-related questions are on-topic on SO but I have a strong feeling that they could be avoided if the tool has better documentation to start with.

Nonsense.

One of the nice things about Stack Overflow is that it can categorize the kinds of information that *don't* go into documentation.

As a prime example, compiler bugs. Or library bugs. Generally speaking, those don't get documented until they're discovered. And how do you know that you've discovered such a bug?

You need someone to be able to confirm that the documentation or specification says that X should happen, yet you are seeing Y. And we do that here by asking questions about it.

Not to mention, SO-style documentation works based on problems, not topics. Topic documentation is great for reference, but it's generally difficult for solving problems. SO documentation works much better at that.

> My point is that everything related to the tool should be available in some form of documentation on the tool website.

Even ignoring what I just said, this is still wrong.

As an example, the C++ standard is publicly available. And yet, even the people who *write it* don't fully understand every detail of every interaction of every one of its rules (as evidenced by all of the defects that keep getting discovered). So asking about a tool (like a compiler) and whether the compiler's results match with what the standard says is frequently not as simple as "look it up."

Hell, questions on Stack Overflow revealed two [rather](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693861/which-memory-barrier-does-glgeneratemipmap-require) [significant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34791187/is-it-legal-to-reuse-bindings-for-several-shader-storage-blocks) holes in the OpenGL standard.

So the fact that documentation for a topic exists is *not* sufficient reason to start saying that we shouldn't have questions about that topic.

> Should we keep this kind of questions on-topic on SO, which kind of action can we take to improve our content?

Stack Overflow exists for all kinds of programming tools. If we can ask questions about a tool as big as Clang, there is no reason we should be forbidden from asking questions about a tool as small as Rubberduck or whatever.

And if you're saying we can't ask questions about the most basic of programming tools (a *compiler*)... then what the hell good are we?

Stack Overflow does not need an arbitrary "this tool must be *this* popular to get questions" rule.

Comment: Thank you very much about the elucidation, specially about the compiler tools I must say that I was completely forgetting about them. I was just thinking about IDE or productivity tools. And I never said that Rubberduck questions should be forbidden, for me they can appear as much as reshaper (I even participate as a contributor :p).

Answer (score 10):

You could make this same argument about *anything* that *anyone* could ever ask *any* question about *ever*.

If the information is *already* readily available in the tool's document, then there's no need for SO to duplicate that information.  If the information *isn't* accessible, the SO *exists* to fill that kind of gap.

Answer (score 6):

Everything about $LANGUAGE programming language should be on their website as well.  We still answer questions about basic language features.  Better documentation in general is great, but it isn't a replacement for the ability to ask questions.  Now if you want to start programming-tools.stackexchange.com go for it-  I might welcome that split.  But for now its on topic.

Comment: Your point about the ability to ask questions is great. But I kinda disagree with the first statement. While there's plenty information on the language website it could happen that some behaviour is worth of further explanation and can have more emphasis so they can have further value to new programmers starting on that language and to the whole programmer community . SO is IMO a very nice place to do just that... Splitting may be a good ideia like you said.

Comment: @BrunoCosta: How do you know that a question about the language is not really about the tool? Maybe there's a compiler bug (which would fall under the "tool" category). Such a split would be a terrible idea, dilluting both to the benefit of neither. Programmers use tools of all kinds, whether compilers, interpreters, libraries, or whatever. If SO is a programming Q&A site, then programming tools should be a viable topic.

Comment: @NicolBolas Like I said on the comment to your answer I was thinking of tools just as productivity tools like IDE's and the like. I sadly completely forgot about compilers.