# Any news on Stack Overflow Channels?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams

It's been almost two months since Stack Overflow Channels [were announced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352065/introducing-channels-qa-for-engineering-teams).

I was really excited with the idea and immediately subscribed to the updates, but the only thing I received was a short survey in the middle of July (which I filled out) and nothing at all since then.

The [channels](/questions/tagged/channels) tag on Meta is at the time of writing also completely empty except for the initial announcement.

What's happening to Channels? Did the testing phase begin?

Comment: Look for it in about [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/176548)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm glad you asked this, we do have some news on Channels!

The team has been working hard to figure out what needs to be done to get it up and running - this includes everything from architecture to design. The developers have been making decisions on architecture and have been building an initial version, and our designers have been doing user interviews on the UI.

Right now, the main focus is to determine what needs to be included for the initial internal MVP. We’re targeting an internal release in the next few weeks. Of course, we'll be dogfooding it before we roll this out to anyone to test.

The plan is to provide regular updates to the community after we've done some internal testing.  We’ll be posting announcements and asking for feedback, when we have some mockups and more information about next steps with Channels.

Comment: From the initial post I got the impression that Channels were almost ready. Must have been wrong.

Comment: "GATHERING USER STORIES" Oh, god... you do have UX people.

Comment: @VasilyAlexeev yeah, it realy sounded like that. It seems, that SE has learned from the last disaster (☼) and is developing new products together with the community - which is a good thing.

Comment: Well, if you need any help. I know of this website where you can ask questions and get answers. Keep in mind asking for what channels you should work on first is a list question and will likely get closed.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Out of curiosity, what is the last "disaster" you're referring to?

Comment: @JohnFeminella I am referring to Documentation. Not the product it self, but what it was for the company.

Comment: This will be a good way to have less expertise and information available to the general public.