# What’s Happening With Channels?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams

Like we have done with other ongoing projects <sup>[1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352590/stack-overflow-jobs-update-july-20-2017), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350492/whats-going-on-with-documentation-this-month), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291031/what-features-did-the-community-team-discuss-have-implemented-or-have-denied-l)</sup>, we're going to try to provide regular announcements about Channels. For those who aren’t aware of what Channels is, we're working on:

> [a feature of Stack Overflow for organizations to have a private & secure space for their engineering teams to collaborate pretty much unrestricted and unstructured apart from public Q&A. Channels are for organizations both large and small and do not in any way affect public Q&A.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352065/introducing-channels-qa-for-engineering-teams)

The response to the initial announcement was overwhelming, with over [2,500 signups](https://stackoverflow.com/channels) from people telling us about their organization, and that they were interested in using Channels for their team. We have been [pretty quiet since then](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356267/any-news-on-stack-overflow-channels), but I'm here to tell you a bit about where we are at, and what's next with Channels.

Since the announcement, the team has been hard at work figuring out everything that needs to be done in order to get Channels up and running. Most of this has been on the stuff that's hidden from view. It's the backend core architecture to get us an internal version to test on. We've gone from pushing the limits and trying to break things, like [Nick Craver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver) load testing SQL Server by putting [10k schemas and 1.5 million tables](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/884859362052800512) into one database to see what would happen, to actually [breaking things](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/302433/164200)...accidentally when Channels code was pushed into production. Over the past month, we were able to get a very rough internal dev version of Channels up for us to starting testing with, and after a ton of work [we successfully got Channels in an isolated environment](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/924003119255773185) for the real [dogfooding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food) to begin.

As I mentioned, we have a rough version of Channels for us to test on. Now, when I say rough, I mean rough. Our current version of Channels looks a bit like this:

> [image: Channels nav]

We have a Channel switcher at the top of the question list to navigate between public Stack Overflow and private channels. This can also be used when switching between Channels to ask a question.

The switcher to get between Channels was put in place for our test environment, but this is by no means what the beta version is going to look like or how it will function. Our primary focus, up to this point, has been on how to get the core architecture working. While we have made progress, there is much to do before we're ready to release Channels into the wild. We're now shifting to think more about what features will be needed, as well as design and integration on Stack Overflow.

#### What's next?

First up, over the next month or so, we're going to be writing a series of blog posts about the work that's going into Channels. This includes insight into our thinking on the product, why people have told us they need Channels. We're also planning on sharing a lot of the challenges we've been facing, including issues around navigating between public Q&A and private Channels. As well as a [dive into some of the architecture](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/923996100071063552) needed to make it run.

Before allowing external folks into Channels, we're hammering away at our version to break and fix everything we can. Our plan is to open it up for some initial alpha testing in late-December/early-January. [Kristina Lustig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7317251/kristina-lustig), our UX researcher, will be looking for those interested in alpha testing some of the early versions of Channels. Early alpha testers will be expected to commit a substantial amount of time and feedback to the Channels project, including in-person visits to your office by Kristina and the PM of Channels, [Chance Heath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5931150/chance-heath), and other feedback sessions. We'll be reaching out to some of those [who initially showed interest in it](https://stackoverflow.com/channels) in the next couple of weeks.

Over the course of the next few months, we're hoping to have a better idea of timeline for beta testing of Channels. In the meantime, keep your eyes open for the blog series that starts in the next week or so.

Comment: That's 13 very quiet people...

Comment: Woo! I hope to reply to my invite email soon, one of the main decision makers happens to be out and the other is just busy. :) Really excited for this!

Comment: @bluefeet and the channels team.  Here is the challenge I hope "Channels" can solve: My hope is Channels will turn my engineering company whose stuck in the 1980s into a place that doesn't have to rely on certain individuals to answer very specific questions.  My hope is that we will have a central hub or knowledge base have you such that anyone can research and learn on their own.  To eliminate the amount of waste and redundancy that we currently abuse in searching emails, the network, or a POS intranet wiki we use that no one updates.  It sounds easy but you have to convince the masses...

Comment: late-December/early-January, huh? That's awfully close to 6 - 8 weeks...

Comment: On a more serious note, if I didn't want to disclose my SE profile to my employers, and they chose to utilize channels, would I need to create a separate profile?

Comment: @LordFarquaad You will need to create a new account to keep them separate.

Comment: One close vote: "This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community.".  I suppose in a very technical sense that's true, as it's just information coming *at* us, not a question.  But trying to close a question that's an official product update...

Comment: This seems to belong at an SO blog instead. Have Meta started doubling as a team blog yet?

Comment: Meta's been and should be that - simply cause its a way to get input too. And it does seek input, indirectly. Main blog has, as of late been mainly for SE careers/jobs by the look of things. I look forward to seeing stuff about QA there again ;)

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev as you can see from the links in the first paragraph, we’ve always used Meta for these types of announcements. Besides being used to point people to what’s coming, we also wanted to include where we are at with Channels.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev It is not like the [time to take a stand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand), where we are discussing some politics. This post is exactly about the software that Stack Overflow powers. And the team is giving us the ability to discuss about it, [like Chris has done](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358957/2441442). I apreciate the open communication!

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt You see, with a post formulated like an announcement, I cannot imagine what could an accepted answer sound like. There are no questions! Okay, you're doing this-and-that, planning to continue so-and-so, I see. Well, more power to you, keep on trucking. Is that what I should post as an answer?

Comment: *A tag for questions that may not necessarily have a clear-cut right or wrong answer and often subjective. If it is not a bug or feature-request, it is probably a discussion.* @ivan_pozdeev

Comment: What is it with trying to close this post? Y'all know full well they'll just reopen it so this is at best annoying to the CM team.

Comment: Will channels have review queues? What channels have in common with public Q&A? The idea is good, it's like easy creating own Q&A site for companies with developers, but how exactly is it going to be used? What kind of questions will be asked there? I have a small developer team, but I have doubts we can use channels for anything else apart from customer support (so they could ask questions here and somehow we get a db of answers).

Comment: is "dogfooding" a cool new term? what does it mean ?

Comment: @Fattie https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food

Comment: Is it intended that the two tabs in the GIF both translate to "Gurke" in German?

Comment: @Fabian Yes, we have two channels about pickles so they probably translate to the same word.

Comment: Private channels & public Q&A next to each other  https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlGxQ.jpg

Comment: People voted to close this earlier? lol

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev [Meta is different.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) On Meta, anything that's a substantial commentary or suggestion about the topic being discussed is suitable as an answer. Even raising questions is valid. Some Meta posts don't even need an answer. It's *much* less strict than the main site.

Comment: What happens in Channels stays in Channels

Comment: I would love love love to have this at my company, but we don't use anything we can't host ourselves, for security reasons. Would be delighted to hear about a self-hosted option... is that 100% definitely not happening?

Comment: @LangeHaare Depending on the size of your team, have you looked into [Enterprise](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise)?

Comment: @bluefeet ooh looks ideal, I didn't know about that. Thanks!!!

Comment: As mentioned, I don't like the darknet leaning--feels like paddling the SE boat in the wrong direction and for the wrong ethos, trying to chase money in a spirit that reminds one of the pre-Area51-hosting scheme.  Coming up with smarter open community-driven processes was a better bet.  But if the intent of channels is to have *temporary* private things vs. *permanently* private things, the design of the feature might be good to let **new users** pick if they want their Q&A to go to the "nice" queue (trained welcome wagon) or general populace, before going fully public.

Comment: @HostileFork I’m not sure I get your feeling this is a ‘darknet leaning.’ Channels are being developed for companies and teams that don’t fit in the Enterprise product as a way for them to share knowledge between the team. Instead of hiding answers in emails and/or chat at a company they could have a Channel for those questions that cannot be on public SO due to proprietary code or the like.

Comment: @bluefeet I understand, but if I were in SE's shoes planning "what should we embrace taking the company's vision to the next level" it would not be taking limited dev resources down this path, especially since I'm betting it will be a dud.  SE is free to do what they like--and will. 
 But *to my leaning* this is getting tangled into a murky line of business with a mess of pitfalls, that also encourages less open exchange, when open exchange and bringing people out of their "fiefdoms" so everyone can learn is the thing I actually like and recommend about SE.  Other proposals are being ignored.

Comment: Is it only me that is curious what questions are on-topic for gherkins?

Comment: Curious stuff. Would it be acceptable to use these channels for things such as specific tag moderation questions? I believe SO is missing a forum for technical meta discussions. "How do we moderate tag x?"  "Which are the canonical duplicates?"  "Please give feedback on proposed tag x wiki changes". Stuff that is a bit too narrow and technical to discuss here at meta, but off-topic on the main Q&A.

Comment: (Needless to say, I expect a channel such as "Language X moderation" to be completely free of charge.)

Comment: Hmm, this seems like a good idea. Plus one from me.

Comment: I think the case for Channels is much stronger than for Documentation. Hopefully, Channels will work out better. Keep it as flexible as possible. Wikis have their virtues too.

Comment: Perhaps a color coding (different backgrounds for different channels) might help in avoiding posting to a wrong channel.

Comment: Having participated in documentation, only to see it flounder then fail. I'll be giving this one a miss. Let me know when/if it ever takes off (oh and when you've decided how much your charging?!).

Comment: @JonH, I fear you may be disappointed, unless you think you can shoe-horn all of that into a Q&A format.

Comment: No more relying on Google for search... :)

Comment: @Benjol Fixing search is definitely on the top priority list due to Channels, which is fantastic because it will also help public Q&A.

Comment: Yet another solution in search of a problem, while the core functionality of the site - that made it great in the first place - is left to rot.

Answer (score 112):

Why is this tied to Stack Overflow?

Surely the scope for Channels is much wider than just programming Q&A even for businesses in the software industry.

I understand that "Stack Overflow" is seen as the major brand here and has the recognition factor and that you're aiming this at software development teams. However, will that cause problems in the medium to long term if Channels takes off?

I don't really expect you to change direction - I'm more after an idea of the business logic behind this.

Comment: We're going to use some of the blog posts to discuss our thinking on this. I believe the first post is going to cover it.

Comment: In a word: traffic. No other exchange generates the level of traffic, and content, that Stack Overflow does. This is significant not just in post generation, but also in advertising and sponsorships. Moreover, many of the other exchanges are more hobby based whereas Stack Overflow is more production based. That said, I don't see why a channel would need to share the same scope as Stack Overflow does.

Comment: @TravisJ - I agree that the scope doesn't need to be the same, but will people think that they can have a non-programming related Channel?

Comment: @ChrisF - Well I can't really speak for others, but in my interpretation it was open for non-programming related questions so long as they were kind of related to development in general, such as configuring a server, monitoring a load balancer, picking the right color gradient, etc. Maybe the channels could have a way to tag an exchange in, so that if the content were to leave it would leave to a proper place instead of just dumping everyone's Yu-Gi-Oh (or whatever the kids are watching these days) questions into Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is it indeed aimed just at engineering teams then, as the OP says?  If so, it seems appropriate to put it as part of SO. (I do think the appeal could be broad enough to warrant not arbitrarily restricting it to engineering knowledge and wonder if the current SE lopsidedness is a bias in deciding to couch it in the "SO v other SE" context)

Comment: One would think that naming it "Stack Overflow Channels" and putting a prominent ad on all the Stack Exchanges would achieve any marketing goals.

Comment: It's up to channel owners to set the tone on what's specifically _off_ topic within a channel, but there's no reason that a channel couldn't encompass stuff for programmers, sysadmins, designers, engineers, testers or any other components within a channel. As long as channel owners and moderators take some time to clearly define "this is what we should be posting in the channel, and this kind of stuff we should just post out in public plain view", then the channel itself will be healthy within the organization.

Comment: In other words, it doesn't have to be about programming to belong in the channel, it just has to be about something the organization behind the channel has determined belongs there. If your company has chefs and they want to post the recipe to their proprietary "YoYoDyne Systems Steak Rub" - they're welcome to do so provided that the channel mods and admins say it's okay :)

Comment: @TimPost - I wasn't questioning that - I suppose I was expecting a Channel to be wider that just programming which is why I'm questioning it being tied to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @TimPost I actually sent you an email a while back (7/27, to be exact) about much this same question... what about (private) organizations that have zero programming at all but lots of questions that get asked, often repeatedly, that could benefit from a repository of questions and FAQs to help their members.

Comment: For what it's worth, architecturally there are many single-points-of-hierarchy (e.g. one parent site) but a great many pieces aren't designed that way, they'd actually allow multiple top level sites to have Channels. The work is non-trivial to do such but we haven't precluded the possibility in the structure. But let's not get ahead of ourselves, let's make it work once first...

Comment: Hm, so they point is to provide a solution for groups which need a Q&A service for themselves but cannot be bothered with self-hosting AskBot or other, or which feel their questions would have a large overlap with StackOverflow's?

Comment: @Catija - if you really like the format but find yourself limited by the site as-is, you might explore hosting your own [StackOverflow clone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267/174723). Plenty of options. And of course, [StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com/) is a site that allows you to pay money for your own Q&A site running on very similar software to StackOverflow and the like.

Answer (score 83):

We would love to subscribe to the alpha, but there some questions that need to be cleared up before we would commit to put our knowledge (and thus quite some time) into SOC.

Points here are from the invitation mail:

- **Free use of Channels for the entirety of our alpha and beta tests.** Okay, and then? Before we spend days of putting information in, we have to know what it means in a few months time when everyone has to start paying for the service.
- **Note that we have already devoted extra attention to our platform security, so we are confident that your data will be safe.** Where does the data reside? How 'safe' is it? What laws do apply? Are there separate data centers for regions other than US?

Other questions:

- Can we connect our customers too? What if we do want to make it less private (say, readable for non-registered users and Google)?
- How sure can we be that investing time won't be a loss? As an example all the time users committed to make Documentation work, which was eventually killed?
- How much is there available on the API services side? Can we make our own integrations?

Comment: Unfortunately, a lot of these questions won't have answers for the alpha testing phase. They are all great questions, but most probably won't be addressed until beta and/or launch of Channels.

Comment: You might want to have answers ready at least for the public beta. Only if you want to earn money, of course.

Comment: @bluefeet are the first two questions really not answerable now? There's no plan for what to do with alpha and beta customers once the service launches? And you haven't got a data storage strategy in place yet but you're almost at alpha?

Comment: @RobertGrant At this point, we do not have a price structure set up - everything is still being worked out. As far as the data storage, yes most of that has been set up and is planning on being covered by the architecture team in a blog post. They are still finalizing things, so any answer I attempt to give at this point would be incomplete.

Comment: @bluefeet fair enough, I guess! Interesting insight into how SE works :-)

Comment: Have you considered doing a small scale internal trial using the alpha? A few users try using it for a little while (a few days, a couple weeks occasionally asking questions) and seeing how it goes? Then you could both get an idea if it's something helpful to your company *and* give any feedback to SO. I agree that going in full force is not an option in these stages, but try-before-you-buy seems like a good strategy even after it matures.

Comment: @bluefeet Why should a company invest into channels at this point, or even later at a beta stage, when you don’t even have answers on such core questions? It feels to me like you should really spend more time on the product design before you start working on the technical bits.

Comment: @poke Why should a company invest at in point? We've got lots of companies looking for a solution like our Enterprise product that will fit their smaller company/team. Those who are going to be in the alpha test will be committing time to help with a product that will eventually help their team and others which are similar. While we don't have answers to everything yet, we know that the design can always change, but the more technical backend architecture, security, etc needs to be nailed down before letting anyone in to play with it and their data.

Comment: @bluefeet *to help with a product that will eventually help their team and others which are similar*, well, that is the point. We don't know if the product exists in a month or two. Still, I can spend a whole day in putting content in SOC. That entire day will be lost when SOC doesn't meet your or my expectations.

Comment: @bluefeet *“looking for a solution like our Enterprise product that will fit their smaller company/team”* – But so far, there is no guarantee that Channels will be able to fill that hole. Enterprise can run on-premise, so that’s a completely different story than having a cloud-only solution which so far does not have any answers for the typical questions business will *need* to have answered for cloud services before *any* real investment will be made.

Comment: @poke Nick is going to be writing a blog post that going to give a lot more details on the setup, but a high-level overview is separate DB, with separate schema per channel for security isolation on a secure network, locked down to minimal folks. He's going to give many, many more details in the post including an encryption key for you all to play with.

Comment: But seriously @poke these are all very good questions and we are working to get answers to all of them. The team behind Channels is moving very quickly to sort out concerns raised, as well as working on getting this into an alpha version to get feedback from people using an early state of the product. The plan is to be open and upfront with answers as soon as we have them.

Comment: @bluefeet That certainly sounds promising! I’m looking forward on what you are going to share about this project in the future. Note that I’m not against Channels at all—I think it’s a really good idea—I just fear that you are planning things in the wrong order. If that’s not the case and you’re aware of all the challenges, I’m looking forward to be proven wrong later :)

Answer (score 49):

What thought has been given to data exports? For example, one of my team leads asked what happens if we try the three months of alpha and decide we don't like it. Or, what if we go through the whole alpha and beta then find out the price model will be outside of what we'll be able to use from the company's budget?

Being able to export what we've done if we want or need to leave is very important, but hadn't been fully thought out in the original post yet. Has this been further refined?

Comment: With all the work done, we have not given much thought on data exporting. We've gone ahead and added this to the list of things to think & work on.

Comment: From my conversation with Chance and Kristina recently, at the bare minimum they will provide a similar sort of data export for private data that is already provided for SO data in general.  Agreed this is an important point -- if you can't get the data out after the alpha/beta, it would strongly discourage any of us from wanting to invest energy into putting data into this platform if we end up wanting to pull out of it.

Comment: We plan on data exports for a variety of reasons, namely: those Channels that get big enough they want to move to Enterprise instead, and if anyone is unhappy and simply wants to go. I don't have ant in-depth details because we're just not there yet, but wanted to relay the goals.

Answer (score 21):

Sorry to be a [broken record](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/304157/211160), but as with Documentation, I'm again worried that this takes focus away from the core competencies of SE--where not much visible evolution has happened in a while.

It seems that expansion into new never-voted-on brainstorms from HQ is favored over appeasing those who were the reasons for initial success, *(e.g. by implementing their [feature-requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) already asked for and voted upon.)*

- How exactly is there being hidden stuff on StackOverflow that I can't see making programmers lives--when taken as a whole--better?  And what kind of stuff is in there, anyway?
- In a metaphysical sense, why is it favorable to empower developers to carry out a greater portion of their daily Q&A in private fiefdoms...rather than building more confidence in the public system?  Is it really the case that making a living off the public system isn't going well enough that can stay the prime focus?

Perhaps using the SE code to build a kind of groupware or issue-tracker that tails off the main site isn't the *worst* idea in the world.  But those products exist.  So it seems tangential, and again a use of development resources on something weird that doesn't seem to have the same oomph as working more on the product that everyone actually uses every day.

I'll note that way back when, SE tried to let people pay to host public exchanges, and realized this ended up with a lot of dead sites.  I think it was a very smart move to cancel that, and invent Area51 to establish community buy-in (with examples of what good and bad questions were, a beta phase, people making commitments to participate).

But this feels like going back to that "oh some people like our features so we let them run their own board".  Except this is not public, so there'll be even smaller audiences...and StackOverflow will now carry new liabilities for any data breach (when people think it's okay to post passwords or keys in their questions, and such).

Since you've decided, I'll just save this post to link to after you cancel this thing and tell us about the next one.  :-/

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "never-voted-on". Channels and Documentation were both presented on Meta in their planning stages. [Introducing Channels: Q&A for engineering teams](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/352065)

Comment: @JoshCaswell I don't equate "presented in their planning stages officially and issued on a blog" with features originating from user demand and upvoted organically.  Blog subscribers (who are habitual clickers of things in the first place) likely don't measure the aspect I'm speaking about: *what is the cost of such efforts relative to other cooler things that could happen*.  For zero cost then sure--try anything.  Just sad to see the main site not perceivably better in quite a many years (it used to innovate a lot), and then venturing into darknet Q&A, which seems counterproductive.

Comment: I'm not sure how Channels is a move *away* from Q&A. It's private Q&A. In order to sell this product (and Enterprise), SE has to improve the Q&A core product - fixing search, for example. They improve search for private users, they improve it for the entire network. I see this move as being in line with the interests of the network as a whole.

Comment: Perhaps the question page should emphasize the importance of selecting to which channels you would like to post your question. The problem then becomes balancing cross-channel posting with corporate security.

Comment: Agree with @Catija. Another "search" related feature is the possible dupe suggestions when asking. If that gets some love, we will hopefully see a nice drop in duplicates asked (and thus a reduction in need for moderation activities). Maybe also improvements in UI or formatting will come along eventually. The core of asking and answering is pretty much nailed down; SO's biggest problem nowadays is the flood of crap questions and answers and trying to avoid the Slashdot effect, which is admittedly a nice problem to have. Even a *small* improvement on this front would be good for answerers.

Comment: @jmpc26 As I say, I'm thinking it's another distraction from where the site should be focusing as a worldwide public resource.  If there's a belief that it will create some trickle-down of new features to please the private channels, that go public, okay...but sounds awfully roundabout to me vs. just doing the feature.  If the "channels" feature was turned into a way to let a trained "welcome wagon" help people who are new have a better experience before putting them before the general public, perhaps.  I'll bet that this will be effort wasted when more interesting things could be done.

Comment: @Catija What I'd liked about SO and historically recommended it is specifically--and pointedly--the embrace and advocacy of *public Q&A*, a living and learning resource.  Getting people out of their dark little forums, putting as many eyes on things as possible.  So taking the public out of it kills my interest.  Like making Wikipedia that's only open to people over 6 feet tall.  Perhaps you'll find a basketball-players-niche who'll go for it, but not a good enough reason to invest one's time and effort on it, when life is short and you're skimping on features on the public project for years.

Comment: *Since you've decided, I'll just save this post to link to after you cancel this thing and tell us about the next one.* this for me is the nub of SOs current attitude to it's community. They've stopped listening.

Comment: Yes, as @Catija said this *IS* core Q&A. The problem with Documentation, as you correctly surmised, was that it had zip, zilch, nada, bupkis to do with Q&A. So to argue "this takes focus away from core Q&A" is.. uh.. completely and utterly wrong? If you are reading this and thinking "wow Channels sounds like Documentation" then I urge you to read more harder-er ;)

Comment: @JeffAtwood *I explained what I meant.*  I suppose a business-minded person might want to be the Slack of Q&A--and not miss out on that service space.  Ok...but I think Slack is a reprehensible piece of garbage.  Striving to be the best *public* Q&A is a far more important goal.  And that goal has not been acted on effectively of late.  I'm skeptical that it'll suddenly get better because the tiny dev team is chasing dollars on something that (I predict) will fall flat.  I could be wrong, but my gripe is *why has SO gotten so stagnant, and ignoring feature requests from the community itself*?

Comment: (I will say, that, no this is obviously not as bad an idea as Documentation.  But there are a lot of other things SO could do to get me excited about the site and its future, when I find my enthusiasm has increasingly waned over the years.)

Answer (score 3):

While you don't have pricing estimates available now, can you give us some pricing meta information - such as whether pricing will be based on registered users (user based), number of posts (content based), or traffic (activity based)?

Is there some thought going into a possible "free" tier of pricing, or will any use have a cost?

Answer (score 3):

Is our content going to be licensed differently?  Will we have individual power over licensing language, or will there be a boiler plate license we can either take or leave, or will it be tied to how much we pay?

Answer (score 1):

Building on ChrisF's answer... and what was *admittedly* a showerthought...

Lemme start off with a few things you guys said

> Channels are a means for organizations to provide a quiet space for their engineering teams to collaborate pretty much unrestricted and unstructured apart from public Q&A on Stack Overflow through a more private means that we're calling a channel. Channels are for organizations both large and small and do not in any way affect public Q&A.

Makes me feel like Channels is pretty much its own product, and it feels rather than bolting on Channels to SO, bolting other things onto channels makes sense.

I also suspect at this point you'd have channel user and non channel user UIs.

Real problems are also cross disciplinary - within an organisation, you might have people using channels for desktop support, or developers and operations/SRE folks. SO and SE's *main* selling point is being a knowledge base and being able to pull in information from elsewhere on the network would be nice. I wonder if being able to onebox specific posts in an answer would be handy. (Yeah, we could reproduce the answers but that's just duplication of answers without context).

Likewise, being able to search, and easily link/pull in  information from across the network from channels would be handy. This would let a channels user both create and agrregate knowledge from across the network.

Does feel like a couple of steps outside what channel's is being described at (and I snuck in a pair of feature requests) but channels can be QA + rather than something added on to SO.

---

In reply to Jon's Comments -

I don't see SO as a "channel" - rather than channels are "mini" sites. Unlike traditional Q&A though, a engineering would require multiple disciplines and often cross pollination/knowledge sharing between them. Channels would work *fundamentally* differently from traditional, scope-restricted Q&A sites.

To use a food analogy, if each main site was an ice cream flavour - channels is going to end up building sundaes, with their own secret toppings.

I don't see channels as anything 'like' the traditional SE Q&A site. You're trading off visibility (on a traditional Q&A site) for the prospect of broader scope per channel. I *don't* imagine though that you'd basically see a bunch of mini SOs, and even if you did, you'd want any information from SO, useful for the current question/answer thread at your fingertips without going off the channel.

Comment: From my reading between the lines (probably incorrectly) it sounds like Channels  is effectively the base product with SO being a large and already existing public Channel.

Comment: editing answer. Running out of space in comments ;p

Answer (score 1):

When will we hear how moderation will work?  Will SO moderators have open access to our content? Will we be able to assign moderators internally? Are we going to have to raise the reputation of some of our users through time and effort in order to effectively moderate our content?

Comment: SO mods will not have access to Channel content. All of that content is going to be restricted to only those with Channel access. I don't have specifics on how all of the moderation will work, but I know SO mods will not see it.

Answer (score -8):

#### What will the price be? Can I download my data? How safe is my data? What if this gets killed off after a huge investment

These are questions applicable to any cloud service. What about all the work that went into GeoCities?

You can't fault S/O for not having any better answers. They will try their best but they can't change reality.

While it won't work for this, even if you could hedge your bets with an on-prem purchased solution if you have infrastructure and staff, 10 years after the vendor pulls the plug, there is going to be a killer security hole or incompatibility or failure to run on anything higher than tomorrow's XP which you eventually have to stop using for one reason or another.

Nothing lasts forever! Your best bet is to hope for an Export All to PDF feature ;-) Until PDF goes the way of Flash...

#### Edit:

*You're suggesting that action should not be taken if the results are not permanent.* from a comment. That is not the intent of this answer. For example of course you should have used flash if it were a fit! Which it was for a lot of things.

The intent of the answer is a conveyance of reality. Things get obsolete and change out from under you. Expect it, and this will lessen the pain.

I'd be proud of the downvotes, as long as people are downvoting the temporality of the way this world is, not a reading-into of the answer that wasn't intended.

We want things to last forever. They don't and that can suck. Ask any 75 year old ;-)

Comment: You're suggesting that action should not be taken if the results are not permanent. That's a philosophical stance, and one that's pretty pessimistic. Flash was an innovative piece of technology that ushered in the modern day browser, contributed to the design of ECMAScript, and gave way to single page applications. Just because the next thing will be better doesn't mean you should refrain from making something now.

Comment: Who knows, by the time SO kicks the bucket (don't see that happening soon), we'll probably have AI capable of migrating our data to whatever's next.

Answer (score -9):

I feel like StackOverflow fails to deliver more and more of new features that it's testing. Maybe it's like the Trello example where they couldn't build more around the core product that already was very good? Wish you all the best guys, but I don't really see the new feature getting adopted and I fear that it will share the outcome of Documentation.

Comment: I strongly criticized Documentation. I initially liked the idea, and maybe it _could_ have worked, and maybe not.  But IMO, anyway, I think this feature is _especially_ in SO's wheelhouse.  They're not inventing a new concept.  They're rather officially providing a vehicle to leverage some of the things that are so great about SO in an ecosystem that is ultimately private.  Admitedly there are a lot of concerns -- they _absolutely_ need to make security and separation of data bulletproof.  But I'm high on this feature in a way I haven't been with any of their other recent initiatives.