# Is it possible to make gifs inserted into posts loop?

Tags: feature-request, images

Sometimes it is necessary or helpful to post a gif with a question.  I just did and noticed it only plays once.  Is there a way to make it loop?

Here is a sample:

[image]

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/VPPKXYy.gif

Comment: (seriously though, the downsides seem huge - most importantly, a potential for endless annoyance.)

Comment: It must be a recent change then because [my earlier (last year) uploaded gif](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278564/158100) loops? Or do I miss the actual issue?

Comment: @Pekka. If the gif is annoying it probably isn't appropriate and should be edited regardless of looping?

Comment: @rene. Perhaps it's metadata in the gif.  I'll try using different software to see if the behavior changes or if there's an option.

Comment: @Scott often probably, yeah, but I can easily see a GIF that is OK playing once becoming annoying when looping

Comment: @Pekka웃 [breaking your hopes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22302406/839601)

Comment: I love that the top post in Meta right now has a looping gif in it :)

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358943/what-s-happening-with-channels

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your animated GIF doesn't loop, that just means the GIF itself wasn't set to loop. You'll need to open it in an image editor that supports animated GIFs and re-export it with looping enabled.

Comment: After I posted I realized that may be the case (thus my comment about 8 hours before this answer).  Thanks for confirming. I'll have to find some new capture software if I want this in the future I guess :).

Answer (score 2):

It's probably just your gif. I'm on mobile at the moment, so I can't readily tear into it for you, but I left detailed instructions over on meta.math: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26978/adding-gifs-not-cycling-continuously/26979#26979

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's not needed, because you can click on it and play it again.

You just need to make sure that no one misses it... =]

Comment: Clicking on it opens it in the existing tab for me, which means your best option is refreshing the page.  This is poor user experience imo.

Comment: I click on it, it opens in the same tab, I watch it, then I tap Back button, and I'm in the post again

Comment: Right.  I personally think that's bad ux.  /Shrug

Comment: I know nothing about UX.............. I guess my users thinks that too........ they're leaving me!

Comment: I wasn't implying you don't know UX. It's very subjective. Sorry if I offended.

Comment: I didn't, I wrote that with humor, not self mercy.. Sorry for being not understandable :)