# Coming Soon: Stack Overflow For Teams!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

Sometimes we chase things not because we can see what's at the end, but because the general direction feels like the one that we should be taking. It might be surprising to learn that the [unshipping of teams](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330427/the-un-shipping-of-teams) was met with quite a bit of optimism on our part, internally; we knew that the direction was still good, and that a bit of quiet time might help us figure out why we felt so strongly that we needed to head in that direction. We needed to get a better fix on that really shiny thing we kept seeing off in the distance.

As we've been [working on channels](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352065/introducing-channels-qa-for-engineering-teams), we've had a series of epiphanies. Well, maybe they weren't really epiphanies, maybe they were just things we needed to say out loud more purposefully to one another to make sure none of us thought all of us were totally crazy:

- Working on products that directly depend on the continued refinement of our Q&A product is a very healthy thing for us to be doing. Even though it can be a bit of a drag to put a ton of work into stuff that only paves the way for more visible changes, it keeps us focused.
- It can be easy to mistake all that stuff you *didn't* see coming as scope creep, especially when that stuff is debt that wouldn't have surfaced otherwise. Sometimes the right call is to keep going even when you see thick and prickly weeds ahead. We've been [talking about our information architecture on the blog lately](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/02/08/information-architecture-navigating-stack-overflow-enterprise-stack-exchange-sites/), if you missed it.
- Human behavior is weird — like, really weird. People make everything more complicated. A lot of our core Q&A model is based on the assumption that people need to prove themselves over a period of time before it's safe to trust them. That gets odd and even onerous in private settings when your paycheck is the foundation of the social contact.
- The product we're currently calling 'channels' is starting to turn more and more into a term to indicate an isolated environment where it's safe for quite a few rules (even fundamental ones, like laws of Q&A physics) to be quite different than they are for public Q&A, or not exist at all.

In [our last major update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358943/what-s-happening-with-channels) we talked about all of the work that was going into getting channels ready enough that we (and some very brave early alpha partners) could start testing it. That has been going about as well as you'd expect for a high speed roller that conspicuously lacks any safety devices, and has been just as exhilarating.

Now that we've identified everything else that needs to go into a minimum, viable product, we have some updates that we think you'll find helpful as we near an announcement of a firm launch date:

1. **Stack Overflow For Teams** is what has come full circle as the product that we've previously described as *channels*.
2. **Channels** are an architectural concept that are primarily inward-facing, but serve as the foundation to allow things like *Stack Overflow For Teams* to exist.

Channels allow us to do things like have many instances of the same tag, have questions with only organizational visibility, have different kinds of privileges, housekeeping scripts and .. a *lot* of other things. We did not realize how much of a departure what we initially called a *channel* could be, especially as we saw our early alpha <strike>gluttons</strike> partners need to bend things to suit their needs.

What other kinds of neat things could a channel eventually support? We're not entirely sure yet, our main goal is to get Stack Overflow For Teams out in public beta the first half of May 2018. We're starting this discussion now to head off any ambiguity that would otherwise arise from future updates, and to open up to any questions you might have no matter how 'blue sky' they might seem.

What I've understated quite deliberately in this post, mostly for the sake of the shred of remaining brevity it can boast, is the *colossal* undertaking it has been to get to a product that is close to being complete enough to ship. We'll have more comprehensive details about features and how Stack Overflow For Teams will differ from public Q&A as we get closer to shipping, way more than I could possibly list here.

If there's something specific you'd like to know, please ask away in an answer (or comment, if you're just interested in seeing if there's something worth asking about). We're really excited to have reached this point and we can't *wait* for everyone to see it.

Until then, ask away, and we'll continue to post updates as we have them.

Comment: Based on the title I thought Teams is being un-un-shipped

Comment: Teams is dead. Long live Teams!

Comment: Very easy to get this confused with Microsoft's Teams.

Comment: This is the first I hear of Channels or Teams. Can you add a quick summary of what feature/service this post is even about, please?

Comment: @Sander "working on channels" and "our last major update" link to the first and second post about it, respectively.

Comment: @TimPost: `[stackoverflow-for-teams]` seems to be the wrong tag here. Did you create that one on purpose?

Comment: Is it going to be a Q&A like the main site, or opinion based questions will be accepted ?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Teams can ask whatever questions and set whatever rules they want for their Team.  In our own usage of it, we've noticed a lot of different questions that would be "opinion based" or off-topic for other reasons on the public site, but which we find to be highly valuable and relevant (and have defined our own "on topic" rules to accommodate those)

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, you thinking it could use one more hyphen? I could go either way, but it was created to be the tag to talk about the product, since 'teams' refers to something extremely dissonant from what we're talking about here.

Comment: @TimPost: I was thinking the `[teams]` tag that was added was the correct one. What's the difference?

Comment: @Cerbrus `[teams]` links to posts talking about something that [no longer exists](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330427/the-un-shipping-of-teams), but where plenty of discussion took place. As this is something completely different but overlaps only in name, a new tag seemed like the best idea, so either could be discussed exclusively without ambiguity.

Comment: I'm a little confused here, are Teams coming, going, or staying?

Comment: What was this post about?

Comment: Will this be free?

Comment: Could you be more specific and precise ?

Comment: Will "stack overflow for teams" be called "Team Overflow"?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: Or perhaps, drawing from the idea of multitasking on modern computers, "StaOverfl owck"

Comment: Would it be right to think of SO teams as like new Stack exchange sites but for smaller private communities that down want to go through the longer Area 51 process?

Comment: @Chris_Rands In a sense, sort of. You'll still be on Stack Overflow, you'll still see the public Q&A, you'll just also see the private team stuff and additional navigation options. So from the UX point of view, you're still on SO, it's just that private content is very clearly differentiated. Now, if your organization favored lots of subjective questions, then you would sort of feel like you were on another site. I think it depends on perspective. SO For Teams is designed for teams too small for a whole private instance, so sort of like a site .. no single good answer here :)

Comment: If I don’t participate in SO for Teams, how will this affect me? Will I get any UI changes that would constantly nag me for not having other Teams?

Comment: Your next product should be called High Availability Reseach and Development.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_KmNZNT5xw a deja-vu

Comment: Does this negate the purpose of Area51? So in practice I could finally create a 'channel' for (eg) Pinball Machine related Q&A's and have it publicly searchable and joinable?

Comment: @PaulG Nope. It has to be programming related, you'll need to pay for it, and the content is going to be private. It would be joinable, but only to folks within your organization. We're _looking_ at the possibility of public teams for organizations that essentially exist to serve the public interest, but that's .. a little ways off, as we still have to explore features that let private teams make certain posts public, or semi-public (as in read-only, but public).

Comment: *“It has to be programming related”* – How are you possibly going to enforce this? The content is supposed to be private and nobody from outside that Team should be able to access this.

Comment: @poke We're not going to be actively policing it but (1) anything else is going to seem _extremely_ out of place with tag prediction and the mixing in of public content and (2) we're pretty sure we can help support any use case at least _loosely_ tied to programming from both a UX and community perspective, but not positive we could overcome the dissonance of a channel for cat gifs (or help bean counters justify the cost). We expect teams to have plenty of subjective content, or stuff like "How do I set up our VPN?" but the product use case is built _primarily_ around programming.

Comment: @poke (continued) So in essence, it's more the need for the use of teams to fall somewhat closely within our expected use case in order for the product to work properly for folks, and we want people to have the best experience. However, we look forward to pushing and growing that use case as people present demand for it, if that makes sense. But I wouldn't expect too many folks to pay for something where they just giggle at memes, or trade recipes (or anything else where a closed FB group would be more than sufficient).

Comment: @TimPost Okay, thanks for the clarification. I’m really curious how this will turn out in the end!

Comment: Hoping this won't see the end like documentation on SO did.

Comment: I was checking the other day, but my previous team page doesn't seem to exist anymore. Can I find that content somewhere? And can you tell me how I'm going to warm up my collegues *again* for this teams feature?

Comment: will it be something like Microsoft Teams where you can have different threads based on topics? what other motivations does this feature have besides visibility level on questions/answers?

Comment: How do you give assurance that team information is private and secured?

Comment: @TimPost - How can a company get in on SO for Teams?  Sorry if that's already been asked...

Comment: @ArpitSolanki "Hoping this won't see the end like documentation on SO did"  You know it will.  Give it a year or so.

Comment: coming in 6 to 8 weeks?

Comment: make one youtube vedio then i will understand

Comment: @AbdulAlimShakir Think of teams sort of like threads, with thread local storage. Then imagine a bunch of penetration testing being done to ensure TLS is _actually_ TLS. Only members of a team or (very select) employees can see team content. I think a big challenge will be a feature that allows teams to make *only some* content read-only to the public, like documentation. Making it private was the easy part, if that answers your question :)

Comment: @jmort253 The public beta will begin *very* soon-ish, I don't think we're setting up any more spots until then. There will be an announcement that should be pretty hard to miss.

Comment: @ParaM We will. There will be some pretty clear and helpful info on what a team is, what you can do with it, how it differs from other things, etc.

Comment: How similar is this to [Questions for Confluence](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/questions)?

Answer (score 265):

When Stack Overflow is used as a work tool, will there be work–life balance related features?

I understand teams will be on the same site as Stack Overflow, probably sharing the same inbox - but if something happens in my "work" channel while I'm away - I really wouldn't want to be pinged about it until I'm at work. 
Features like push notifications, chat pings, "post seen by", "user last seen at", etc. are very nice *while at work*, but in my opinion cause unhealthy expectation while away from work.

This is pretty much an opposite point from [Makoto's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364148/7586).

Comment: As far as I know you'll have good control over notifications, but I'm not 100% certain that we have a place where you can differentiate your time on the site. This actually goes a bit deeper, because there might also be a point where you'd say "Hey, not only do I not want work notifications right now, but I don't even want to _see_ posts from my private work stuff while I browse on Sundays" -- we might need to get quite a bit more input shortly after launch to see what would work best for the use cases. A very solid point / question, thank you for raising it.

Comment: Would you use the same account in work? I'm not sure I want all my SO activity associated with my workplace

Comment: @NickDewitt - I don't know how that's intended to work. [This post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364239/7586) raises some good points related to that.

Comment: @Kobi me neither, and if I don't know, and we decide to use this at work, then I would probably setup a new account on my work email for that. It might be nice to be able to use them both in the same interface, but don't think that people won't make new accounts for this unless it's clear how it does.

Comment: If we could have a user interface where we have 2 accounts; a work account and a private account, and there was a hotkey to switch between the two that would be even better ;-)

Comment: Github teams would be a good model: I can use the same identity and be a member of multiple teams, or use separate identities for them (with a little juggling of certificates and the like). So the ability to configure which teams are visible when might be a team membership setting?

Comment: I want to especially draw attention to the "post seen by" and "user last seen by" notes that Kobi made.  This drives me crazy in all other chat/interaction programs I use, and would hate to see it appear in StackOverflow.  Please, please, please don't include such a feature. ;-)

Answer (score 66):

How distinct from Stack Overflow main will Stack Overflow For Teams be? How much integration is there, if any? In particular:

1. Are accounts linked between Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow For Teams? What about between two different teams? If they're not linked by default, is it possible to link them?
2. Can one close a question on Stack Overflow For Teams as a duplicate against a question on Stack Overflow?
3. Will the 'related questions' list on Stack Overflow For Teams show results from Stack Overflow? What about vice versa?
4. Will chat be included with Stack Overflow For Teams?
5. Can one setup a public Stack Overflow For Teams (think an open-source project)?

   - If it's public, does this change any of the above?
   - Are question *migrations* allowed between public Stack Overflow For Teams sites and/or Stack Overflow?

Comment: Pretty sure some of these were answered in [the original teams posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307513/the-power-of-teams-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow), but then again, since we don't necessarily know what's changed since then, it's probably fair to re-ask.

Comment: Hi Rob - (1) yes, you can have one Stack Overflow account that logs you in to both your usual account and your teams by default (2) No, question and answer data between the two is totally separate (they exist in different DBs) (3) Question list pages can show both, but for now "related questions" are just public or private, not shared (4) No (5) Currently all Teams are private

Comment: @JoshCaswell Note that that post is about “Teams” not “Stack Overflow for Teams (aka Channels)”. The former was a project that landed in a way and was [then unshipped](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330427/the-un-shipping-of-teams). While the original idea shares something with Channels, I don’t think any of the answers there necessarily carry over.

Answer (score 43):

Thinking from an organizational standpoint alone, and not knowing very much of what's on the other side of the fence, the one burning question I can think of is,

**Does this pave the way for push-style notifications in the inbox?**

My organization makes use of Confluence for its Wiki functionality and one of Confluence's strengths is *opt-out* push-style notifications, such as email.  Stack Overflow has the ability to let you *opt-in* to emails, but they're not as robust; you can only opt-in on answers you leave, and not really on comments.

Given that, and given how inconvenient it might be to have to check Stack Overflow repeatedly to get notifications for team-wide updates, etc, would this then make push-style notifications a feasible future feature for the rest of us?

(API would be a plus/preferred if it's feasible, but email is king for now.)

<sup>(If I like what I see of Teams I'l try to convince power people to look at it, but I have very little power in a sea of **hundreds**.)</sup>

Comment: This is definitely something we've had a lot of requests for from Enterprise users (heck, we've had a lot of requests for it from users on the public sites, going back all the way to SO's beta... So I guess it shouldn't be too surprising). I know Geoff has put some thought into it, but it's probably not something that's going to happen for the initial rollout. Maybe later though...

Comment: Some sort of push notification seems to be present on the SE app. Also, an authenticated-to RSS feed might be a good idea. Maybe.

Comment: I think we're going to need to spend some time talking about notifications once folks that have spent some time using the platform number greater than a dozen or two. There's also the question of when we _shouldn't_ send you notifications, or perhaps even be showing you 'work' content as you browse the site. Taking half-baked stabs at that this early seems like a kinda bad idea, but it's pretty clear that it will be one of the first major things we'll need to work on as folks prioritize what they'd like to see in the product next.

Comment: ...I realize at this point now I'm just being selfish, but web workers would be a *start*... Do take the time to think about this though, since it's a rather big thing.

Comment: Push notification definitely works in the mobile app on iOS

Comment: @jcolebrand: But that's the *mobile* app. I have *both* mobile apps installed. I'm acutely aware of mobile push notifications. I want *desktop* push notifications.

Comment: Just making sure. Not everyone is aware. However with my watch and phone paired for notifications I just got a buzz on my wrist that I had a notification and was able to quickly open the site to respond to you.

Answer (score 37):

Will there be an option to install Teams on-premises? The issue with a lot of collaboration tools is that they are SaaS and run in "the cloud", but that is an instant no-go for our company simply because we don't want our data anywhere outside our local servers, especially not on US-based servers. I imagine that is true for a lot of companies outside the US.

Comment: It's very unlikely they'll support this.  Only high-value operations have this concern, and there just aren't many such that need this.  Since there's little demand, I doubt it will happen?

Comment: Every company's data are high-value to them, and this is a very common concern for example in Germany and often voiced in media. No one wants their user data on potentially out-of-reach servers on another continent. Especially if it may contain sensitive internal development information.

Comment: I agree (we don't keep anything in the US); maybe you're right, perhaps there's enough demand that they will do that option.

Comment: That already exists, it's called [Stack Overflow Enterprise](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise). Though it seems to be targeted towards very large corporations.

Comment: agreed. I don't see anyone using this as advertised (somewhere in the comment a sample question was posted 'how to set up our VPN'). There is no way a company would allow employees to enter such data into a public website.

Comment: Personally I would be happy if we could just ensure our data was on a server farm in a location of our choice (don't mind it being Saas as long as I can choose not to have it in the US)

Comment: In practise, having a cloud in germany should solve pretty much all european data concerns. (Assuming security and such are in good order). Hence an on premise solution would likely not be worthwile.

Answer (score 28):

Is the structure of Teams going to be inherently hierarchial (e.g. a Boss/Administrator and several Users/Underlings/Team Members/Peons), with privileges doled out based on pay grade, or will there be room for egalitarian teams (everyone has the same privileges) or meritocratic teams (e.g. where privileges must be *earned* via participation, not  by paying money or already holding some position of power)?

Comment: Currently there is only one elevated role (Admins) who have the ability to edit the settings of the Team and manage members

Answer (score 27):

Are there plans for any bleed-over in terms of reputation, badges, privileges, or penalties between the main site and Teams, or will they be hermetically sealed?

For example:

- A user has been Question Banned on the main site. Are they still allowed to ask questions on a Team?
- A user has been put into Timed Suspension on the main site. May they participate on a Team?
- A user has a high reputation on the main site. Does that give them extra privileges on a Team? That could be interesting - leading to organizations attempting to recruit high-reputation users onto their Team in order to gain access to their high-reputation privileges ("We need some new recruits with 10k rep who can see and vote to undelete all the stuff that John deleted when he left."). Alternately, a Team might attempt to recruit low-reputation users who would be powerless to oppose the wishes of the Team leader ("We're only hiring people with less than 3k rep, The Boss doesn't like it when people vote to close his memos.").
- A user on a Team has been making posts that would be acceptable on the main site, but that violate internal Team rules. May the user be suspended from the main site as a penalty?
- A user on a Team has been making posts on their Team site that are unacceptable anywhere on SO, either the main site or a Team site, but their main site behavior is impeccable. May they be suspended from the main site as a penalty?
- A user has done quite well for themself on a Team. Does this translate to any benefits (e.g. rep, badges) on the main site? Can a Team authorize the granting of main-site benefits?

Comment: _"in order to gain access to their high-reputation privileges"_ Why wouldn't there be diamond moderators?

Comment: @JoshCaswell diamond moderators are supposed to be impartial, 10k users might have more leeway in that regard to take actions that benefit their Team (as opposed to the site in general).

Comment: Rep is separate from main (and even from other teams where you might participate). There's no 'bleed over' of privileges (or a revocation of them, such as what happens if you're suspended). The mechanism behind that also happens to resemble a large caliber gun, and appears to be directly pointed at our feet, so I can't promise that a bug in this area won't make headlines - but in _theory_ it's all separate.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I think team admins will be able to appoint their own internal moderators.

Comment: Note also (just found out), if you manage to get 200 rep on a team but do _not_ yet have 200 rep on the main site, you'll get the association bonus. This isn't any different than getting it if you had 200 rep on, say, Mechanics SE. However, you'll still have to take care to not get caught voting up your coworkers too much on the public site, as those votes will be reversed just like any others (and you'll still probably get suspended from the public site for voting shenanigans). Or, tl;dr: Association bonus works as if a team were a separate SE site.

Comment: @TimPost doesn't that leave open the option for someone to create a team with a bunch of sock puppets so they can fraudulently give each of their sock puppets 200 rep from the safety of their team, which would then give each of their sock puppets a "protected" 200 rep using the association bonus. I'm not sure if the mechanics allow this, but couldn't said person just pass a 200 rep bounty through their socks in the team, drastically reducing the amount of work required to create a sock army?

Comment: @Tiny You're forgetting the part where they have to give us their billing info and credit card details ;) In the extremely unlikely event that we get a rep farm so well financed that they can afford a team, we would shut it down.

Comment: @TimPost Do you mean the association bonus should work when joining a Team? Or only the other way around is true?

Comment: @Adinia I _think_ both ways are ultimately going to be true as teams will (for that purpose) just be treated as if they were like any other site, however I don't think I can confirm that until a whole lot of glue finishes drying and someone figures out how to get that cat off of it. Will update (or more likely post the initial feature set) once it solidifies a bit more.

Comment: As a note, the behavior @TimPost mentions earlier about how earning 200 rep in a Team will grant you the association bonus on the network has been changed. This no longer is the case as of this posting. While we had required a credit card to create a Team, we've recently changed this policy to allow people to try out Teams without a credit card, so we've stopped awarding the bonus for the reason mentioned by user4639281 above.

Answer (score 19):

How private are the Q&A on Stack Overflow for Teams? Are posts stored in plain text in the database? Will Stack Exchange employees be able to view them?

Comment: Yes. The posts will be stored on the same servers as the rest of the SE network. The posts are all plain text. Why would you expect something different?

Comment: @jcolebrand Who says I have any expectation at all?

Comment: Your comment implies an expectation that it would somehow be able to be encrypted.

Comment: @jcolebrand I think you are reading more into my question than is there. I don't know how the underlying SE engine works with the current sites, so I have nothing "different" to compare to.

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com would be a great place for you to start then. The fact that you are asking if the text in the database is encrypted when the results are plainly visible on the website makes very little sense. If the computer can decrypt it for visible view then the devs can see it too. How would you propose they manage destructive user posts? What about people who leave a company and come back to damage the reputation of their employer before they can be deactivated here? I'm trying to help clarify. what is the benefit of any sort of encryption here?

Comment: It is surprising that the **private network** posts would be stored unencrypted on SO's cloud - or not segregated in some other secure way.  This means that all SO employees, or indeed anyone kicking around on that cloud, can read everything written by private teams.  This eliminates many industries and probably any large organization.  It's very unlikely GE or NASA would have all their internal QA cheerfully readable by the staff of a QA web site.

Comment: @jcolebrand The benefit is that plaintext Q&A will make this feature useless to any company. The type of knowledge that SO for Teams proposes to archive includes commercial secrets that no company that plans to stay in business is willing to expose. p.s. I'm not sure how a public-facing web page tells me anything about how the data is stored in the database. I especially don't understand how the existing database tells me anything about the functionality of a new feature that is not yet publicly available.

Comment: hi @jcolebrand - "The posts will be stored on the same servers as the rest of the SE network"  I'm confused, do you work for SE, jcole?  Or, you read this somewhere above?

Comment: @fattie I follow the dev architects on twitter

Comment: I see, cool, thanks for explaining .. absolutely no problem to me but just so you know it gave the impression you were giving a definitive company answer, cheers.

Comment: Actually for what it's worth (@Code-Apprentice and others), TimPost above (see comments) mentions that "and the content is going to be private".  I may have misunderstood but perhaps that means that indeed there'll just be an instance (/whatever technical solution) for each of these private SOs.   cheers

Comment: Wait - conversely it appears there's something called "Stack Overflow Enterprise" which is indeed your own instance (I think).  Anyway .. whatever!

Comment: I think this is a great question. No company in their right minds would use "Stackoverflow Teams" unless they are guaranteed their data is safe.

Answer (score 15):

Will it be possible to close a Channels question as a dupe target of questions on *any* Stack Exchange site? E.g., if my company starts a channel and someone asks how to recursively list the contents of a directory in Windows, can I mark it as a dupe of https://superuser.com/q/879678/156577?

Comment: No, while organizations will likely be able to define custom close reasons, and one of those might be something similar to "This is general reference" (which we might advise against, depending) we probably won't be supporting that for perf and logistics reasons alone (as well as being equally reticent to consider migrations from teams). You could, though, just answer with a comment or link and close the question as O/T because "no need to use our team space for this" or something similar. We'll of course listen to all use cases and help people achieve what they want using what's available.

Comment: In general I do find this a very annoying thing in stackoverflow different sites that there are many duplicates and you can't do anything about them because those are separate sites. Like softwareengineering site for example.

Answer (score 15):

Will Teams be able to configure their site to allow members of the public to register or post? This could work to allow an organization to have a *public* Q&A site about their organization - e.g. an "Ask [Organization]" site.

@FTP mentioned privacy as a "major use case". Will privacy be *required* or just *available*?

Comment: Right now it's going to work from a domain level (and yes, we're being careful in light of recent exploits taking advantage of that) and totally private. The whole idea of bringing better support infrastructure so you can better support users, or even more, is totally on the table once we get the initial version stable. I'd imagine it starting with the need to make canonical / industrial knowledge stuff that doesn't need to be private public, but curated only by a team, as that seems to be the biggest initial use case. We have to see when we have more than dozens using it.

Comment: +1 on having publicly available team-based Q&A - like a mini stack-exchange based around our own product... I'll admit I looked at this post and hoped that's what this was... :)

Answer (score 12):

Would there be an ability to add tags on this that won't be visible to the further Stack Overflow community?

For instance, having the tag of `internal-reporter`, or `<insert-product-name-here>`, so that we have the ability to organise our questions based on the products they relate to?

Comment: Yes, Teams can "pull in" tags from the public site or create their own tags that exist only inside the team in their own namespace.  In all cases all of the content is only available to members of the team.

Comment: This might be a trivial case, but what happens if a tag is created in the team, and then the same tag is created on the public site? Would the main site tag override/affect the local tag?

Answer (score 11):

What are the officially supported ways of separating your work activity from your private activity on SE? I suspect that many users that participate on non-technical sites would want to keep that activity separate from their work activity, both inside their company channel and on sites they use for work-related questions.

The two major options here are to have both, work and private activity on the same SE account, or to create two separate accounts.

- are there any visible connections between the channel activity and public SE activity?

  - Can a channel user or admin connect the two?
  - Can a community moderator or regular public SE user that is a member of the channel connect the user on the public SE site with the user inside the channel?
- Are separate work and private accounts officially supported now? And I mean true official blessing, not the toleration of benign socks with many caveats we have right now.

Answer (score 10):

What's the moderation model for Teams? I can think of the following obvious possibilities:

- Teams are moderated only by the teams themselves, with regular SO moderators stepping in in only the most egregious cases (e.g. illegal content, predatory behavior).
- Team moderators and SO moderators share duties with respect to Team content, sort of like City Cops (with jurisdiction only in the city) and County Cops (with jurisdiction both in the city and outside).
- Team moderators moderate with respect to internal Team rules, and SO moderators moderate with respect to general SO rules (e.g. removing NAA answers, deleting spam, enforcing English Only, etc.).
- There is no Team-specific moderation, SO moderators will have full jurisdiction to moderate within Teams.

Comment: Considering that a major use case for Teams is sharing information that should not be known outside of the organization, option 0 is the one that makes most sense: SO moderators have no privileges in regard to Teams.

Comment: @FTP what about organizations that don't really care who knows the information, but just want a Q&A platform that works well and is mostly free of spam?

Comment: @Robert my understanding is that teams will be self-moderated and completely invisible to mods unless we're a member and we will have no responsibility/privileges automatically carried over whatsoever regarding them because of the public SO ♦.

Comment: @JonClements is correct, Teams are entirely moderated by themselves as the content is completely private to the Team itself.  Moderators have no ability to see that a given Team even exists, let alone the content or members of it.

Answer (score 8):

What is the recommended team size for this product? Will it work right away with ten, or only begin to show its usefulness after a few years with people coming and going?

Comment: The major use case for Teams revolves around organizations where there aren't really enough contributors to justify having an enterprise instance, but the need to ask / answer questions using the Stack Overflow model is pretty clear. So, yeah - teams of 2 or 3 will work just fine as long as folks commit to using it, and make it a habit of getting knowledge out of email archives and into the site. This helps make sure there's always something to answer (or ask), and keeps people fed with stuff to do there.

Comment: Again, the big hinge for success there is consciously making sure you get information out of the dark places where it's not so easy to find, and into Q&A format. As long as that happens, teams of 2 or 3 will thrive just as happily as teams of 20 - 60 or even more.

Answer (score 1):

One feature that might be useful is if each new question for an individual team is automatically and permanently tagged with the current version or most recent commit to master in the team's project. Perhaps SO Teams could be optionally linked to the team's Git repository?

The advantage of this is that SO Teams questions will be heavily targeted to their own software, to the degree that refactorings and new features can cause old questions to go out of date very quickly. If I find a question in my SO Team board that seems to precisely describe the problem I'm facing, I won't know right away whether it's gone obsolete, especially if it's older. If I can quickly see the state of the project when the question was asked, I can checkout that commit/visit it on my Git host and quickly see whether the code I have a question about has been significantly changed.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a 6 months free trial period - it's the sort of tool which I'll struggle to get budget for without evidence that it works.

Answer (score -2):

Will Stack Exchange employees (programmers, sysadmins, contractors, 3d party providers, management) be able to view the posts of Teams ?

--

Note, @jeremy below has explained

> they're not spinning up any private infrastructure. They already offer that: **Stack Exchange Enterprise**. This is the low-resource more-intrgrated less-secure cheaper alternative. You're right that most bigcos won't use it. They're not the primary market..

Comment: If they have access to the database running this, why *wouldn't* they be able to see it...?

Comment: huh?  what "database"?  in a situation like this you just spin off an aws instance for each private client.

Comment: ... I'm fairly sure they're not using AWS for this.  Far be it for us to start solutionizing a way around this, though.

Comment: (Why would they not be using AWS, or GC?)  Hmm, whatever topology they're using - I don't know  - such "private" SOs would have to be .. private.   Right??  GE or NASA will not use a postboard system, for employees to discuss their internal technology where ... anyone at the ISP can read it!!!!  SO must be spinning off a private-whatever for each private customer.

Comment: @Fattie they're not spinning up any private infrastructure. They already offer that: Stack Exchange Enterprise. This is the low-resource more-intrgrated less-secure cheaper alternative. You're right that most bigcos won't use it. They're not the primary market. They get high-touch b2b sales spam for Enterprise instead.

Comment: @Fattie are you in the administration of GE or NASA? I think you fundamentally misunderstand everything about this. If you really want to have a legitimate discussion where we can explain how security works on the internet, then I am somewhat happy to do so. But if you can read the data, then so can anyone transmitting the data, including the people who wrote the software you're using, as they know how things are built. Yes, if they don't have the key they can't decrypt it, but HTTP doesn't really have a great mechanism for force transmitting that key all the time.

Comment: Secondly, they do actually have a for-pay service where your data is not mingled in with the SE systems. https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise

Comment: Thirdly, they very openly talk about their infrastructure https://stackexchange.com/performance https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/02/17/stack-overflow-the-architecture-2016-edition/ https://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/11/22/what-it-takes-to-run-stack-overflow/ https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/2zd9lz/we_keep_stack_exchange_stack_overflow_server/ https://blog.serverfault.com/2015/03/05/how-we-upgrade-a-live-data-center/

Comment: They literally run their own colo datacenters and have tested their failover before https://blog.serverfault.com/2012/10/30/failing-over-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange-for-sandy/

Comment: (hey @jcolebrand, are you talking to the right person?  Did you mean to post the comment under the other question?  WHo has mentioned encryption?)

Comment: @JeremyBanks - totally makes sense, cheers

Comment: @Fattie between this answer and another you are using the same points, so I consolidated any conversation to one post.  You said "It is surprising that the private network posts would be stored unencrypted on SO's cloud". You also keep going on and on on comments here about how it's untenable that they wouldn't completely absolve themselves of any ability to see the data forever. It's like you've never heard of an NDA or a SaaS.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? This is a worthwhile question.