# Why does my Stack Overflow for Teams URL start with a /c/?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams

I created a team using Stack Overflow for Teams.

I observe that the base team URL is `stackoverflow.com/c/TEAM_NAME` and was curious, why?

What does `/c/` stand for?

To investigate, I did a search for every word the started with "c" on [the Stack Overflow Teams page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams):

> [image]
>
> `create` `can` `check` `contribute` `contributors` `college` `classrooms` `currently` `canceled` `convert` `credit` `card` `charge` `cancel` `center` `calculator` `contributions`

But none of them seem to fit. ☹️

In fairness, the alternatives have trade-offs:

- `stackoverflow.com/team/TEAM_NAME` is a bit longer, with a bit less "cool "factor.
- `stackoverflow.com/t/TEAM_NAME` is kind-of ugly in a proportional font: look at "/t/".
- `TEAM_NAME.stackoverflow.com` may feel incongruous with the information architecture.

But if we're picking an arbitrary letter, wouldn't we default to `x`–the coolest letter?

- `stackoverflow.com/x/TEAM_NAME`

Comment: It is only 26 letters in English

Comment: Could really also stand for company, I mean (i think) that's what they are aiming at

Comment: We should have chosen  as prefix for teams, as its the coolest unicode character, however it may give a less professional meaning to other people

Comment: `let TEAM_NAME = 'meta';`

Comment: It should definitely use `/t/` -- making it a T & A(nswers) site.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

> But if we're picking an arbitrary letter, wouldn't we default to x–the coolest letter?

can categorically confirm character "c" completes candidate criteria concerning coolness; case closed, casually

Comment: creative composition.

Comment: can't compete.  consecutive 'c's criteria completely confounding

Comment: Creat Cesponse.

Comment: @L_Church contradictory canonical categorization causing confusion; carefully consider cancelling comment

Comment: cue conduct causing complete conclusion confounding categorization causing confusion.

Comment: comment ceased.

Comment: cannot comment cause...cause...cause crap!

Comment: C-c-c-combo breaker!

Comment: @DanielJames *Cool concoction!

Answer (score 86):

"c" stands for channels. In the [introductory post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352065/introducing-channels-qa-for-engineering-teams) they were called as channels:

> > Channels are a means for organizations to provide a quiet space for their engineering teams to collaborate pretty much unrestricted and unstructured apart from public Q&A on Stack Overflow through a more private means that we're calling a channel. Channels are for organizations both large and small and do not in any way affect public Q&A.

However when they were released, they were rebranded as "Stack Overflow for teams". From this post [Coming Soon: Stack Overflow For Teams!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364145/coming-soon-stack-overflow-for-teams):

> Stack Overflow For Teams is what has come full circle as the product
>   that we've previously described as channels.
>
> Channels are an architectural concept that are primarily
>   inward-facing, but serve as the foundation to allow things like Stack
>   Overflow For Teams to exist.

which is why you can see that [channels](/questions/tagged/channels) is a [synonym](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/stackoverflow-for-teams/synonyms) for [stackoverflow-for-teams](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-for-teams).

Comment: This is correct. We kept channels as the name for the architecture and environment in things like code and server names. So `/c/` as the url is short for "channels". One of the main things keeping "channels" as an "architectural concept" accomplished was letting us rebrand without having to go and rename a bunch of infrastructure and code.

Comment: @Kyle, I still like the name channels. :(

Comment: @KyleBrandt to be fair, we *could* have changed the prefix relatively easily - we just didn't choose to; we could just pretend that "c" means "customer", "client", or something?