# Why does the URL for questions on Teams not include the title slug?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, hyperlinks, title

I just noticed that the URL for questions on Teams doesn't include the title slug, unlike on the public Q&A platform, e.g.: `https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/{TEAM_SLUG}/questions/{QUESTION_ID}`.

I can only assume that it's to prevent accidentally leaking sensitive info when copy-pasting the URL somewhere else, but is it really the case?

Comment: Didn't public Q/A had a feature where even for deleted questions, you would still get the title returned? I assume in teams you don't want that to happen, so yes, for privacy reasons I expect the slug to be removed on purpose.

Comment: I could imagine the inclusion of the title being relevant on the public site for SEO while this is just not applicable in StackOverflow for Teams.

Comment: I also wonder what the `/c/` part is?

Comment: @Marijn: [Why does my Stack Overflow for Teams URL start with a /c/?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367305/why-does-my-stack-overflow-for-teams-url-start-with-a-c)

Comment: Your guess is pretty close to the truth, but I'll pass this on to the Teams folks to see if they can provide an answer themselves.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct. This is to prevent leaking sensitive information via URL.
It is highly likely that question titles and tags will contain enough sensitive information such that leaking a database of URLs would be catastrophic (e.g. references to secret project names, upcoming releases, etc).

It's also basically impossible to safeguard URLs. They're stored in too many places and too many systems have access to them.

So, we decided to get rid of them. This is the same choice that Slack has made (channel names used to be in the URL, now they're obfuscated) and many others.