# Channel notification not showing up on stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, achievements-dialog, stack-overflow-for-teams

I happened to be on [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) when I got a notification from a [channel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/352065/559745), but when I clicked on it I saw nothing:

[image] 
[image]

This happens for achievements as well as for inbox messages.

On all other Stack Exchange sites it works as expected:

[image]

Comment: Seen the same; downvotes don't always show up for some reason

Answer (score 2):

There were a three issues in play here.

1. no rep history being reported (even on SO.com). That is fixed.
2. Seeing different things on SO.com than you see on other Q&A sites. This is also fixed.
3. Not seeing Teams updates in inbox/achievements on SE.com. This is a security issue and will not be fixed anytime soon.