# Stack Overflow for Teams login via Active Directory

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

We're thinking of using [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams), but I can't seem to find out how to use that with our existing [Active Directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory).

Any references?

Comment: I don't think that is possible at the moment.

Comment: A nice feature request, but this would be very difficult to achieve with on-prem AD. It could be set up to work with Azure AD I guess.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352065/introducing-channels-qa-for-engineering-teams#comment491883_352110 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/352118/1663001

Comment: @DavidG I don't know the details very well but I think AD supports OAuth via ADFS, something along those lines? On-premise AD would work too then.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow for Teams doesn't currently have Single Sign On as an option (though we are evaluating adding it for the future).

If you have a large team (500+ users), then you might be a fit for [Stack Overflow Enterprise](https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise) which does support both SAML and AD based SSO. Check that page and submit the form on that page for more info.

Comment: Thanks, @alex-miller. So this means it's either enterprise or no AD support at all (not even Azure based)?

Comment: @YaOg he mentioned they are evaluating it for the future.  FOr now only Enterprise has it.

Comment: @YaOg definitely something we're interested in building for Teams. we just haven't *yet*.

Comment: is this still true of stack overflow for teams?