# What is a "team" in Stack Overflow for Teams?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I am not sure how teams operate in the new Stack Overflow for Teams that is sold to enterprises. I understand what a team is and I'm sure that a user can be a member of any number of teams.

When, as user, I'm logged to Stack Overflow for Teams, how are teams implemented?

Do I change of teams every time I will work with another team as I must change of Stack? site when I'm in Stack Overflow and will go to Mathematical or Super User sites to post another question?

Are there some site's pages that allow work on more than one team at the same time?

Example: having the choice to list all questions in one team OR all questions in all connected teams OR all questions in all selected teams.

I do not have the possibility to use the Stack Overflow for Teams free trial.

Comment: Probably a first step for background: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352065/introducing-channels-qa-for-engineering-teams

Comment: Teams you are a member of would appear in the left navigation bar, and you would use that to change teams, if I am not mistaken. Check [this image](https://venturebeat.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/stack-overflow-for-teams-sample-2.png?resize=1024%2C717&strip=all), for example.

Comment: @yivi: thanks, this is the answer that I searched :-) Team is like a context defined in one same site.

Comment: @tensibai: thanks for your help; but this article speak more about "chanels" than "teams". "chanels" seems to be for small enterprise that will have a private domain using chanels. But "teams" seems to be for StackOverflow for enterprise.

Comment: @schlebe "channels" and "teams" are exactly the same thing. "Channels" is the name the product had before it was released. [Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) is oriented for small/medium teams, [Enterprise](https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise) is for very big organizations (at least 500 users are recommended for it to be really useful, if I remember correctly). It's a private, hosted instance.

Comment: @schlebe channels for the former name for teams, it has been renamed during the beta IIRC