# Stack Overflow for Teams usage statistic

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, statistics

I am going to submit a report to my management about getting Stack Overflow for Teams for our company.

When I read [the pricing page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/pricing), I saw the following sentence.

> Used by more than 100,000 organizations around the globe

Does it mean that Stack Overflow for Teams (the paid version) is used by 100,000 organizations — or that the public Stack Overflow site is used by 100,000 organizations?

Because if 100,000 organizations use Stack Overflow for Teams (the paid version) it is very easy to convince my management that we need to try it.

[image]

Comment: Why would that be a statistic on the public site's usage, on the teams page? I'm certain that number would be way higher for the public site.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, I also thought it, but it seems like it should be less than 100,000 in paid version also. If they archive this, it is a huge achievement.

Comment: Why does it seem like it should be less? And why on earth would the number of other users affect your decision to use it or not.

Comment: @ivarni Come on, everyone is doing it!

Comment: But but.. what if there are more organisations **not** using it than there are organisations using it?

Comment: Please note that the price for Teams has gone up significantly a few days ago, I suspect that some organizations will be dropping out of it because of this (If they are not grandfathered into the old pricing scheme)

Comment: @xdtTransform can they really find stuff on Teams without the benefit of google? Built-in search has been notoriously bad. Did we ever get [the overhaul we were promised](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352065/introducing-channels-qa-for-engineering-teams/352082#comment491517_352082)? Maybe it's just less of a concern in a Teams instance with so little content compared to the public site.

Comment: @canon, That's why we do not plan on trying SO team. I guess for some people SO team new question will just be the new google. And other will close dupe it. Then it will be consider work harassment and they will have the CoC talk.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton: and your point is?

Answer (score 7):

When we were writing the original copy, we pulled numbers about broader Stack Overflow usage. But now that we see it in context on the page, we agree that it can be misinterpreted. We have moved forward with adjusting it. Although Stack Overflow’s Q&A product (public or private) is used by developers at more than 100,000 organizations, our Private Q&A product is newer and currently used by thousands of organizations (specific numbers are not disclosed, as we're a private organization).