# Is it OK to use SO to reach local sensor/big data professionals/enthusiasts?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, old-teams

A friend is working on a (local authority-sponsored) project which aims to bring together professionals and enthusiasts interested in "big data", with the aim of using sensors to track various aspects of the urban environment, and making the data available for anyone to use in their projects. It is aimed at anyone from Arduino enthusiasts to remote-sensing professionals.

She asked me if SO could be used to reach people who might be interested in this project. I said I thought SO wasn't the right forum for something like that, but I thought I'd ask anyway:

- Is SO or any SE site or meta-site appropriate for reaching out to programmers who may be interested in such a project?
- If posting a question was inappropriate, would taking out a paid advertisment on SO allow me to target people with specific interests and in a specific country?
- Could the Jobs or Teams feature be used for this? (This is about a non-profit open-source project, there are no jobs on offer.)
- Is there a better third-party site or forum to use for this?

Any suggestions welcomed.

Comment: *there are no jobs on offer* - Do you mean that there aren't any *paying* jobs or that there aren't going to be *any* positions, not even unpaid volunteer ones, for this whatsoever?

Comment: You definitely can't post a question that's actually just an advertisement for this. The [advertising page](http://business.stackoverflow.com/advertise) for Stack Overflow states: *You can target Stack Exchange visitors by Geography, Reputation and Tags.*

Comment: [Data Science SE](http://datascience.stackexchange.com) is for Q&A about, well, what it says on the tin. But just like any other SE site, it's only for topical Q&A. What you're asking seems to be outside the purview of Q&A altogether.

Comment: @BSMP As I understand it, the local authority wants to create a  platform aimed at bringing interested parties together. An existing agency (where my friend works) has been tasked with creating this platform, but it will not be running any of the resulting projects, and as such is not hiring anyone.

Comment: Is the project open source and looking for programmers to write actual code? If so, you might [advertise it on the site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314722/open-source-advertising-1h-2016).

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks, I didn't know about this.

Comment: A paid advertisement is almost certainly an option (although someone from the team would have to weigh in), but other than that, I think this is completely outside the purview of SE. Unless, of course, you're hiring, in which case you could use Jobs.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it OK to use SO to reach local sensor/big data professionals/enthusiasts?

Unless you have a job to offer in conjunction with this group, Jobs wouldn't work for you. But you could create a team focused on the topic of "Arduino enthusiasts [and] remote-sensing professionals". We currently have many interest groups already using Teams. If you're not already in the private beta, [you can sign up here.](https://docs.google.com/a/stackoverflow.com/forms/d/1CpgNiGZ0XNUqueXc4dydraliKZqZnJO7HWEuesXYkmQ/viewform)