# What is the proper way to attract people to the open source project you're trying to build?

Tags: feature-request

I'm writing a speech on PJAX for an upcoming [Code Camp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Camp), heard that people are able to attract people to the coding portions of their presentations, and was wondering how exactly to attract contributors to their project.

I'm trying to flesh out a JavaScript PJAX "driver" with this project: https://github.com/Jquery-PJAX/PJAX

Comment: This question isn't off topic.  There is a way you can do it.

Comment: Why so many downvotes?

Answer (score 4):

The only way to do that here on Stack Overflow is to submit it as part of the [Open Source Advertising](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314722/1079354) cycle.  You'd have to create an ad that described the campaign, and your project would have to be beholden to the criteria there.

If you find that your project does *not* fit the criteria, there would be no other way you could use to garner attention here on Stack Overflow that would be considered valid.

Comment: Well, you could also buy advertising space for pretty much anything if you wanted to.