# Open Source Advertising - 2H 2016

Tags: discussion, community-ads, open-source-advertising

We're now entering the second half of 2016. And with it, we enter a new round of Free Vote-Based Advertising for Open Source Projects for Stack Overflow. We are clearing the leaderboards for the second half of the year.

Here is your chance to create a [Free Vote-Based Advertisement for an Open Source Project](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/). Create a graphical ad for an open source programming project and post it as an answer to this question (in the right format), and it will feed live remnant ads on Stack Overflow.

### Ad Requirements

It must be an advertisement **soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code**. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source. It's for finding programmers who will help contribute code or other programmery things (documentation, code review, bug fixes, etc.).

Your ad should be an original creation which has not previously appeared on Stack Overflow. Please do not resubmit entries that have appeared as ads on Stack Overflow in previous periods.

In order to work, the answers you post to this question **must** conform to the following rules.

### Answer Template

```
[![alternative text if image is not displayed][1]][2]
    
  [1]: http://image-url
  [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to add any commentary, keep it in the comments.

### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **300 pixels by 250 pixels**, or twice that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
- Must have a 1px border if (part of) the background is white, 2px if the image is high DPI.

The output, which ultimately will be served in an ad slot on Stack Overflow, can be previewed by clicking through to this URL:

http://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/300x250

### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be served up by that URL and shown on Stack Overflow. You can see all the ads that currently make the threshold and meet our criteria on this page:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/327559

**Note:** *As with previous [iterations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314722/open-source-advertising-1h-2016) of this program, if the exact ad image has already appeared in a previous cycle, it is not eligible to be run in this cycle. However, if you design a new ad, it will be able to appear if it gets enough votes*.

Comment: If the exact **ad** with the same link has appeared before, it is not eligible, or if the **project it promotes** has appeared before?

Comment: @cat The question seems to come up often; I'm surprised the copy+paste for these posts hasn't been updated. But [here's your answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281524/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2015#comment139139_281524) (the ? is one line above): `The ad itself -Grace Note♦ Jan 7 '15 at 14:07`

Comment: do we have to be the owner of a project to promote it?

Comment: Just to clarify, are we voting based on both our interest in a particular project and the ad design or purely based on the ad design?

Comment: @Hack-R, I believe it is mainly supposed to be based on ad design and suitability for SO advertising, but as with anything else on SO, if you have a reason for voting a certain way, I think that's up to you.

Comment: Can I submit multiple ads for the same project ?

Comment: @Hack-R Your reasons for supporting an ad are your own to make - the basic idea is "Do I want to see this ad on SO, do I want others to see it on SO?" Remember that in this case, these are the open source projects of your peers, so this is basically a way to show them your support.

Comment: @Subin My first inclination is "No". If you have more ads at 6+ votes, then you have that many more presences than every other project, which seems a bit off on the spirit of the initiative here. Also, if you burn out all your design ideas in one year-half, then that makes problems for following runs of this.

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC Nope! Also, thanks for making your username un-typable. :)

Comment: @cat If you start with C it shows up in the auto complete :)

Comment: New year, new question soon?

Comment: @martijn-pieters I have updated the answer. The contribution tagline was somehow missed when I updated the answer in mast suggestion (check in comments)

Comment: I'm a big fan of the open source ads...is there to be a 2017 iteration?  Almost to March now...

Comment: @GraceNote We're completely skipped over 1H 2017...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open Source Advertising - 2017](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349017/open-source-advertising-2017)

Answer (score 95):

[image: Contribute to Atom, the hackable text editor]

Comment: Hm. Don't get get me wrong, I like this particular design - but are you going to post basically the same thing for *n* projects, with *n* > 1?

Comment: @RadLexus Yes. For Atom and Nylas. I haven't thought of any other projectcs, and if I do I expect I will use a different design, but I thought it suited both of these projects well.

Comment: Minor nitpick, but i don't think the comma belongs in there. The official website doesn't have it.

Comment: @Scimonster the website has a new line which wouldn't fit into the ad neatly so I replaced with a comma. Would you prefer no comma there?

Comment: Yes, without the comma. It feels clunky like this.

Comment: The comma is an eyesore.

Comment: Arrggh, that comma...

Comment: @Scimonster Removed the comma

Comment: @Tim Appreciate the effort. Looks awesome now!

Comment: @edwinksl Really sorry for how long it took me :P

Comment: The fact that the `t` of `21st` is larger than the `21s` is making my eye twitch.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Made it super script

Comment: Can you update this ad to the proper (2x) size? 600x543 is *so close*!

Comment: Is this ViM like?

Comment: @AlexejMagura it's like notepad++

Comment: @Tim so no macros or internal scripting language to create your own crap?

Comment: @AlexejMagura no idea

Comment: Please tell me this isn't written in JavaScript and CoffeeScript and that it's actually written in a performant language like C or C++.  Dx

Comment: @AlexejMagura it's written in JavaScript using electron. This means it can be easily run on any operating system.

Comment: @Tim All I hear is heresy: surely this is a sign of the end times.  I just don't see how it will be able to outperform, let alone keep up with, editors such as Emacs and ViM?  It's written in a language that while portable is leaky as crap not to mention a little slow for something as intensive as a text editor.

Comment: @AlexejMagura in what way do you have performance issues with a *text editor*? I'm fairly sure it will keep up with your 50 words per minute...

Comment: @Tim What if I need to open up a 2GB file or even an 80MB file?  How long is it going to take?  Well, I can tell you one thing: pretty darn long.

Comment: @AlexejMagura if you need to open a 2GB file I'd suggest you use Vim. Do you often have to open a 2GB file?

Comment: @Tim exactly: why should I use another text editor when I'd need to switch back and forth between text editors for different tasks?  Why not just use one that can do everything, like ViM and Emacs.  And yes, I frequently open large files at work, some of them even in excess of 2GB.

Comment: @AlexejMagura why use atom? It looks nice.

Answer (score 54):

[image: Julia: A fresh approach to technical computing]

Answer (score 37):

[image: GraphHopper Open Source Routing Engine]

Comment: Try online https://graphhopper.com/maps/ and ask questions here https://discuss.graphhopper.com/c/graphhopper And if you downvote let me know why :)

Comment: Ad feedback: if you shifted the text up a bit and drew some posts on the hills on the right, you could make it look like a gigantic billboard overhanging the road (which is what I thought it was when I first saw the ad).

Comment: Ah, nice idea - thanks. Will try. What do you mean with 'posts on the hills'? Like a bridge?

Comment: Like so https://graphhopper.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/oss-ad2-300x250.png ? (not sure about the slight yellow from the spotlights)

Comment: Also if you can make it 600 x 500, that would be nice - up to 30.7 use screens bigger than 1920 x 1080 and a significant portion of those are high DPI users.

Comment: GraphHopper is only about routing, not geocoding or visualization. Read this section of the readme: https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper#for-the-web Do not understand your complain about the 'natural' thing, please explain.

Comment: BTW: we have 'good first issues' lowering the barrier for beginning :) https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3A%22good+first+issue%22

Comment: Finding zip codes is geocoding. Regarding 'naturalness': We have a community, we are real people, we have principles, we love OpenStreetMap and what we do. Much more than cold, hard programming :)

Answer (score 36):

[image: Contribute to VeraCrypt]

Comment: @EngineerDollery Crypt is short for encryption...  TrueCrypt was an extremely popular encryption tool that is now defunct. Since that popular project died this ad is just saying to resurrect it with the most popular fork, which is called VeraCrypt. It's nothing to do with like burial crypts or anything like that. Sorry if this was confusing...

Comment: Funny. Possible improvements: the veracrypt logo&font is kind of diffuse, also it is bigger than 150kb. I've used a color palette to go under 100kb

Comment: This is another one of those ads that doesn't really tell you what the project is or what its mission is. Even if you go to the linked project page, you're overwhelmed with technical details and no vision. You have to tell people what the purpose is. "Resurrect FOSS Data Security" is a poor slogan for that reason; it doesn't mean anything. Also, as others have pointed out, this is a rather poor-quality ad. The main logo is very blurry, the tagline fonts are jagged and have terrible kerning, the artwork is cartoony which contrasts poorly with the corporate-looking logos...

Comment: @CodyGray I would disagree that it's the job of a still picture ad to give the entire background of a software project. TrueCrypt was exceedingly popular, so a *lot* of people will get it from that and for those who don't "data security" combined with the word "crypt" should connect the dots. If someone is too slow to get that and too lazy to Google it, I wouldn't expect them to be much of a potential contributor anyway. It's not like this is a commercial. It's a picture. IMHO it's already got too much text on it.

Comment: theB and @EgineerDollery if your questions have been answered could you delete your comments? I added the "Contribute Now" text and this was never intended to have anything to do with a burial crypt (that would make for a heck of a dark scary-ass ad!). On that note I always thought of "TrueCrypt" as being more of a pun on "True Crip" (as in Crips and Bloods) than on like "Tales from the Crypt".

Comment: I can agree slightly about the cartoony grass. On the other hand, I got the point right away, and I've never even heard of TrueCrypt before. Also, who ever talks about crypts anymore that that should be the first thing to come to mind?

Comment: Right, @hack. The still picture doesn't have to do it, but *something* has to do it. Like I said, I tried clicking on the link to the GitHub project page, and it lacks a concise summary of the project's aims, also. If the goal here is to solicit contributors, you need to have a better public face. How should I know if I want to get involved in contributing to your project? You have to figure out a way to get me interested. "Yet Another Cryptography Library" is not really interesting.

Comment: A crypt is a lot less scary than a major gang from South-Central LA! And I doubt if above else would make that connection, especially given the graveyard image. And, no, I'm not deleting my comment.

Comment: While the joke is funny, the ad as a whole doesn't feel super professional. It also doesn't mean anything to people who don't know what TrueCrypt is (apparently a lot more people than I expected!). If people don't know that TrueCrypt was one of the very, very few choices for FOSS on-the-fly disk-encryption tools (and not just a crypto library), they're a lot less likely to see the importance.

Answer (score 34):

[image: coala - linting and fixing code for 55+ languages]

Comment: This was made possible thanks to the help of [Beatrix Bodó](http://trixi.graphics/) who mainly designed this for us. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi,

any feedback would be truly appreciated!

You can either [file an issue, especially if it's something that can be improved](https://github.com/coala-analyzer/coala-artwork/issues/new?title=StackOverflow%20Advertisement%20Feedback) or comment right here.

Comment: By the way the [tryonline page](http://coala.io/#!/tryonline) has a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Thanks @user31782 we're on fixing that!

Comment: (If someone stumbles upon this, the link is now https://coala.io)

Answer (score 32):

[image: Goxel, Open Source Voxel Editor]

Answer (score 28):

[image: WinFsp - FUSE on Windows]

Comment: You get my upvote. But do you really need the angled banner saying "OpenSource"? It looks out of place and isn't really necessary. Maybe you could have another line on the cmd saying "contribute" with the cursor at the end waiting for the Enter stroke.

Comment: Thank for the comment and upvote. I have made a couple of changes with the icon and made the angled ribbon into a horizontal one. Hopefully this looks better.

Comment: Ok, I changed it again and added "Contribute" on the "command line". I like it! Thanks for a great idea.

Comment: Looks great! Glad to help.

Answer (score 28):

[image: nodestream - Streams your bytes. Never gets tired.]

Comment: Looks like most of the other proposals. Not necessarily a bad sign, but it hinders me to upvote.

Comment: I will not deny I took some inspiration from the other posts here. The thing is, I'm but a software developer with no design experience trying to get more contributions to my project. One of them might be a better logo design or a better SO ad. :)

Comment: I think the tagline from your GitHub page is better and more descriptive: *"Streaming library for binary data transfers"*. This one is trying to be too clever. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I have updated the punchline to reflect that on Github.

Answer (score 25):

[image: Make Java WORA Again Fork Codename One on github to bring Java into mobile devices!]

Comment: Can people who downvote please comment with an explanation for the downvote?

Comment: If I had to guess, it's because people are tired of the "Make [thing] [adjective] again" meme, and don't want to be seeing it for the next six months.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I had assumed it was because of the design. We tried to make it reminiscent of an iOS icon but it's a bit problematic with the aspect ratio.

Comment: Too many gradients, not the best choice of font which should be also not be transparent, a bit of visual confusion from the background lines.

Comment: Thanks, the main design element we were going for is the standard iOS icon (xcode inspired). The lines are based on the xcode themeing to signify the Java <-> iOS/xcode connection. I don't like the font either but it goes with the slogan. I prefer the clean design as well but most of the cleanly designed ads on this page get fewer clicks.

Comment: Codename one rules!

Comment: To a person unfamiliar with the project or Java, this means nothing. I am one of them. :)

Comment: Thanks @oldtechaa this seems to be the post with the highest number of downvotes by far yet the highest number of clicks on the ad... Unfortunately explaining something as elaborate as this in an ad is impossible. Most Java developers should be familiar with WORA (Write Once Run Anywhere) and what we are doing is making WORA work for real on mobile devices including iOS, Windows 10, Android etc. with a single code base. It's hard to explain any coding project to someone outside of the core community let alone in an ad, if you can think of a way to clarify it further that would help.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog, I think that's the thing about your project. It's good, just so specific that only the target audience will understand the ad. That's not a bad thing. I would retract my downvote after the explanation and reconsideration, but it's locked in. You're well over the threshold anyway.

Comment: @oldtechaa every project here is pretty specific, since most developers know Java as the number 1 or 2 language in the world they would probably know this. No worries about the downvote, I appreciate the fact you explained it which I can't say for the other 8 or 9 downvotes...

Answer (score 24):

[image: Orange – Data Mining Fruitful & Fun – Contribute on GitHub]

Comment: Do you want Universal Pictures' legal department coming to knock at your door? Because that yellow blob looks an afwul lot like a Minion. IANAL though.

Comment: Speaking of potential trademark infringement, the "orange" here looks an awful lot like the logotype for Orange Telecom. They *might* be different fonts, but you'd need a font expert to tell them apart. They certainly look very similar to me. The only thing different is that stylized "g" that you have. Not sure if that's enough; it looks like you're playing off of the Orange logotype.

Answer (score 18):

[image: Meshki UI]

Comment: Simplicity is the best.

Comment: Maybe "Simple. Dark. Responsive" - as it certainly is not #FFFFFF

Comment: @Tim You probably meant #000000, but that wouldn't really be black either when viewed on a screen .-.

Comment: @Underyx no it wouldn't, and yes I meant #000000. But the colour he has programmed in is not #000000... so you can't really call it black when it's not even trying to be black.

Comment: "There's something about this that's so black, it's like how much more black could this be? And the answer is none. None more black."

Answer (score 17):

[image: Contribute to wp-dynamic-css, a dynamic CSS compiler for WordPress]

Comment: It looks very similar to Tim's.

Comment: I've changed it a bit, is that better?

Comment: Looks good too, and not too similar to anyone else's. Now for the upvote.

Answer (score 16):

[image: EME - Elegant Markdown Editor]

Comment: `.jpg`, which can be seen from the jpeg artifacts in the image. Please provide a `.gif` or a `.png`.

Comment: This is my favorite Markdown editor!

Comment: The icon caught my attention, the editor's good as well. Not disappointed.

Answer (score 14):

[image: Contribute to Nylas N1 on GitHub]

Comment: PNG Image, 74.8 KB, 600 x 500 to support Retina / High DPI

Answer (score 13):

[image: CReMa: web and mobile have never been so close]

Comment: CReMa (Cordova React Material-UI) is a base project to develop web and cordova applications (for IOs and Android) all together. React is used as the core framework (https://facebook.github.io/react/) while Material-UI is used for the graphic components (http://www.material-ui.com).

Answer (score 11):

[image: MMLanScan for iOS]

Answer (score 10):

[image: YAWP! - Auto-Scalable REST API Framework]

Comment: Hi there, I would really appreciate any feedback, especially from down voters. Thanks

Comment: It seems a little too comical. That's why I downvoted.

Comment: @oldtechaa thanks for the feedback. Lets try this more sober style :)

Comment: That's better. It also shows original design, which is good. +2.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Click here for the ClickFix homepage]

Comment: I wrote this for myself and found it so beneficial that I thought it would be worth sharing with the world. Unfortunately, it is not yet written in a way that makes it accessible to *all* - this is the main reason I am posting this Ad. I've tried to make the Ad a descriptive as possible - this is software to help people with glitchy mice that fire unwanted extra clicks, making them frustrating to use. If any downvotes, please tell me why :)

Comment: It is a *very* nice-looking ad. I like the stylistic flourish that you did with the mouse cord, turning it into a heart, and I also like that you included a description of what the project's actual purpose is. But aside from the ad itself, you'd have a very hard time convincing me that this is worthwhile. A new, non-broken mouse is only a few dollars. Why spend valuable development time writing software that works around a broken one?

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for your compliments :) As for this program's value, you *do* present the approach that many people take. However, I found ClickFix very worthwhile because my expensive Logitech mouse started having problems, and customer service wouldn't send a replacement - writing this piece of software has saved me (and a few others) about $120 each.

Comment: @JasonCemra I really didn't understand [the need for] this back when I saw the advert.  Now I do because I could really use it for my mouse :D.  Sadly, Windows only though.

Answer (score 8):

[image: join Linux-stopmotion]

Comment: I like the notion - but couldn't the name be a bit more, uh, creative? Also you need punctuation on the sentences at the bottom, I think.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Make awesome web apps with PHP & JS and publish it on our Lobby Store]

Comment: Lobby is a project that is a bit hard to understand unless you download it and run. Please [let me know your feedback](https://www.facebook.com/groups/LobbyOS) and report issues on GitHub : https://github.com/LobbyOS/lobby

Comment: This ad doesn't obviously solicit contributors; could you make that more obvious?

Comment: @ArtOfCode How is it now ?

Comment: well it's certainly more obvious that you want contributors...

Comment: If you can make it 600 x 500, that would be nice - up to 30.7 use screens bigger than 1920 x 1080 and a significant portion of those are high DPI users.

Comment: The project seems fine, but the ad doesn't quite look 21st century. Your website looks great. If you could update your ad some and make it look anything like your site, that would be great and I would give you an upvote instead of a downvote.

Comment: There are lots of web app frameworks.  Your ad might be more successful if you explain what makes this framework different.

Comment: @oldtechaa I'm a coder i.e. not that great with image editing. But I have tried my best. How is it now ? I created it as an SVG, good modifications are welcomed : http://imgh.us/so.svg

Comment: It's mainly not about the art, it's the lacking content. I would never click on that ad.

Comment: It looks great now. +2. (Upvote instead of down.)

Comment: From the website I still do not understand what it does. Framework to run webapps? What has it to do with Android & Wordpress? Do you mean that it should act for the 'webapps' like what wordpress does for CMS/blogs and android for apps?

Comment: @Karussell Exactly. I'm glad you got it. @ usr1234567 I understand :) @ oldtechaa Thanks. I hope others would do the same

Comment: I would mention that this is a comparison (or mention it a bit later) as it is a bit confusing and the other interpretation that I had that you created a wordpress clone or something

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom It has an App Store to install apps automatically and publish new apps. It also has the ability to auto update itself and installed apps. Also, it works on Windows & Linux and it is only a 13 MB Zip file.

Comment: @Karussell You're right. It is confusing. I have updated the [site](https://lobby.subinsb.com). BTW, I wonder why the people who downvoted haven't commented about the issue with the ad. Do you think it's better now or needs more improvement ?

Comment: It is good for me. Probably the downvoters won't be notified after the update? Also you can change the vote only within a certain time

Comment: @Karussell, do you know what the time limit is? I changed mine almost a day after I downvoted, I think. If that's unusual, maybe they changed the time limit for this.

Comment: Great work @Subin .

Comment: I think the ad needs to clarify what it does, if that's possible. Is it something kind of like XUL, but based on HTML/CSS? That's what sprung to my mind.

Comment: @Wyatt8740 Yes, it's kind of like XUL, but apps run on an installed browser of user's choice and there is an App Store to automatically install apps.

Comment: @subin Hm, okay. Kinda neat, I guess! Not sure I'd personally use it ('app store' is a toxic term for me), but it sounds cool anyway. I'll at least try it ;)

Comment: @Wyatt8740 Thanks. In the future, we will add more useful apps for developers and non developers. Maybe those apps will help you out personally. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

[image: Framework for developing 3D web apps]

Comment: Upvoted, Seems interesting. I would definitely go though it.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Botonomous Framework]

Answer (score 0):

[image: QT Based Android Manager for Linux desktop]

Comment: Hi everyone, PhoneLin is targeted for linux desktop, which can manage Android device from Linux desktop. I would really appreciate any feedback, especially from down voters.

Comment: The name could to be clearer and larger, and the by-line smaller. It's now the other way around. Also, the logos could be smaller and the Contribute line centered (as everything else is). Is that the correct tint of green for the Android man? It looks jarringly off against the bright blue background.

Answer (score -1):

[image: Cekirdekler API: OpenCL for C# with iterative load-balancing and pipelining for multi-device systems of GPU,CPU and ACCELERATOR]

Answer (score -7):

[image: Luminous! To know every system information you need and to customize your development experience! iOS and Swift 3!]

Answer (score -9):

[image: GraphHopper Open Source Routing Engine]

Comment: You're supposed to have a black border. Notify me when this gets fixed and I'll upvote.