# Ads, should I unblock them if I won't click on them?

Tags: discussion, advertising

I was reading this article:
[Why Stack Overflow Doesn’t Care About Ad Blockers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/02/Why-Stack-Overflow-Doesnt-Care-About-Ad-Blockers/)
and I'm not sure what to do to help. I'm really cheap and I'm almost certainly never going to click on an ad. So I use an adblocker, but I whitelist pages that are not that invasive or I want to help. Is it better for Stack Overflow if I keep using the adblocker so I won't affect campaign performance, or if I whitelist the page, so the ads could be shown?

Comment: I may be completely incorrect and completely misinterpreting the blog post... But I think it doesn't really make much of a difference, if any. I think it really just comes down to personal preference.

Comment: i mean, you never know, one of the ads might actually present a tool that would be useful to you or that you'd want to contribute to.

Comment: though, to be fair, i do use an ad blocker and block all jobs related areas and advertisements while in the office. I just don't feel right seeing job advertisements while in the office, and don't want my focus drawn away any more than it already is while on SO. That's what works for me. At home, i allow them to display.

Comment: its personal preference. eg. You do not want to be distracted during job, disable them  on other hand if you are thinking for job change enable them

Comment: @KevinB if that were ever the case, my paranoia would still prevent me from clicking the ad. I'd open a new tab and google it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The answers provided already do a great job of answering your question, but as the author of the blog post I feel like I should weigh in.

Quite simply: ***You do what is best for you.***

It's great that you want to support us and help in any way you can, but we want Stack Overflow to be the best possible experience it can be for *you*. If ads are something you find annoying and you know you'll never click on them or buy anything, go ahead and block 'em.

My opinion is akin to [Kevin B's above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338359/ads-should-i-unblock-them-if-i-wont-click-on-them#comment414517_338359):

> i mean, you never know, one of the ads might actually present a tool that would be useful to you or that you'd want to contribute to.

But I tend to be a gray area, 'you never know' kind of person. Maybe one day we'll find that sweet spot of targeting and relevance and finally serve you an ad that actually interests you, and the product will be one you're willing to spend money on. Based on the hard work my team (and others) puts in I believe that most Stack Overflow users will eventually have that experience-- and many have already.

On another level, keeping ads enabled if you tend to be skeptical, critical, or otherwise disinterested in them makes your opinion and your eyes valuable to us-- even if you don't intend to purchase anything. We have plenty of users who find issues with our advertising where errors make it past our team (see [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advertising) and [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advertising) for just two examples), and we monitor Metas network-wide as a result. Or just by using the up/downvote module!
[image: downvote module]

**In summary:**

- Do what will make your experience on Stack Overflow best for *you*
- My *very* biased opinion is that you should keep them on, but only if you agree with any of my points above or in my blog post
- You are pretty terrific for asking this question

Answer (score 10):

I would say **no**.
From the [Help Center on "See Reduced Ads"](/help/privileges/reduced-ads):

> We want to emphasize that you should only re-enable banner ads if you want to see them, not because you're trying to support us financially. In fact, it doesn't really do us any good to show you ads for products that you don't want to engage with. So make the decision that's best for you, and that's the one that's best for us too.

Comment: BRB deleting this for a badge :P

Answer (score 7):

I'd say that it very much depends on exactly which ads your ad-blocker is blocking.

Stack Overflow runs a great many self-referential ads, advertising Q&A that can be found on other sites in the larger Stack Exchange network. Unless you have *very* narrow interests, these can be very interesting and relevant. (And if you *do* have very narrow interests, I'd advise you to consider expanding your horizons a bit.) Reading these Q&A are, of course, free. Like all knowledge wants to be.

Also, Stack Overflow runs [open-source advertisements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327559/open-source-advertising-2h-2016) that have been selected by the community at large. Again, you might find a project that is interesting to you, and since they're all open source, they are fully cheapskate approved.

Finally, Stack Overflow runs a *bunch* of ads for its [Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) site. Most of these simply advertise the existence of the Jobs site itself, which is arguably rather pointless for users who clearly already know about its existence (as evidenced by the fact that they have and maintain a CV there), so you might want to block these. However, there are also advertisements for specific jobs that an algorithm thinks you might be interested in, based on your tag activity. While employers have to pay to use the Jobs site, it is completely free for job seekers, so unless you absolutely love your current job and would never consider a new opportunity, you might want to keep seeing these.

The other ads displayed on the site are commercial in nature, as you implied in the question. The linked blog post makes it rather clear that Stack Overflow doesn't mind you blocking these. If you aren't ever going to click on them anyway, you aren't a target of the advertising, so preventing them from being displayed on your screen doesn't actually change anything.

It is also worth pointing out that the most annoying of these "commercial" ads—the classic "banner"-style ad that is displayed below each question—goes away automatically after you have reached [200 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads). (You can re-enable them if you want, but the same logic described above and in the blog post applies.) If you're like me, once you've reached this threshold, the annoying/irrelevant ads go away, and you're only left with things that might potentially be interesting. Until that time, you might consider using a well-tweaked ad blocker.

It all comes down to personal preference, though. Smart advertisers pay by the *click*, rather than by the serve, so it really doesn't make any difference. And even if Stack Overflow is managing to get dumb advertisers that pay for a block of ads irrespective of clicks, the server tracking those ads for billing purposes doesn't know or care if you're using a client-side ad blocker.

Answer (score 2):

If your sole concern is to help publishers (i.e. StackExchange), then **don't block ads.**

I believe *most* people think they'll rarely, if ever, click on an ad. And this is more or less true; average [click-through rates (CTR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click-through_rate) are in the ballpark of 0.1%, and that's for well-targeted ads. But not all ads are done for clicks, some simply want to show you the ad so that the next time you're at the store, you'll subconsciously recall that brand. Even if the target is clicks, advertisers can use [ad tracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_tracking) to correlate clicks or [conversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_marketing) with previous [impressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impression_(online_media)), and price the impressions accordingly. For example, maybe you viewed an ad for widgets on Thursday (but didn't click), on Friday you went to widgets.com and bought a widget. The advertiser can, based on tracking cookies, measure how many people bought a widget against whether they've previously seen the ad, and value the ad accordingly. All this is to say, **even if you don't click an ad, it's still of value to the advertiser, and to the publisher.**

But as a user, you need to consider whether the personal cost to usability and bandwidth is worth the tiny financial benefit to publishers you care about. [Cost per impression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost_per_impression), measured in thousands (CPM), is about $1 average - the really premium publishers, like say NYT used to be, might be 10 times that. So every ad you see is worth about 0.1 cents.

If personally you don't mind the ads, sure go ahead and unblock them. But for StackExchange at least, there are much more effective ways to show your support, like participating in Q&A and curation.