# Will there be open source advertising in 2017?

Tags: support, open-source-advertising

There has not been [a call](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327559/open-source-advertising-2h-2016) for [open-source advertising](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/) this half-year.

Is this to be taken as Stack Overflow is no longer doing this?

Which is a fine and legitimate business decision, for example, if all remnant advertising slots have been sold to paying customers.

Comment: From hence forward, all ads shown will be for Documentation. They will be wrapped in `<blink>` tags for maximum visibility.

Comment: `<marquee><blink>we're begging you...</blink></marquee>`

Comment: @Qix with neon purple text on a florescent green background.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for introducing me to the `<blink>` tag. I was going to implement it in all of the pages on my site just now but unfortunately: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blink. What a pity. You've gotta love the example GIF on that page though.

Comment: @DavidB, you need to use the modern way, with CSS - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344354/how-to-make-blinking-flashing-text-with-css3

Comment: @DavidB [The origin story](http://www.montulli.org/theoriginofthe%3Cblink%3Etag) is pretty great too.

Comment: @DavidB [blink-polyfill's got your back](https://github.com/contra/blink-polyfill).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is, in simplest terms, a goof.

There are still plans and intents for advertising from open source initiatives. It was *supposed* to have gone up at the same time as the rest of the Community Promotion Ads went out to the network at large on February 2nd. That in itself was already delayed due to a combination of personal circumstances of my own and other start-of-year tasks (primarily election and community blog related) getting in the way.

So apparently when that was in fact done across the network, somehow... the post for Stack Overflow didn't happen. And I didn't realize it didn't happen. And we kinda moved on to work on other tasks until this was brought to my attention.

We'll go forward with setting up [a new Open Source Advertising](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349017/open-source-advertising-2017) - it's late enough into the year that we'll be setting up a single thread to run for the remaining 8 months, instead of forcing a reset after only 2 months.

Comment: How often does the set of ads change during a normal 5/6 month cycle? If it doesn't is it better to have two 4 month cycles so that more projects get a promotion opportunity?