# Open Source Advertising - 2017

Tags: discussion, community-ads, open-source-advertising

Due to [goofs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348845/will-there-be-open-source-advertising-in-2017/349016#349016), Open Source Advertising was never opened for 1H 2017. As we're already into May at this stage, we'll be opening a new set of Free Vote-Based Advertising for Open Source Projects for Stack Overflow that will run until the end of 2017.

Here is your chance to create a [Free Vote-Based Advertisement for an Open Source Project](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/). Create a graphical ad for an open source programming project and post it as an answer to this question (in the right format), and it will feed live remnant ads on Stack Overflow.

### Ad Requirements

It must be an advertisement **soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code**. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source. It's for finding programmers who will help contribute code or other programmery things (documentation, code review, bug fixes, etc.).

Your ad should be an original creation which has not previously appeared on Stack Overflow. Please do not resubmit entries that have appeared as ads on Stack Overflow in previous periods.

In order to work, the answers you post to this question **must** conform to the following rules.

### Answer Template

```
[![alternative text if image is not displayed][1]][2]
    
  [1]: http://image-url
  [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to add any commentary, keep it in the comments.

### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **300 pixels by 250 pixels**, or twice that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
- Must have a 1px border if (part of) the background is white, 2px if the image is high DPI.

The output, which ultimately will be served in an ad slot on Stack Overflow, can be previewed by clicking through to this URL:

http://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/300x250

### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be served up by that URL and shown on Stack Overflow. You can see all the ads that currently make the threshold and meet our criteria on this page:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/349017

**Note:** *As with previous [iterations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327559/open-source-advertising-2h-2016) of this program, if the exact ad image has already appeared in a previous cycle, it is not eligible to be run in this cycle. However, if you design a new ad, it will be able to appear if it gets enough votes*.

Comment: I was pointed to this _question_ because I want a icon for the _gitlab_ tag. But I don't see how I can use this here for that goal.

Comment: Is there going to be a 2018 question?

Comment: @JF [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362773/2422776) it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open Source Advertising - 1H 2018](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362773/open-source-advertising-1h-2018)

Answer (score 59):

[image: Help us develop bots to monitor and improve moderation efforts on Stack Overflow]

Answer (score 52):

[image: Julia: the high-level, high-performance dynamic programming language for numerical computing]

Comment: Awesomely, this advert was made using julia ([ad source code](https://gist.github.com/cormullion/8880c53bcb7766f50aca6c024ea845f8)) and cormullion's own [Luxor.jl](https://github.com/JuliaGraphics/Luxor.jl) package

Answer (score 50):

[image: Bring Java to Mobile Devices]

Comment: Can some of the people who downvote clarify why they are downvoting this so we can improve?

Comment: i like codenameone most

Comment: Java already *does* run on mobile devices. Maybe you could come up with a slightly better short explanation of what you do?

Comment: Not on iOS devices, not on Windows mobile/tablets and not WORA. Notice the picture is of an iPhone device. Notice that it's just impossible to convey a **REALLY** complex project like Codename One without making the ad look like a lecture. E.g. in this "short" video I just tried to answer "what is Codename One" and it took me 40 minutes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMRmo6ZRnGw

Comment: I upvoted this because it does not have that "Make Java WORA again" tagline (unlike last year)

Comment: If you don't want to have to learn 3 or more languages and programming conventions plus the nuances/lifecycles of all the different platforms, Codename One does that for you. Focus on functionality and design of your app instead of figuring out how to port it to all the platforms and use the different IDE's for each.

Comment: CN1 is the most versatile cross platform mobile development environment that I have run across. Add to that the fact that it is open source, extensible, and supports native code as well.

Comment: How about "Help us make Java more interoperable"? That seems like a pretty accurate description of what you're asking for help with.

Comment: I have developed a small app using codename one. It's truly a WORA technology and once I understood a little bit I was able to create really simple and slick app.  I was able to demo it on both iOS and Android at the same time.  Can't wait to learn more and build better apps.

Comment: @ArtOfCode that really flows off the tong ;-) 
It explains less of what we are doing... What we are doing is clearly WORA on mobile, but the younger generation of developers isn't as familiar with the WORA acronym as it isn't as common. I also used that over verbose description last year and people complained back then too with a similar number of downvotes.

Comment: Perhaps to some the add seems to imply a Java <-> Apple connection. Keep in mind you're targeting explicitly multiple brands of phone, perhaps reflecting that in your add next year would lead to less downvotes.

Comment: Sorry @Mast I don't think I follow, Java does run on an iOS device with Codename One and is 100% Apple "safe" as we translate the bytecode to C source code with our open source VM. We also work on Windows/UWP with a .net translation tool (fork of iKVM). Can you give me a concrete example?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog People seeing the advertisement for the first time don't know that. Your add only shows one device. Your goal is to target many devices. Therefore, it looks like you don't convey your goal with your ad.

Comment: I looked for a decent image of devices but couldn't find something representative that isn't too noisy. Since a form of Java is already on Android I didn't want to create confusion about that and Windows mobile isn't exactly the chief focus. iOS devices are the key "missing piece" when discussing mobile which is what I tried to convey in the image. I was conflicted about the wording as "Bring Java to ALL mobile Devices" but that would be "slightly" inaccurate because although we support tizen thru the JavaScript port, it's not exactly a first class citizen.

Comment: "Bring Java to *more* mobile devices?"

Comment: That might mislead people into thinking they can run their Android app on iOS which isn't the case here. We use the Android VM but our libraries abstract Android to provide WORA so it's really a different development experience entirely (GUI is written in Java not XML like in Android). I understand what you are saying but the problem with any complex product is no matter how I phrase it there is some aspect that "misleads". I used Java instead of using WORA to get familiarity, I also didn't want to use WORA since that might create a perception of a JavaScript/WEB framework

Comment: Why not just expand the acronym? "Write Once, Run Anywhere for Java"

Comment: That removes the mobile, I'd say "Mobile write Once Run Anywhere for Java" the problem is that I wrote something similar last year and got 21 downvotes: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332873/756809
Possibly because of Trump (who knew, back then I still thought it was funny) but I'm a bit hesitant about it. Problem is that people downvote and then some people guess why the downvote happened after the fact and I'm pretty much at a loss to explain this. E.g. in this ad we got 8 downvotes while the other guys got 2 at most. Is it because of what you think or just because people don't like Java?

Comment: the github logo is so much bigger than the project logo.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think our logo is really important here as this is about the open source project.

Comment: I like CN1, use it for 5 different projects at the moment.  Maybe the ad would be a bit more powerful if you took multiple devices and fanned them (like a deck of cards) or similar.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted that too but couldn't find the right image. It's a free stock photo. The images I found with multiple devices were either ugly, out of date or noisy.

Comment: Tagline sounds not very smart.

Comment: @AndrewSnejovski the goal is simplicity. Every extra word/character forces a reduction in font size and visibility. If you have a suggestion for a better tagline I'd love to hear it for the next update of this

Answer (score 41):

[image: Get involved in the LibreOffice Suite]

Answer (score 27):

[image: Traccar GPS Tracking System]

Answer (score 21):

[image: Help us bring the glorious VBE into this century!]

Comment: @Downvoter please let me know how to improve the ad. Thanks. "I hate VBA and creating tools for VBA coders should be criminal" is not a good reason.

Comment: You can downvote for any reason you like, to be fair.

Comment: @Mat'sMug bit slow on the uptake here but I hate (well that is a going a bit far) people who say "I hate vba" - they are usually code snobs - guy who has been mentoring me loves vba and he used to lecture C at one of Russia's best universities .... also one of the guys who made <<this....stack overflow>> possible wrote the spec for vba ...

Comment: @whytheq to be honest, contributing to Rubberduck / diving neck-deep into its quirks and weird inconsistencies puts that love to the test ;-)

Comment: oh crap, it's now written in C# 7...

Comment: you'd better amend that quick!

Answer (score 14):

[image: oVirt - Open your virtual datacenter]

Answer (score 13):

[image: a standard library for JavaScript and Node.js]

Comment: Numeric computing and statistics, as the two more precise categories stated, are hardly "standard", particularly for a language that was supposed to make HTML divs blink.

Comment: @K3---rnc JavaScript has evolved considerably since its initial creation. The project provides standard, i.e., robust, well-documented, and tested, implementations for a variety of use cases, with an emphasis on numeric computing. Regarding the more precise categories, one of the core aims is to bring robust and performant numeric computation capabilities to both the browser and Node.js.

Comment: Awesome job guys!

Comment: @kgryte Of course it has. How does it (the numeric computing part) compare to [mathjs](https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs)?

Comment: @K3---rnc In general, when compared to mathjs (or any math library that can be currently found in the ecosystem), the algorithms are more accurate, robust, and performant. Almost all of the numeric computing algorithms are tested and benchmarked against reference implementations, so you can confirm for yourself the prior statement. One of the next development phases will be multidimensional data structures and associated algorithms (linear algebra). When compared to other JS math libraries, the implementations will be more performant, especially given the use of native add-ons and WebAssembly.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Contribute to Orange Data Mining]

Comment: Link is down: https://orange.biolab.si/ FYI. EDIT: Nvm, now it's up? Seems to be intermittent.

Comment: @Carcigenicate we are having some maintenance done on our servers infrastructure. I hope it won't go down anymore. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 11):

[image: Contribute to the nicest CMS on the planet!]

Comment: Good job, although you're missing the tagline for this one

Comment: Spunky made this one

Comment: I mean the "Tagline to show on mouseover" bit in the submission

Comment: Feel free to edit it in. Or tell me what it should say :-)

Comment: It should say whatever you want people to know about your ad if they can't see the image. Right now your alt text is literally just, "Tagline to show on mouseover". (As an aside, people under 2K can't edit other user's posts on Meta.)

Comment: Ah, got it, edited the text description in

Comment: Maybe make it a bit shorter, how about "Contribute to the nicest CMS on the planet!"?

Comment: It is done @luketowers any other comments?

Comment: Nope, looks good! Thanks for doing that!

Answer (score 11):

[image: Say more, more clearly]

Comment: Looks quite interesting! How can I contribute to the Issues? Or new features?

Comment: @FilipeMiranda https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon

Answer (score 11):

[image: JanusGraph: distributed, open-source graph database]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Opsdroid - A Python Chatbot Framework]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Botonomous Framework]

Comment: Github: https://github.com/iranianpep/botonomous

Answer (score 5):

[image: Meshki: A Dark CSS Library]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Goxel Voxel Editor]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Devist - Release notes generator]

Answer (score 1):

[image: mini.css - minimal, responsive, style-agnostic CSS framework]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Contribute to Pyautoupdate on Github]

Comment: I think your project would massively benefit from a better README file; I've read it twice and I'm not even sure what this project *does* exactly; it's also missing links to something else which could clarify this (e.g. website or documentation) . I'm sure this information is available *somewhere*, but you should probably make it more obvious what your project does and what using it "feels" like in the README itself.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I added a link to documentation in the README. I am currently rewriting the README offline and will update it once it is ready. Please let me know if any other parts of the README and documentation are confusing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rekit: new way of React development]

Answer (score 0):

[image: IBM Data Merge Utility]

Comment: If you leave a down vote, please explain what I can do to improve the project or question.

Answer (score -5):

[image: SCFFLD: JSON based dependency injection - contribute on GitHub]

Comment: Before hovering over the image to see the link, I couldn't tell the name of your project.  Even now, I can't find the _C_ in that logo.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Thanks for your feedback. I know it will seem questionable to some, but leaving the name of the ad is a conscious decision (the name is obvious once the link is clicked). The logo is just a logo, a recognisable graphic. The important text is the text you can see (and read). Thanks again for the comment!

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom FWIW https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCt31.png