# Open Source Chat Android Application for Stack Overflow

Tags: support

A while back a fellow member of [Room 15 (Android)](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15/android) started creating an Android application for the Stack Overflow chat. I recently picked it up and revived it and it is open to community work.

https://github.com/room-15/ChatSE

(It's in Kotlin.)

Comment: Open Source Advertising: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349017/open-source-advertising-2017

Comment: I don't see any harm in more blatant plugs of community projects here, I mean after all it is meta (but also highly recommend the open source advertising too for more exposure).

Comment: I suggest putting it up in https://stackapps.com/

Comment: Can we get an APK

Comment: @UnknownDeveloper I'm currently out. I'll try to put an APK somewhere later. It's still in development, although the core functionality is there.

Comment: Also now on Stackapps. Thanks for the suggestion @suraj https://stackapps.com/questions/7495/open-source-chat-android-application-for-stack-overflow

Comment: The problem with stackapps is that nobody ever visits that site. I've seen feature requests with over hundred upvotes that are covered by stackapps userscripts, but nobody knows about that.

Comment: I wouldn't have seen this if it was somewhere else.