# Should Stack Overflow advertise the SaveCodeShare open letter initiative?

Tags: discussion, legal

A consortium of organisations and FSFE (free software foundation europe) have written an open letter and a [detailed white book](https://savecodeshare.eu/static/assets/WhitePaper-ImpactofArticel13onSoftwareEcosystem-SaveCodeShare.pdf) about the proposed EU directive on copyright, https://savecodeshare.eu/.

I believe SE websites, and SO to start with, have every reason to support this initiative. Should it be advertised on the website?

Comment: I'm not in favor of anyones agenda even if it relates to the topic at hand.  The minute we favor one thing over another this starts some sort of war.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open Source Advertising - 2017](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349017/open-source-advertising-2017)

Comment: @JonH I just retracted my vote for that. It has to be an actual programming project, but this isn't, so it's not eligible.

Comment: No, this is a Q&A site. Also from reading the whitepaper I disagree with it's conclusion that it somehow endangers open source. Based on what I understand from the article the idea is to make sites like github remove content that violates the license (similar to how google responds to DMCA notices) I don't see anything wrong with that.

Comment: I look forward to a future where every time an application runs a popup shows saying "This part of the application uses open source software. [I Accept] [I Refuse]".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The site has had a rocky time with issues which were polarising or widely controversial.  The opinion is for these to be confined to the blog.

If Stack Overflow wants to support this, expect a blog post about it. If they don't, don't be incredibly surprised or offended.

Comment: The argument in the white book is that under the new regulation sites like SE would have to impose on their user stringent automatic filtering of anyone's posts to detect possible copyright infringement. I should probably have been more explanatory in my original post.

Comment: @Joce:  That's irrelevant in the face of whether or not Stack Overflow will promote it.  If they do decide to take it up, then they'll likely do so through their blog.