# Are we going to have Open Source Advertising in 2018?

Tags: discussion, open-source-advertising

I just realized that the [last open source advertising campaign](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349017/2422776) ran through the end of 2017. We're already almost a month into 2018, and I don't recall seeing a new campaign for 2018. Searching for one didn't reveal anything either.

Is this intentional, or did launching a new campaign just fall through the cracks? (or is my search-fu just that bad?)

Comment: Great timing - was just hunting for the 2018 thread.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It'll be going up this week. Most of January got eaten by a variety of new-year tasks (mostly election organization related, as well as moderator appointments that are still in progress). Community Promotion Ads were just setup across last week culminating over the weekend for 66 sites, missing the 4 newest graduated sites. They, as well as Stack Overflow's Open Source Advertising, will be going up later this week as a result. Ideally while it's still January.

---

#### Update

It is now up. While it was still January ♪

[Open Source Advertising - 1H 2018](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362773/open-source-advertising-1h-2018)