# Open Source Advertising - 1H 2018

Tags: discussion, community-ads, open-source-advertising

It is 2018, and it is still January. We will commence with resetting the Free Vote-Based Advertising for Open Source Advertising for Stack Overflow for the new year. This time, returning back to our twice-a-year convention for the system.

Here is your chance to create a [Free Vote-Based Advertisement for an Open Source Project](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/). Create a graphical ad for an open source programming project and post it as an answer to this question (in the right format), and it will feed live remnant ads on Stack Overflow.

### Ad Requirements

It must be an advertisement **soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code**. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source. It's for finding programmers who will help contribute code or other programmery things (documentation, code review, bug fixes, etc.).

Your ad should be an original creation which has not previously appeared on Stack Overflow. Please do not resubmit entries that have appeared as ads on Stack Overflow in previous periods.

In order to work, the answers you post to this question **must** conform to the following rules.

### Answer Template

```
[![alternative text if image is not displayed][1]][2]
    
  [1]: http://image-url
  [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to add any commentary, keep it in the comments.

### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **300 pixels by 250 pixels**, or twice that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
- Must have a 1px border if (part of) the background is white, 2px if the image is high DPI.

The output, which ultimately will be served in an ad slot on Stack Overflow, can be previewed by clicking through to this URL:

http://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/300x250

### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be served up by that URL and shown on Stack Overflow. You can see all the ads that currently make the threshold and meet our criteria on this page:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/362773

**Note:** *As with previous [iterations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349017/open-source-advertising-2017) of this program, if the exact ad image has already appeared in a previous cycle, it is not eligible to be run in this cycle. However, if you design a new ad, it will be able to appear if it gets enough votes*.

Comment: May take a day or two for the hookup to actually begin and ads to start displaying, as a forenote. But let's not let that get in the way of folks to begin their submissions and voting.

Comment: It seems some people are downvoting without any comment. Please provide meaningful comments so people can improve

Comment: It seems ***a lot*** of people are down voting without comment...

Comment: Yes, I have +6/-6 right now and not a single comment on what's the problem...

Comment: Maybe people just don't _like_ the ad? Nobody is _required_ to explain their downvote.

Comment: Not required but it would be nice. After all it's open source projects and we drive the projects based on feedback/community. If you just don't like the ad you usually just ignore it (don't upvote) downvoting generally implies that something is wrong or really bad...

Comment: It's actually quite "usual" to downvote options one doesn't like in competitions like these. To be blunt, this _is_ a popularity contest.

Comment: I don't mind bluntness. I didn't downvote anyone here and since there are just 3 of us right now I doubt this adds up to the 10 downvotes I got... It's not a zero sum game with one "winner" so I'd be happy if my peers in the OSS community pass the threshold too.

Comment: @GraceNote: I noticed there's a nice template pre-filled in the answer box (After trying to discard it with no result :P). Just curious: is that tied into the `[community-ads]` tag? Or is that something you manually enter somewhere?

Comment: @Cerbrus It's due to the tag, yeh.

Comment: A popularity contest??? I thought SO is about finding and providing help, not about being popular. Besides, I don't think it is a contest at all. I personally would be glad if the other projects get promoted.

Comment: @scopchanov: Yes, SO _is_ about quality Q/A, but in this question, users get to _choose_ which ads they will see, by voting on ads they like / dislike. That's basically a popularity contest. Which isn't exactly _bad_, in this case.

Comment: @Cebrus, if they all are eventually shown who is the winner?

Comment: @scopchanov: let's not go into hypothetical scenarios.

Comment: Think of it not as a popularity contest, but a popularity check. The whole idea is for the community to vet the content before it gets shown to the site at large. If you think all the projects that people put up are stuff that the public should be seeing, it's perfectly fine to vote them all up. Others might have their own reasons to vote as they do. There might not be a "contest" aspect so to speak but in the same way that votes are used to help filter the general Q&A content on the main site, it works on the same principles here.

Comment: Just a thought - shouldn't this be [meta-tag:featured]?

Comment: Good afternoon,    
it is a brilliant opportunity for open source software! I'd have a question: is my open source product eligible for participating in this campaign? https://reaction-engine.bitbucket.io   
Thanks,    
V.

Comment: @GraceNote I was wondering if, and when, the OSS advertisements will be displayed in Stack Overflow ads. Based on the click counts for all the ads listed here (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/362773), it seems these ads have not been running. I am basing my comparison off of last year, where click counts steadily increased over time. I am seeing no such behavior this time around for all eligible OSS ads. Are the ads actually being run on SO?

Comment: What is a "remnant ad"?

Comment: Going to echo @kgryte's question about if these actually ran or not (?)  For purposes of transparency, it should show how many impressions were given. 
 I'd like to put in an ad for the next cycle, but 6 clicks for 6 months doesn't seem like it would be worth it...

Comment: Would there be a 2H anytime soon?

Comment: Hi! I'm wanting to organize putting together a team to port dnSpy to OSX. Someone told me to come here, but the rules here make it sound like I need to already have a community for the ad. What should I do?

Answer (score 31):

[image: Julia: the high-level, high-performance dynamic programming language for numerical computing]

Comment: Code to draw this ad is [here](https://gist.github.com/cormullion/fa92a6d4678942db543ada10a6cef5f2).

Comment: Julia is great, and getting better, but it's definitely not just for data science and technical computing!  It's also has a lot of advantages for general programming compared to C, C++, C#, Java, Go, Python.   The ad itself is great, as usually, Cormullion comes up with beautiful designs.

Answer (score 24):

[image: Contribute to Traccar project]

Answer (score 20):

[image: Contribute on GitHub!]

Comment: Good luck on the voting!

Answer (score 16):

[image: Written in C#7.2 - no VBA knowledge is needed]

Comment: This project is written in C# 7.2 and the team is happy to hand-hold contributors of all levels - knowledge areas include working with Antlr4 parse trees, WPF/XAML UI work (MVVM), deep COM interactions with the .net CLR & GC, code inspections & quickfixes, refactorings (no VBA knowledge required), and more. Roadmap includes hijacking code panes (planning to use AvalonEdit and Dragablz) and implementing custom IntelliSense & autocompletion. Lots of work, yes - that's why we need your help!

Comment: Other contribution areas include translations (currently English, French and German), updating the repository's wiki, and then the website (also open-source, ASP.NET MVC) could use a refresher too. Long-standing "most wanted" features under development and in need of help include a source control panel (kind of like Visual Studio's *Team Explorer*) and the wicked-complex *Extract Method* refactoring.

Answer (score 14):

[image: Bring Kotlin (and Java) to All Mobile Devices]

Comment: *It must be an advertisement soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source*. This ad is not soliciting anything, it is just a link to the project. It doesn't meet the requirements.

Comment: Why? That literally links to a github project which includes contributions, pull requests and a contribution guide. This is no different than any other ad here

Comment: Your ad needs to be explicit about what you need. The other ads all, in one way or another, ask for *people to contribute to the project*. Your ad could just as easy be construed to mean 'come *use* this project'.

Comment: I don't see that. First ad just says "Contribute on github", second says "pay 20 years of technical debt" that's not a specific contribution. 4th says contribute on github etc. We say "Bring Kotlin and Java to mobile devices". We want people to help us bring these languages to all mobile devices. I don't see how our ad is any different from the other ads? It's only missing the "Contribute on github" statement but it's pretty obvious when the github link is the only link there...

Comment: Then your ad is ambiguous. I interpreted the line to mean “this project will let you write mobile apps targeting multiple platforms using Kotlin and Java. If you are asking for help porting then you may want to make that clearer.

Comment: Everything in ads is ambiguous because it doesn't display in that size. It displays in the corner at half the size and if we write more we distract from the message. I think it's pretty clear, it's bringing kotlin and java to mobile. Not bringing your apps written in kotlin/java which is the messaging we use for end users (who are also developers in this case). Again how is this different from any other ad here? Looking at them I understand what they do not what they want because the latter is MUCH harder to explain.

Answer (score 14):

[image: 30 seconds of code]

Comment: My previous submission was criticized for not including enough details about the nature of the project, so I decided to submit a new ad with a short description. Hope this isn't against any rules.

Comment: This feels like what SO was actually thinking Documentation would become.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom  Yep :) Before the community killed it :)

Answer (score 12):

[image: ConTabs - Simple yet flexible tables for console apps]

Comment: The antialiasing around the logo does not work well.

Comment: @usr2564301 That's not anti-aliasing, it's an outline with a transparency gradient. But I agree.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Visit FlatGUI on Github]

Comment: @usr2564301, Thanks for the feedback! The image is so simple not because I was too lazy to create a comprehensive one. It is actually made _on puprpose_ to be like that in order to represent the very idea behind the project - simple and right to the point, yet beautiful and easy to use. Nothing clutters the interface nor obstructs the user interaction with the software. As for the emphasizing of the flatness, to be honest I can't imagine what could be flatter than a one-color background. Also, Traccar and FlatGUI are quite different projects and different things work best for each one of them.

Comment: @usr2564301, I mean, I understand your idea - they are both flat, but still in my case this image is exactly what I had in mind when I was developing the widgets.

Comment: @usr2564301, How about now?

Comment: Oh much better! It looks as a representation of itself :)

Comment: @usr2564301, I like this description very much: "a representation of itself". As a matter of fact both images have a message of their own, kinda like a Q&A. The first one is asking - "How does a simplicity look like?" The second one answers - "That is how". :)

Comment: @scopchanov: thanks for making it explicit what you are advertising for. Note that software developers are consumers too, using libraries. But now your ad is clear: you want contributions, not asking for developers to use the library.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thanks for the input!

Answer (score 8):

[image: Nimn (निम्न)]

Answer (score 7):

[image: oVirt - The Open Source Virtual Data Center]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Swiss army knife for AWS CloudFormation templates - validation, conversion, generators and other various stuff]

Answer (score 1):

[image: CodexMicroORM on GitHub]

Answer (score -1):

[image: Rubberduck is an OSS VBIDE add-in project aiming to modernize the VBE]

Comment: Isn't this the same as https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362883/3033053 ?

Comment: @silencedmessage it's the same project, indeed. I put up an ad, and ThunderFrame came up with this one - I manage an OSS project, I don't police core contributors and go "no you can't do that" when they do nice things.. I'd have made the click-url point to the GitHub repository though... IMO if it wasn't for the C#/WPF/COM lettering this submission would look/feel more like it's aimed at our users (VBA devs) than for recruiting contributors, but that's up to this community to decide, through votes.

Comment: Would this not look better with the ducky upright? It is not as if you should be aiming for a scientifically accurate perspective projection.

Comment: *It must be an advertisement soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source*. This ad is not soliciting anything, it is just a link to the project. It doesn't meet the requirements.

Answer (score -4):

[image: ROS Code: Fast and easy to use programming language for enthusiasts. Contribute on GitHub.]

Answer (score -5):

[image: PowerPreference]

Comment: Please review the image requirements in the question: *"The image that you create must be 300 pixels by 250 pixels, or twice that if high DPI."*

Comment: That's a good size, but unfortunately there's a typo in your ad now :P

Answer (score -8):

[image: PMD - an extensible cross-language static code analyzer]

Comment: PMD might be a useful tool, but -1 because I really, really don't want to see guns in Stack Overflow, ever, and especially this week.

Comment: Apart from that: graphically, the Tahoma text on the bottom seems forcibly inserted in to an existing design. It's stylistically a different font style than the 'main' message, far too much to the left, with bad vertical spacing. There is no reason to repeat "PMD" (in bold or otherwise). The GitHub line is uncomfortably close to the bottom and right.

Answer (score -8):

[image: Rockburg open source music industry simulation game!]

Comment: *It must be an advertisement soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source.* This ad is not soliciting anything, it is just a link to the project. It doesn't meet the requirements.

Answer (score -10):

[image: Coco, the fastest crypto online]

Answer (score -19):

[image: Shortcode Cleaner - Clean your WordPress content from unused broken shortcodes]

Comment: Shortcode cleaner Lite Features:

- Clean up the frontend site content.
- Clean up posts, pages, custom post types [content, excerpt, title, metaboxs].
- Clean up sidebars widgets [title, content], menu links, settings options.
- Clean up any content within broken shortcodes.
- Clean up normal and nested broken shortcodes.
- Cleaner Dashboard Reports.
- Check where broken Shortcodes found in.
- Control of the cleaner settings.

Comment: *It must be an advertisement soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source*. This ad doesn't meet the requirements.

Answer (score -26):

[image: Laravel]

Comment: Can you please anyone explain why this has so many downvotes so I can prevent posting these types of things in future

Comment: I expect it's the lack of any kind of strap line or tag line or slogan or even a hint as to what it is. I quite like the design, but it's not enticing me to click...

Comment: ___"This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source."___

Comment: *It must be an advertisement soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source*. This ad is not soliciting anything, it is just a link to the project. It doesn't meet the requirements.

Comment: Also, it's Laravel.