# Open Source Advertising — 1H 2019

Tags: discussion, community-ads, open-source-advertising

2019 is here! Which means it’s time to refresh the Free Vote-Based Advertising for Open Source Advertising for Stack Overflow for the first half of the year!

Here is your chance to create a [Free Vote-Based Advertisement for an Open Source Project](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/). Create a graphical ad for an open source programming project and post it as an answer to this question (in the right format), and it will feed live remnant ads on Stack Overflow.

### Ad Requirements

It must be an advertisement **soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code**. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source. It's for finding programmers who will help contribute code or other programmery things (documentation, code review, bug fixes, etc.).

Your ad should be an original creation which has not previously appeared on Stack Overflow. Please do not resubmit entries that have appeared as ads on Stack Overflow in previous periods.

In order to work, the answers you post to this question **must** conform to the following rules.

### Answer Template

```
[![alternative text if image is not displayed][1]][2]
    
  [1]: http://image-url
  [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to add any commentary, keep it in the comments.

### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **300 pixels by 250 pixels**, or twice that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
- Must have a 1px border if (part of) the background is white, 2px if the image is high DPI.

The output, which ultimately will be served in an ad slot on Stack Overflow, can be previewed by clicking through to this URL:

http://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/300x250

### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be served up by that URL and shown on Stack Overflow. You can see all the ads that currently make the threshold and meet our criteria on this page:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/379273

**Note:** *As with previous [iterations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362773/1328704) of this program, if the exact ad image has already appeared in a previous cycle, it is not eligible to be run in this cycle. However, if you design a new ad, it will be able to appear if it gets enough votes*.

Comment: May take a day or two for the hookup to actually begin and ads to start displaying, as a forenote. But let's not let that get in the way of folks to begin their submissions and voting.

Answer (score 75):

[image: Help us develop bots to monitor and improve moderation efforts on Stack Overflow]

Comment: I already knew that your work is awesome (I "use" it sometimes in the relevant chat room). But now I discover how beautiful and well designed your web site is. Congrats!

Comment: Thanks @Denys. We are looking for ways to continuously improve our work. Do let us know if you have any feedback for us. :)

Comment: Nice hippo. I really like that one.

Answer (score 29):

[image: the Julia language on github.com]

Comment: Code to draw this ad is [here](https://gist.github.com/cormullion/d5d87f54c2823df0be371f5198b56546)

Comment: this add is pretty cool :)

Answer (score 25):

[image: Flame]

Answer (score 22):

[image: LibreOffice]

Answer (score 15):

[image: Traccar]

Answer (score 11):

[image: help us create the next generation of backend development]

Comment: Is that logo _supposed_ to remind me of a fidget spinner?

Comment: @xjcl nah thats just a happy accident.

Answer (score 10):

[image: ROS AV - An open source CLI to combat malware and viruses]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score 4):

[image: GAAS]

Comment: you might need to add a border around the bottom edges.

Answer (score -7):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: One thing that would help if you edited the template enough to replace "Tagline to show on mouseover" with something related to your project. Not changing that simple part of the post doesn't say much for the project.

Comment: That is an image so adding hover to them isn't that easy enough. Non of the ads have similar effect.

Comment: @null. Try [edit]ing this post, and replace the text *Tagline to show on mouseover* with a tagline you want to show on mouseover.

Answer (score -8):

[image: 7cart is a base project for building things like online stores, catalogs or service platforms.]

Answer (score -13):

[image: PHP Config Writer]

Comment: Can you share why you downvoted this? This is my first ad so I don't have experience with that.

Comment: Well, I quite like the idea of an advert _in_ code so I gave you an upvote, but - to try and understand the downvotes - some thoughts ... I think overall the graphic lacks visual impact. There's no  visual hierarchy, not much to grab the eye's attention and then keep it. It's quite dark (and there's a lot of "black space") and low-ish contrast, and the colors and fonts, while they might be good for practical coding, don't have much visual appeal. ...

Comment: ... perhaps successful ads try to be engaging and entertaining, and/or provide some wit, humor, visual delight, or human interest, but if you don't speak PHP there's not much of that going on here?

Also, people may have strong existing opinions about the PHP language and take the opportunity you've provided to state it; the internet is like that - everyone has an opinion. :)

Comment: @cormullion Thank you for your explanation :) I will maybe change this ad to brighter. If this won't be enough, I will maybe later create another ad and maybe for another product.

Comment: At first glance it looks as though there was an error loading some module into the page. It takes too much effort to parse it as an advertisement. I don't think it will be very effective.

Comment: I created more bright ad. If it won't be OK, I will try to create another different ad.

Comment: IMO the syntax highlighting isn't helping, particularly the bolded keywords - eyes see "use, require, new", and then the name of the project is buried in code, literally; consider giving the project name and message a stronger emphasis, so that the boilerplate background code *feels* like background, and the actual message can be caught at a glance.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I unbolded use and other keywords and bolded project details.