# Open Source Advertising — 2H 2019

Tags: discussion, community-ads, open-source-advertising

Yes, it's already July — which means the time to refresh the Free Vote-Based Advertising for Open Source Projects for Stack Overflow has come!

Here is your chance to create a [Free Vote-Based Advertisement for an Open Source Project](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/). Create a graphical ad for an open source programming project and post it as an answer to this question (in the right format), and it will feed live remnant ads on Stack Overflow.

### Ad Requirements

It must be an advertisement **soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code**. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source. It's for finding programmers who will help contribute code or other programmery things (documentation, code review, bug fixes, etc.).

Your ad should be an original creation which has not previously appeared on Stack Overflow. Please do not resubmit entries that have appeared as ads on Stack Overflow in previous periods.

In order to work, the answers you post to this question **must** conform to the following rules.

### Answer Template

```
[![Alternative text if image is not displayed.][1]][2]
    
  [1]: http://image-url
  [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to add any commentary, keep it in the comments.

### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **300 pixels by 250 pixels**, or twice that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
- Must have a 1px border if (part of) the background is white, 2px if the image is high DPI.

The output, which ultimately will be served in an ad slot on Stack Overflow, can be previewed by clicking through to this URL:

https://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/300x250

### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be served up by that URL and shown on Stack Overflow. You can see all the ads that currently make the threshold and meet our criteria on this page:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/386746

**Note:** *As with previous [iterations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379273/1328704) of this program, if the exact ad image has already appeared in a previous cycle, it is not eligible to be run in this cycle. However, if you design a new ad, it will be able to appear if it gets enough votes*.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is this also a part of the "We're testing ads across the network"  campaign?

Comment: No, this is an ongoing thing, that's been happening for years :) See all the previous iterations [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-source-advertising). The first link in the post also provides some more background context ;)

Comment: Finally, some good news ;D

Comment: What does "if high DPI" mean? Should the png uploaded have 300 x 250 pixels or 600 x 500?

Comment: This is so cool. How have I never seen this before?

Comment: It is possible to define tags which are related? I have something in mind which is only relevant for a minority of users.

Comment: First point in the image requirements says "The image that you create must be 300 pixels by 250 pixels, or twice that if high DPI," @ImportanceOfBeingErnest ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, @rekire,that's not possible.

Comment: Sorry, if my question wasn't clear. DPI is a device property, not an image property. So I find "if hight DPI" highly confusing, because it's not clear what exactly "high DPI" relates to. Maybe asked differently: In which case should one upload a 300 x 200 pixel image and in which case a 600 x 500 pixel image?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I believe that's more of a relic from the days when High DPI screens weren't the norm, and when creating an image to suit high DPI screens was (presumably) a harder task than a normal-sized image (don't quote me on this). These days, nearly every advertisement is 'High DPI' (i.e. created at twice the specified size), as there is almost no reason why it would be harder to do so, and more people are likely to benefit from the higher resolution image.

Comment: What's the deadline and does the ad  run until the end of 2019?

Comment: There's no deadline, @PauloMatos, and the ads will run until the next cycle (Jan. '20).

Comment: From what I can tell, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, it's just a matter of preference. I'm told most of our advertisers, for example, just send us 300x250. Might be that there's something to angussidney's comment.

Comment: @JNat image alt text does not "show upon mouseover" as you anticipate. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271135/reuse-image-description-alt-text-as-hover-tooltip-title-by-default

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Nothing in the post talks about a mouseover. Deleted comment?

Comment: Can the placeholder text prepopulating the answer field be updated so that the alt text ends with a period? Most folks are leaving out terminating punctuation.

Answer (score 111):

[image: Help keep Stack Exchange free of spam - Charcoal-SE on GitHub.]

Comment: I'll post this on Travel Meta too.

Answer (score 80):

[image: Help us develop bots to monitor and improve moderation efforts on Stack Overflow.]

Comment: Why the cat? Does it have some special meaning? Are cats known anti-plagiarists?

Comment: @CodyGray, we catch copy cats ... The real reason is that [Guttenberg](https://stackapps.com/q/7197/42239), our plagiarism detector's logo is the cat. Most of our bots/dashes have an associated logo. Like a dog for the NAA detection bot, A hippo for the [vandalism detection dash](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379306/4099593) and so on. The dashboard for [plagiarism detection posts](https://copypastor.sobotics.org/), also has a slogan of _"Whatever you do, our cat will always be watching you."_

Comment: @CodyGray yes they are, you should see my cat's reaction when I quote him openly..

Answer (score 18):

[image: Mathematica++ A C++ library that speaks Mathematica.]

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it might be because of the border, uneven and oddly colored as it is.

Comment: Hm I see. I overlooked the border size. Updated.

Comment: To be fair, you don't even need the border, if you don't want one -- it's only required for ads which have a white background.

Comment: Downvotes might happen because your add doesn't seem to invite programmers to write code but is just an add for the project. Also the site you link to doesn't give any hint how to participate.

Comment: @BDL Thanks. Corrected that. Inviting contributors is the primary objective.

Comment: Is the GitLab icon allowed to be transparent? Companies dont usually like their logo modified... Also, the central shape might be better as a circle.

Comment: Yes they do allow "PNG downloads have a transparent background, JPGs will have a white background." They even let you download SVG image of their logo. https://about.gitlab.com/press/press-kit/

Comment: Well, it’s not the surrounding white background I was worried about (which they’re referring to), but the actual icon itself. But no worries. :)

Comment: With the edits, this turned into a very nice-looking and perfectly suitable ad. If I were to make a suggestion, it would be to try moving the lower red bar upwards, equalizing the spacing between the logo on the top and bottom. Not only would that bring a balance to the design, but it would also give the “contribute” part a bit more room to “breathe”. Not sure how it will look, but I’d say worth a try.

Comment: https://imgur.com/8aIcgt2 Looking better ?

Answer (score 17):

[image: October is a Content Management System (CMS) and web platform whose sole purpose is to make your development workflow simple again. Help us make October better than it already is!]

Comment: How do you pronounce this name, is the leaf involved and that and I or a t

Comment: @TheGeneral October, like the month. The full name is OctoberCMS. It's a very flexible framework based on laravel, which imho adds a lot more punch to laravel.

Comment: Oh I see :) it was kind of obvious now. I was thinking ociobert. Or another incarnation

Comment: Ociober? Ochober? Rebo [`\vdash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile_(symbol)) Co written in reverse for some reason?

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta You should ask the designer of the logo for that reason. I'm only a github contributor and loosely affiliated with the project, but they've had this logo for a long time. What I do know is that internally in the code a lot of october references in javascript or translations start with `oc.specific.specific`

Comment: The Contribute on GitHub at the bottom there looks okay at its current 2x size, but when it's downsized to 50% for display, it'll be pretty small - you might want to consider making it a bit larger.

Comment: @ArtOfCode good point, will do that tomorrow morning.

Comment: @Tschallacka Please file an issue pointing them to our feedback here. That logo is illegible. =/ "October" is certainly not what I would think without any accompanying text.

Comment: @jpmc26 that has been their logo for years. I doubt they'll change their opinion. And after all, it's a logo. I've seen worse, more incompatible logos.

Answer (score 17):

[image: Painterro - JavaScript painting plugin]

Comment: That logo argh, it is not the best. I know they aren't going to change it for us, and no, I am not part of the political correctness brigade that is ruining Stack Exchange and SO, but I hate seeing that stupid moustache thing. Yes, I am female, and no, I am not oppressed by men!

Comment: Upon further consideration, I have removed my downvote. It is useful to have paint plugins for web browsers, not to need to go to MS Paint  on PC locally everytime. Also, there aren't tons of web apps out there that provide that. Just because I hate the logo doesn't mean this service/web app isn't worthy. I'm sorry for my prior comment.

Comment: Hi @EllieKesselman whoops, I am sorry to hear you did not like a logo, I really did not think moustache might be so annoying:) I was just a developer and I was looking for a logo, sometimes it is not easy to get a nice idea;) And what came to my mind, if you push brush to the table it might become like a moustache, and it might be associated with a good Mexican boy, which might be good association with Mexican "painterro" name. I am from Eastern Europe so do not know a lot about Mexic a lot but from here is like something atmospheric and unusual. Let me know if you have another logo ideas =)

Answer (score 16):

[image: ppcg-leaderboard: A versatile leaderboard script for Code Golf Stack Exchange.]

Comment: Does this still require a border? I technically used gray for the banner but I'm not sure. I think it would look fine without a border.

Answer (score 14):

[image: CONNECTIVE: large-scale reactive programming]

Answer (score 13):

[image: Help us accelerate genome research! Contribute to MMseqs2 on GitHub.]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Make offline backups of your cloud hosted source code repositories - Contribute to SCM Backup on GitHub.]

Answer (score 2):

[image: With DocPHT you can take notes and quickly document anything and without the use of any database.]

Answer (score -1):

[image: Shuttle]

Answer (score -3):

[image: gantt-schedule-timeline-calendar]

javascript / typescript gantt-schedule-timeline-calendar component

Answer (score -4):

[image: We've been at it since 1990 and we're still nowhere! Desperately seeking help! -RMS-]

Comment: *We've been at it since 1990 and we're still nowhere!* **Desperately seeking help!** [-RMS-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Stallman)

Comment: You might want to add a border, since your post is not in compliance with the contest rules.

Comment: @B.Letz Just did that.  You're [the second one](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50976187#50976187) telling me...  **;-)**

Comment: It'd be better if at least one path through the arrows led to the order in which you want the text read. As it is, the eye wants to follow both the arrows and the top-down, left-right reading order, which are in conflict. That adds cognitive dissonance. In addition, when displayed at the 300x250 resolution, which is the default at which this will be served on non-high-DPI displays, the text used in the boxes is a bit small. It's still readable, but its height is a pixel or two shorter than most of the text on the page.

Comment: @Makyen Thank you for the kind words.  This was posted as a joke and GNU Hurd will probably never see the light of day so the cognitive dissonance was a feature, not a flaw.  Too bad there are more people that do not have a sense or humour compared to people that do...  **;-)**  _(Or maybe they have a sense of humour, but not a sense for the absurd)_  **>:-)**

Comment: @Fabby That's impressive! Still being nowhere after three decades of trying, I'm in awe ;)

Answer (score -5):

[image: Fornux ZetaNet - Portable Social Media Platform]

Answer (score -6):

[image: Pychat - Self-hosted video chat like slack]

Answer (score -14):

[image: RaptorJIT. Fast, powerful, simple: choose all three.]

Comment: This is a nice-looking ad; very clean and elegant. It is perhaps *too* clean. Consider adding a bit more description about what the project is and/or what it’s goals are (I can’t tell anything meaningful without clicking through), and an explicit call for contributions (which is the point of these ads).

Answer (score -22):

[image: sled is the champagne of alpha embedded databases]

Comment: This would probably be better if it didn't have text overlapping the images or other text.

Comment: @TylerNeely I'm no designer, but I kinda fiddled around with your concept. Maybe something more like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfj4s.png

Comment: @Tschallacka I love it, nice work :D

Comment: @TylerNeely Feel free to use it as the advertisement concept. Just switch out the urls, it's already on the i.stack.imgur uploaded

Comment: @Tschallacka I think if we add our points together we will win. Maybe we should combine the sled and october ads to improve our chances?

Comment: the october mountain is really good - especially for sledding

Comment: @TylerNeely Combining won't work. The ads that are circulated are directly pulled from these individual posts, if they reach more than 6 points. At the moment you have an ad that's in wrong dimensions and uses the faux pas comic sans ms. The image I made resembles the "sledding down the mountain" and is a bit cleaner without trying to lose the whimsical nature, which might inspire people to click and look, and might help you reach the treshold of 6 votes.

Comment: @Tschallacka We can win this thing!

Comment: @TylerNeely If you really want to win you might want to edit in that image I made, or make a better one yourself, in either 300 x 250 or 600 x 500

Comment: I'm not even mad that tree on a sled is legitimately cute.

Comment: This ad is terrible and I hate it. +1, please go into marketing and revolutionize the ad industry with this trash. I'd probably turn off my adblocker, fingerprinting be damned.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words, @NicHartley :D I'm confident that the sled advertisement is the only one submitted so far that would actually appeal to the demographic with enough time to collaborate on an open source project in the first place: students! (they love fun, and being cool, which is why I was sure to mention those important project qualities on my ad)

Comment: @tyler I think you’re both overestimating the amount of spare time students have, and their love towards Comic Sans. Unless by students you mean middle schoolers, in a we, good job?

Comment: @Tim thank you for your kind words <3