# Open Source Advertising — 1H 2020

Tags: discussion, community-ads, open-source-advertising

It's 2020! And... March, yes... Late as it is, it's time to refresh the Free Vote-Based Advertising for Open Source Projects for Stack Overflow!

Here is your chance to create a [Free Vote-Based Advertisement for an Open Source Project](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/). Create a graphical ad for an open source programming project and post it as an answer to this question (in the right format), and it will feed live remnant ads on Stack Overflow.

### Ad Requirements

It must be an advertisement **soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code**. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source. It's for finding programmers who will help contribute code or other programmery things (documentation, code review, bug fixes, etc.).

Your ad should be an original creation which has not previously appeared on Stack Overflow. Please do not resubmit entries that have appeared as ads on Stack Overflow in previous periods.

In order to work, the answers you post to this question **must** conform to the following rules.

### Answer Template

```
[![Alternative text if image is not displayed.][1]][2]
    
  [1]: http://image-url
  [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to add any commentary, keep it in the comments.

### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **300 pixels by 250 pixels**, or twice that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
- Must have a 1px border if (part of) the background is white, 2px if the image is high DPI.

The output, which ultimately will be served in an ad slot on Stack Overflow, can be previewed by clicking through to this URL:

https://stackoverflow.com/ossads/300x250

### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be served up by that URL and shown on Stack Overflow. You can see all the ads that currently make the threshold and meet our criteria on this page:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/394409

**Note:** *As with previous [iterations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386746/1328704) of this program, if the exact ad image has already appeared in a previous cycle, it is not eligible to be run in this cycle. However, if you design a new ad, it will be able to appear if it gets enough votes*.

Comment: Suggestion for improvement of question : clarify if being a non-competing site is a requirement.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward "You can see all the ads that currently make the threshold *and meet our criteria* on this page:"  [Click and have a look](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/394409)

Comment: This link doesn't work anymore: https://rads.stackoverflow.com/ossads/300x250

Comment: Mm, not sure what broke, @MEE-ReinstateMonica, but fixed it in the post so that it works. Thanks for the heads-up :)

Comment: FYI it seems the click count hasn't updated in a long, long time. Are these ads still being served? Guts say something's broken... We're still a few months ahead of what would be 1H 2021 (assuming a January launch this time), so there's still time to fix things =)

Comment: You mean the click counts [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/394409), @MathieuGuindon? If so, I just tried clicking on one of the ads, and after refreshing that page the click gone had gone up by 1 — so it looks all is well there?

Comment: Yeah no not disputing that the mechanism works, just saying that the click counts appear to have been essentially stagnant for several months now, as if none of them had been served since. IDK how the tag mechanics are implemented, but could be some hard-coded 6-months aging mechanism that makes 1H stop working even if 2H isn't put up. IDK, I've monitored this batch of ads pretty closely (had the browser tab open on my mobile all along!), and it was buzzing with activity until it suddenly stopped. The click counts stagnating would be a *symptom*, not the problem.

Comment: I tweeted something about "wow look at that we win SE ads this year" on 08/31 and none of the figures budged much since, so it's been stagnant for at least 2 months now.

Comment: I checked with our ads team, @MathieuGuindon, and it looks like something broke on our end around 2 months ago, indeed, and it went unnoticed. Thanks for pointing it out; it should now be fixed :)

Comment: @JNat is there a different thread of 2021 or should we post proposal for our open source project in this thread only?

Comment: I haven't refreshed the ads yet for 2021, @invider — keep an eye on [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405031/will-there-be-open-source-advertising-in-2021) for updates shortly.

Answer (score 292):

[image: Codidact: Help us build an open-source, truly community-run Q&A engine. Visit codidact.org, join us on Discord, or contribute on GitHub.]

Comment: Codidact will be a new kind of Quora focused on Coding?

Comment: @TemaniAfif No. Codidact isn't thematically focused on anything for now. We want to provide a framework for communities, which will allow them to do Q&A, canonical knowledge (=Wiki), Meta discussions to some extent blogging, and other things we can't imagine right now in the way they need it. There will only be few rules from us (mostly a basic-decency CoC), whereas the communities are free to decide on most of their rules. We'll try to find a balance between content curation and individual help, for which these different categories (Q&A, Wiki, ...) might be a good start.

Comment: Ha Ha! Brilliant! When I first started to scroll down from the question and saw the top of this image, I literally (nearly) fell off my chair laughing! (Laughing *with* you, I should say, rather than *at* you!) Made my day.

Comment: @TemaniAfif - "[Codidact: The community-oriented Q&A platform](https://link.medium.com/8ps2ql8kC4)" might help explain things a bit

Comment: Let's be honest, this is a competitor to Stack Overflow that was born from the community frustrations with SO leadership. If this post is intended to be humorous then I hope everyone interprets it that way. I hope nobody seriously expects SO to advertise a competitor for free.

Comment: @Flimm Codidact is not a competitor to Stack Overflow at all. Yes it was born out of Stack Exchange and frustrations with aspects of the platform but it doesn't seek to replace SE in any way whatsoever. Codidact aims to solve similiar challenges in different ways. The internet is big enough for both platforms...

Comment: Why do I keep reading this as "code addict"?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Because if you're on SO you must be a programmer...and all "real programmers" are Code Addicts. Just their <s>drug</s> language of choice varies. (*and why doesn't anything seem to work for strikethrough in comments...*)

Comment: @MatthewBrent When Stack Overflow was born, it was designed to replace Experts Exchange, and they told the world that it was (see [Who's Your Arch-Enemy](https://blog.codinghorror.com/whos-your-arch-enemy/)). It solved similar challenges in different ways. I liked that. It seems to me that Codidact is following a similar path: out of frustration with SO, it is attempting to solve similar challenges in different ways, as you said. That is the very definition of a competitor. That's cool, own it!

Comment: I do want to add that Stack Overflow is not nearly as hated as Experts Exchange, despite all the recent difficulties. Last thing, and then I'll stop posting comments: if Codidact don't want to be seen as a competitor to SO, they need to change the tagline. Right now it reads like this: QA engine (like Stack Overflow) but open source and community-run (but better).

Comment: This is just poetic.

Comment: @Flimm I don't think Codidact has to do anything. It's a free world and Stack Exchange has nothing to fear from Codidact (or from choice). In fact, both projects might learn a lot from each other and I think Codidact is also an awesome opportunity *for Stack Overflow*, to help try out and test different models of Q&A they might adopt in the future without using the main plaform.

Comment: Who knows. Someday SO could decide to spin up an instance of Codidact for each of the SE sites (except the really big SO "main" site itself) and not have to deal with new features, updated design, etc. It all becomes someone else's problem :-)

Comment: From the site: "We also believe that Q&A communities should be free from the politics and shenanigans of private, profit-focused companies." This is clearly a shot at SO.

Comment: @qwr obviously, codidact was literally conceived as and created to be a direct competitor / antithesis to current Stack Exchange.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Here, s̶t̶r̶i̶k̶e̶t̶h̶r̶o̶u̶g̶h̵ in comments.

Comment: @MrLister OK, how do you do strikethrough in comments? (Unlike Q&A, I can't edit to see the source.)

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Add U+0335 (short stroke overlay) chars in between the letters, copied from a char select app.

Comment: @MrLister Aha! Quite a kludge, but still could be worth it a times. Thank you.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact _“Unlike Q&A, I can't edit to see the source”_ — Use this [SOBotics tool](https://tools.sobotics.org/tools/get-body-comment/).

Comment: Seems at very initial stage.

Answer (score 69):

[image: Flarum; forums made simple. Help us build ground breaking, open source forum software.]

Comment: Some extra spacing is recommended for white text but I feel you're o v e r d o i n g i t. Just look at the contrast of the lowercase "fl" ligature with the rest in "flarum"! If you are going to space out, disable ligatures. That "using" is sticking out and can best move to the next line.

Comment: Now that you mention it. I'll take a look tomorrow whether I can improve on that. Thanks!

Comment: I feel the font style looks a little boring...

Comment: Where's the animal?

Comment: The image it's ok for me. The software behind the image is the valuable stuff ;)

Comment: The "Forums Made Simple" centered under FLARUM and off-center with the rest of the text is really bothering me.  But I <3 Flarum.

Comment: I believe the plural for forum is fora.

Answer (score 60):

[image: Open source add-in for static code analysis and tooling in VBA and VB6, written in C#.]

Comment: Note: non-code contributions are welcome as well, especially translations and wiki pages / user documentation. Join our [dev chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929/vba-rubberducking) to ask anything about how everything works, from git & GitHub to C# and .NET, ANTLR grammars and parse trees, COM interop and/or the "fun" parts of being hosted in the VBE, or how to go about implementing and testing a new inspection, a quickfix, a refactoring, ...anything. If you're coming from VBA we're happy to help you learn everything you need to contribute whatever you want to this project =)

Comment: I don't get it[

Comment: @Jonathan issues labeled "up-for-grabs" have a "difficulty" label: "01-duckling", "02-ducky", "03-duck", and "04-quackhead" - in other words "be a ducky" => "be a contributor"

Comment: Also, the project's name "Rubberduck" comes from "Rubber duck debugging" (explaining the problem in details to an inanimate object, often leads to enlightenment), which felt perfect for an IDE plug-in with static code analysis features!

Answer (score 58):

[image: AnkiDroid Flashcards: Help all students learn more efficiently]

Comment: This isn't rendering: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/394409. I believe all the rules have been followed. Any advice?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398031/one-of-the-open-source-community-promotion-ads-is-not-displaying-properly - I can't comment as I don't have the rep, but thank you @Cody Gray

Comment: can I report this Bozo Ad as inappropriate?? No since it asks me to drag and drop some image what the hekk is that

Answer (score 39):

[image: Help us build fair analytic tools.]

Comment: Here's a project that screams for an add-on called "Sieve".

Comment: Or maybe one called "onagen".

Comment: Do you have an ad in Spanish? So we can post it in [es.so]'s Community Ads: [Community Ads 2020](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4713/83)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' thanks for the heads up. We just posted an ad in Spanish over at your place.

Answer (score 29):

[image: TopAnswers on GitHub]

Comment: The perspective font is a little hard to read and blurry.

Comment: @qwr skills needed: PHP, postgres, docker, graphic design. tag:status-completed.

Comment: It would probably work much better without the perspective. Don't make that last line bigger, set it at the same size as the paragraph above it. Maybe even a tiny bit smaller – it is less important than what the site is about, right?

Answer (score 19):

[image: chroot, mount --bind, and binfmt_misc without privilege/setup for Linux.]

Comment: for the non-French speakers : in French, if read as one word ('Proot'), it sounds exactly as the [onomatopoeia for a fart](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/prout).

Comment: "I am Proot"???

Comment: @Pac0, hence the capitalized "R", therefore "P-Root" if you will.

Comment: Shouldn't the `^` be at the `c` of `contributors.h` rather than pointing at the new line?

Comment: @Pac0 and in Swedish. :)

Comment: @KenY-N feel free to test in a compiler. This is the output from `gcc`.

Comment: This tells us exactly nothing about what PRoot is though. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Mast if you look at the previous versions, (See: https://github.com/proot-me/blog/blob/9cc093881043db7d40cca864cd47e22e65a8a5a4/assets/img/proot_advertisement.svg), it had a description, but it was too wordy. Perhaps I could put "learn more at ..." before the website? Otherwise, how can I keep it short and sweet? :)

Answer (score 13):

[image: Help us build an open-source Java toolkit for beautiful, native mobile apps]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Help us build a cross-platform messaging client]

Answer (score 10):

[image: atbswp: The open source multiplatform clone of tinytask]

Answer (score 2):

[image: The Clean Links addon and its community need your help!]

Comment: Perhaps I can make a few suggestions... An ad isn't a manual, so you don't  need examples. You need: the name (☑️), a graphic (a big version of your brush)), and a couple of lines of description, then ask for contributors Eg "contribute on Github". Delete everything else! Then choose a nice pleasant color for the background. Make sure there's at least 30% empty space. hth

Comment: Haha, that previous version didn’t seem to catch on at all indeed @daycaster. Thanks for the feedback, hopes this one works out better.

Comment: Yellow on gray is hard to read. Remove the spaces before the exclamation marks. Otherwise, this is a much better version than the previous one.

Comment: @user4642212 I have removed the spaces and increased the text’s contrast.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Contribute to SCM Backup on GitHub, help us make offline backups from more source code hosters]

Answer (score 0):

[image: t-rext]

Comment: I think this one needs a border, per last bulleted item under Image Requirements: "*Must have a 1px border if (part of) the background is white [. . .]"*

Answer (score -1):

[image: Webrix.js - Powerful building blocks for interactive React applications]

Comment: You may want to read [Will there be Open Source Advertising in 2021?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405031/215552)

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes I read it before, but I gave up on waiting 

Comment: @YoavKadosh this might interest you: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408437/11573842