# One of the Open Source Community Promotion Ads is not displaying properly

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, open-source-advertising

[This page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/394409) displays the currently eligible [Open Source Community Promotion Ads](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394409/open-source-advertising-1h-2020).

Note that the image for the 9th ad (bottom-right corner) is not being properly displayed.

Looking at that page's HTML source, the corresponding table cell contains:

```
<td>
   <a href="http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/ct/398005?url=&amp;s=a596fb223a8b22bb81d4e68e482126c6384cb492834bc2fbd238cd653f4d4e50" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
   <img src="" alt="" title="" width="300" height="250">
   </a>
   <br>
   <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
      Score: 44<br>
      Created: 19 hours ago<br>
      Clicks per day: 0 (0 total)
   </div>
</td>
```

The image source is empty (`<img src=""`), thus preventing the ad from being displayed. What is causing this?

It seems that [DA_123's ad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398005) meets all of the stated requirements. [Its image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyRij.png) is 600×500 pixels (high-DPI), is a PNG, is < 150 KB in size, has a thick blue border, and has been uploaded to imgur.

And, of course, it meets the score threshold, or it wouldn't be displayed in the list at all. The problem is either related to the image itself, or a bug in the code that selects/displays these ads.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! This was caused by a regex fail due to the [migration to Commonmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark) on MSO. It's now fixed.