# Is it acceptable to make a post to find partners for a hobbyist project?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I would like to make a post to attract other developers/architects/strategists to plan and redevelop an existing web site.  This has been a non-profit work, so the post is intended for hobbyists or perhaps students looking to learn.

Is this type of post acceptable on SO?

Comment: Would be totally against rules (adding link to a rule that possibly allows that would greatly improve the post)... slightly more than adding excessive signatures/thank you notes to the post (as later can be edited out by anyone).

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take the time to look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Comment: Perhaps [Indie Hackers](https://www.indiehackers.com/)? It is not strictly what they do (I have mostly seen people reporting what they have already done and getting some comments for the next step - not collaboration requests), but this could maybe be reframed (probably never use the word "hobbyist") - e.g. *collaboratively exploring market potential for X that is targeted towards Y, with hope for Z in mid 2021.* There is a group called *[Building in Public](https://www.indiehackers.com/group/building-in-public)*. Lurk around for a while before you post anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any posts either here on meta or on the main site would be closed and deleted as off-topic at best and might even end up being flagged as spam.

The best you could do here is put some information about what you're up to on your profile and hope someone sees it.

If you're doing something that's already popular then Stack Exchange might sometimes let you create an [Open Source Advert](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394409/open-source-advertising-1h-2020) but I don't think there's been such an offer for H2 2020.