# Community Ads for 2021

Tags: discussion, community-ads, open-source-advertising

**September update:** Community Ads are now live network-wide. All ads with a score of 6 or higher, or with a score of 4 or higher *and* no downvotes will be displayed (except for any that have a note from the CM Team explaining why it wasn't selected). Go to [the main post on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364556/208518) for a list of the ads that are being displayed. And stay tuned for 2022's edition for the next opportunity to submit more ad proposals!

---

**AUGUST NOTE:** This post has now been locked and new submissions are not being accepted. Ad submissions are now undergoing review by the Community Team, and this question will be updated once the ads are live.

---

We're almost halfway through 2021, and [in case you missed it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364556/208518), Open Source Advertising is gonna be a bit different this time! **TL;DR: submit and vote for ad proposals before August 2nd!**

#### What are Community Ads?

Community Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, or on other sites in the network — they're a bit different from [the Open Source Ads initiative of previous years](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394409/1328704). They can show up in the right sidebar, or in banners in question pages. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be considered by [the Community Management Team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/208518) to be displayed.

#### Why do we have Community Ads?

This is a method for the community to create [Free Vote-Based Advertisement for an Open Source Project](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/) and have a say in what gets promoted to visitors on the site. The goal of this initiative is to promote advertisements *soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code*. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source. It's for finding programmers who will help contribute code or other programmery things (documentation, code review, bug fixes, etc.).

This initiative has an added goal of providing your community with *an opportunity to showcase exemplary questions from your main site, as well as frequently-linked-to guides from your Meta site*. While the latter makes sense to be shown solely on this site, the former can be shown all across the network. These should avoid hot button topics, and instead focus more on evergreen questions that show what your community’s all about.

#### Why do we reset the ads?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. Historically, we've reset the ads twice a year — since this is the first run of a new format, we'll run the ads collected in this post through the end of 2021 and reassess the rotation cycle then.

The community ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a previous exposure.

#### Are there restrictions to the ads I can post?

All proposed ads need to abide by [our Code of Conduct](/conduct). [Our ad creative guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/advertising/guidelines) also generally apply (note that the first 2 bullet points on the “Tracking” section do not apply, and a lot of the guidelines surrounding claims, comparisons, proof, etc., while still applicable, may not be particularly relevant). Finally, ads can not be promoting products nor soliciting programmer time or resources for: knowledge sharing or collaboration tools for technologists, or for sites where ad buyers are primarily targeting technologists.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored:

1. **Each answer must relate to a single ad submission.** Please do not post multiple ad submissions in the same answer.
2. All answers must be in one of the below formats:

   1. If you have an image for the ad you want to display on this site (must be the case for ads to external sources):

   ```
   [![Image name. Example: "community_ad_name_300x250"][1]][2]

     [1]: https://image-url
     [2]: https://clickthrough-url
   ```

   2. If you want to create an ad for a question from your main or meta site, to be advertised on this or other sites in the network (staff will generate a frame for the ad with this site's theme, for brand consistency):

   ```
   Question title  
   Question URL
   Ad size (right sidebar or banner ads)
   Site(s) to be displayed in. Can be:
     - "self" for ads to be displayed on this site
     - "all" for ads to be displayed all over the network
     - a specific subset of sites
   ```
3. Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels for right sidebar ads or 728 x 90 pixels for banner ads. Images can be double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF, PNG, or JPG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Selection process

**This post will remain open for ad submissions and voting until August 2nd**. At that point, the question will be closed/locked, and no more ad submissions will be accepted. For ad submissions to be considered for selection by the Community Management Team, they must have **a minimum score of 6 at the time the post was closed/locked for submissions.** Given this is the first run with this new format, we may adjust the score threshold to be a bit lower if we see ads struggling to get to it (especially if the ads are not getting downvotes) by the time submissions and voting are closed.

#### Reporting statistics

Once this cycle is over, at the end of 2021, the Community Management Team will provide you with reporting statistics, as described in the "reporting" section of [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364556/208518).

---

Feel free to use the question's comment section to ask for any clarifications.

Comment: "for sites where ad buyers are targeting technologists" - What does that even mean? What's a "technologist"? Also, taken literally, wouldn't that apply to all websites with a significant "technologist" audience that uses any form of targeted advertising?

Comment: I made an edit to try to reduce the impact of the statement you're asking about, @l4mpi, and hopefully clarify it a bit. Lemme know if I can clarify further.

Comment: Since this is a trial for this new format, we're not building in any blocking. In general, this hasn't been something that has been requested in the past, as these are ads curated by the users of the site. We'll assess how much of a problem for our users this is once the trial is over, but for now we have no plans to allow users to hide the ads. For now, high-rep users can opt out of ads as has always been the case, and once these are live you can always report an ad if you think it's somehow problematic or disruptive.

Comment: @JNat sorry to hear that, i have already more suggestions whyt you can block for users that don't want it, for example the huge yellow right side, with something or other that i don't care about, if it wasn't yellow, it wouldn't be so annoying

Comment: Looks like ublock dislikes cdn.sstatic.net (where the placeholder image is hosted)

Comment: "ads can not be (…) soliciting programmer time or resources for: knowledge sharing or collaboration tools for technologists" Does this prohibit ads linking to GitHub repos for knowledge sharing or collaboration tools, and asking for the viewer's participation in developing these? E.g. [Flarum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394438) (forums share knowledge), [AnkiDroid](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398005) (flash cards share knowledge), [ChatSDK](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394456) (messaging clients are for collaboration), etc.?

Comment: This has already been mentioned on the uber-meta post, but that rule is still awfully written. It excludes far too many tools that aren't remotely competitors or even in the same category as SO. The goal is to justify not advertising codidact and that `.xyz` I don't remember, the implementation blocks anything involving communication or learning in tech (and that's a rather substantial and ridiculous scope, may I add, especially when a few of the projects covered have tags on main here and/or elsewhere in the network)

Comment: @JNat sorry, your edit doesn't clarify anything. Again, how is "technologist" defined in this context? And regardless of its definition, isn't the whole "sites where ad buyers target X" a misdirection, as by my understanding most ad companies profile the users (or buy profiles) and offer ad buyers to target specific demographics based on those profiles, so the ad buyers usually don't target specific sites? So would literally any site using google ads be excluded as google allows ad buyers to target "technologists" everywhere their ad tech is used?

Comment: I also agree with @Zoe that the no-competition rules (while understandable) are BS in the current form. Simply slap a disclaimer like "we will exclude any ads to competing sites and products" in there, or just "we reserve the right to exclude any ads we don't like". Trying to create a concrete rule that targets codidact without calling it by name seems like it would just lead to more headaches than it's worth. Same for the ad rule, if a site is big enough to have any impact on SO ad buyers it probably doesn't need to be advertised it in the first place and should be exculded on those grounds.

Comment: Exactly that ^ -- I have full understanding that SO may want to exclude competing products from ad space they give out for free, not so much for blocking anything involving learning or communication. Either of those two options would've been much better (and more accurate in terms of the actual end goal), and doesn't exclude an _entire category_ from being allowed to advertise just because of _two_ projects they don't want to give free ads to.

Comment: I get the outcry against the new "not allowing competitor's products" rule, but I don't agree with that. The adspace is provided free and obviously it doesn't make sense for any company to allow ads for competitors products. The reason why we didn't have this restriction earlier was because we didn't have any ad for a product that was clearly started as an alternative QnA site to Stack Overflow. Think of it as why we can't have nice things. If we start to misuse more and more of this free stuff, the restrictions would get tighter and tighter.

Comment: @BhargavRao not sure what exactly the "that" is you're not agreeing with. I'm saying _excluding ads for competing products, or anything SO doesn't like, is fine_ but the rule as currently written is not useful, and a generic "we exclude stuff we want to exclude" would be better.

Comment: Why does the alt text need to be the file name? Is that what’s going to be presented to users who can’t see the image or will those who get their as chosen have a chance to submit an image description later?

Comment: Fun fact: Wikipedia has not primary article about the term [technologist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technologist) but would like to have one. Maybe someone with expertise in the field of technologists could write one. It's also a Canadian professional title.

Comment: @JNat are we going to get an answer as to what a "technologist" is any time soon? Or do we have to wait for a blog post that promises to create a process for explaining indecipherable statements by SE staff?

Comment: Took me a bit to go over all my weekend pings, @l4mpi... Technologists is the term we’ve been using for a bit over a year now to describe some of our userbase. While in the past we’ve mostly referred to developers, technologists is meant to encompass not _just_ developers, but also SREs, Data Scientists, DevOps, to name a few. The main gist of it is that some of these folks aren’t necessarily developers in the traditional sense, but their work still entails leveraging technology in ways that are similar to or overlap with developers’ work. (1/2)

Comment: Folks over at Server Fault, for instance, may not be developers, but we’d consider them technologists. (2/2)

Comment: And while I can see why the narrative that this rule is meant to prevent ads to Codidact might make sense, I wanna point out that as written it does not forbid ads like [this one](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5422/9208), for instance. We've _always_ held the right to pull any ad, because this is a space _we_ are providing — this time we decided to make it a bit more explicit _what types of things_ we foresee not advertising. Feels like a reasonable approach to me, instead of using a much scarier "we can exclude whatever we want."

Comment: @JNat thanks, so it's basically just a shorthand for "our users". And again, the problem with the explicit rule is that it seems very badly written - interpreted literally, any site with targeted ads visited by SO users is disallowed. The "visited by users" part is self-fulfilling for a community ad, and AFAIK all big ad providers profile, so any site using an ad provider like google is right out? That is probably not the intention, but if the rule is unclear and/or arbitrarily enforced then it's no better than a "scary" (not really, IMO) generic rule, but way more prone to misunderstandings.

Comment: Have a look at revision 7 [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/364556/revisions) (and maybe the feedback in the post too), @l4mpi, for a bit more context on why I'm saying "scary" about a vaguer clause. And technologists is not quite "our users" but maybe more like "our _tech sites'_ users." Also, "any site with targeted ads visited by SO users is disallowed" seems inaccurate — the point is not whether the sites are _visited_ by technologists, but rather whether the ads _are targeting_ that specific audience.

Comment: @JNat "whether the ads are targeting that specific audience" - again, to my understanding all modern ad providers target _individual users_ and do so _regardless of the site they're on_. Doesn't someone tagged by google as "watches soccer" have a chance to get an ad for soccer related things on literally every site that uses google ads, even if the site has nothing to do with sports? And if that's the case, then the sentence as written would exclude literally every site that uses such an ad provider, as all big ad providers would have ads targeted at techy users.

Comment: ... or alternatively, if the sentence only applies to sites that have a specific contract with ad providers to serve non-individualized tech-specific ads, wouldn't it be almost useless as it would not include sites that use big ad providers like google?

Comment: Would it be clearer (and address your points) if we clarified as "sites where ad buyers are primarily targeting technologists _because those sites have technical content_" or something along those lines, @l4mpi?

Comment: @JNat that sentence is more restrictive and thus possibly clearer, but again, **ad buyers are able to target users regardless of which site they are on**. Here's a direct quote from [google](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/2404239?hl=en&ref_topic=3121944): "Audience targeting allows you to reach people based on their interests, such as sports or travel, even when they visit a page related to a different subject". Your sentence seems to imply that you do care about GDN ads, but only when they're shown on a tech related site, which frankly does not make any sense to me.

Comment: @JNat as an example, say there's a community ad for a cat pictures site which needs coding help for whatever reason. Due to the ad, the site is visited by a lot of SO users. Let's say the site uses GDN ads to pay for hosting. GDN will then probably deliver a lot of tech related ads to the SO visitors because GDN targets individual users. Your sentence implies you wouldn't care about any of those ads - but you would care if the site was hosting the user manuals for electronic devices instead of cat pictures. Not that I'm complaining if that's the case, it just doesn't seem logical.

Answer (score 37):

[image: Rubberduck: an ambitious COM add-in for the VBIDE, written in C#]

Comment: Rubberduck enhances the VBA/VB6 editor (aka VBE, or VBIDE) with static code analysis (many inspections address several frequently-asked [tag:vba] Stack Overflow questions), unit testing, refactorings, navigation tooling, and much more. Code-wise, the project needs help with implementing the many inspection and refactoring ideas (the "issues" list has them all), improving the WPF/XAML user interfaces, and there is a lot of work, for all skill levels; we're always happy to hand-hold a curious duckling and help them take their first PR to the finish line, and non-code contributions also welcome.

Comment: This duck is bigger than [last year's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394419/8967612). I wonder if that was intentional ;) I like it anyway!

Comment: Ducks do tend to grow over time, like most animals. And code.

Comment: Ducks usually grow up within a year, though this duck still seems to be a baby, if a slightly bigger one, one year later

Comment: The slightly fuzzy image quality of the duck is mildly infuriating...

Comment: @DBS thanks for the feedback! I'll try to fix that, but it probably won't happen today.

Comment: Open-source ducks mature much more slowly, @mousetail.

Comment: i'm loving ducks, but the duck needs to sharpen its 'teeth' and its outlines a bit ;)

Comment: I'm afraid I struggle to support anything that means VBA remains a thing in 2021, nice ad though.

Comment: @Liam Thanks! VBA would still be a thing in 2021 without Rubberduck though, whether we like it or dread it! With Rubberduck, VBA devs are nudged towards writing more consistent, explicit code that *does what it says* and *says what it does*; devs coming from VS or VSCode find the navigation and refactoring tools they're looking for, and unit testing makes it easy to *reliably* port VBA functions over to your favorite language, whether that's VB.NET, C#, or TypeScript. VBA is still stuck in 1997, but the IDE doesn't have to be!

Comment: I have vafgue memory that we had this same conversation last year :D

Answer (score 26):

[image: Uno Platform: Apache 2.0!]

Answer (score 12):

[image: Webrix.js: Powerful building blocks for interactive React applications]

Answer (score 12):

[image: Condename One: make Java and Kotlin rock on iOS]

Answer (score 8):

[image: MSK Markdown: contribute on GitHub]

Comment: Just a suggestion: why don't you have some text in the screenshots on GitHub?

Comment: @41686d6564 Sure. my project still new but I am making my best to improve it. From my main reasons for posting the banner is for people to contribute in Issues, pull requests, improvements. and all ideas and improvements are welcome, but yes, I need to improve screenshots context. also for next Improvements, prefer to add it in GitHub not in comments. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 8):

[image: Rails REST Framework: DRY Web APIs for Ruby on Rails]

Comment: A nice-looking ad that appears to meet all the requirements. Thank you for the submission.

Comment: Thanks @Cody! My first one; gotta give credit to Creatopy lol.

Comment: +1 nice design but might argue that the green checkers are not really compatible with the redish design - have you thought about maybe using larger white checks without the round green bckgrd? Another thing is that you are also wasting space (screen/ad real estate) by leaving that much space between _"contribute.."_ and the _'we are making it easy'_ slogan? by increasing the font size on the core features you will gain more readability and reduce the gap

Comment: @iLuvLogix Thanks for the feedback! I replaced the green checks with white ones and I bumped up the font sizes to try to use more real-estate (hopefully without overcrowding the space?). I'm a noob at this so feel free to give me more pointers if you have more.

Comment: Looks much better already, the only thing left that comes to my mind is to reduce the size of the checkers by about 25-30 % and vertically aligning them with the list-points. might be also worth to try different style checkers, such as more [dynamic looking ones](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/03/Green_check.svg/1200px-Green_check.svg.png)

Answer (score 7):

[image: Foxglove Studio: web-based visualization tools for robotics]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Foxglove Studio: web-based visualization tools for robotics]

Answer (score -3):

[image: Web development for everyone]

Comment: That text is barely readable...

Comment: beacuse of resizing rule i need to rescale it

Comment: Can you try with a png image? They are usually better suited for text.

Comment: file size is too big for being png

Answer (score -4):

[image: Worldlang - Code once, transpile to any langauge]

Comment: I'd assume that you're not getting upvotes because the image doesn't really say what this is about. "Contribute on GitHub isn't the primary thing. Anyone looking at the ad is going to know that's what you're advertising to have happen. The thing to focus on is to let people know the very *basics* of what it is you're wanting them to contribute to. In other words, "what is worldlang?" That basic information is in the less obvious text at the bottom. Another time, "worldlang: code once, transpile to ..." should be what's in large font and top/center.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to.

Answer (score -9):

[image: Traccar open source GPS tracking]

Comment: It *really* helps if your ad briefly states what languages and/or technologies your project is using in order for viewers to be able to quickly know if it's a project to which they can easily contribute or is something which they would desire to work on in order to learn something new.

Comment: I agree in the general case, but apparently Traccar has a lot of different tools under the same umbrella, pretty much spanning the gamut from web development to mobile. As an embedded guy, I feel pretty left out, but a lot of developers should find *something* there that fits within their expertise. I don't think it would be useful to clutter up the ad with all of the different technologies in use for each of their tools. It *does* seem like the ad itself is a bit sparse and missing something, though.

Comment: One of the reasons I linked to org is that there are wide variety of options. Web, mobile, backend etc.

Comment: sry but that lloks like a ppt slide from high school to me. maybe bring in some bckgrd-graphics and add more info. maybe play with the fonts a bit

Comment: That isn't appealing at all

Comment: You could (should) list the most significant languages / technologies used...